# Allowing user to select app language/locale?

Tags: android, localization, locale

I have an Android app that I have just prepared for localization, with one locale completed and more on the way. I want to give users the option of viewing the app in a different locale (ie- language) without having to modify their system locale settings.

So, for example:
App has locale capability for en, es, zh, ja.
User has "es" selected as their system locale.
User can open the application's preferences page and select "ja" locale.
App will now display the text/formatting according to the Ja locale of the app.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm more curious from a design standpoint why you would want this functionality.  At what benefit for the user?

Comment: I'm with the OP here as depending on the application I prefer English or Italian (when available) and my phone is set to English...

Comment: @justinl - I think this would be absolutely useful for the exact reason that Dario mentions. It's about flexibility. Being able to choose the language that gets displayed, and not having to stay with the system-wide option.

Comment: Fair enough :)  I wish we had an answer for Quartertone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled onto the following stackoverflow post while on an unrelated search. This is exactly what I've been looking for.

[Changing Locale within the app itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/android-changing-locale-within-the-app-itself)