# Android, costum localisation while running app

Tags: android, localization

i have problem switching locale language while app is still running, how to do that? Thanks. I have read lot of docs... and still do not find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful, changing the locale on the fly isn't officially supported! **You** have to take care of refreshing every text yourself! In my case, as I don't have many UI elements, I just did `button1.setText(R.string.hello); button2.setText(R.string.bye);` after chaning the locale.

Comment: so, do you have any suggestion, or alternative ?

Comment: The alternative is to change the locale in the device settings (it can be done programmatically, but requires extra permissions in the manifest) and reload the whole application. Many users won't like you changing their settings, though.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code in [Changing Locale within the app itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/android-changing-locale-within-the-app-itself)

Comment: Thanks, but i need for 80% versions of android platforms

Comment: is there something witch will work on at least 80% platforms?