# How to implement languages for particular application

Tags: java, android

i am supposed to implement different languages(indian languages) for particular application

without changing languages settings on phone.

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/intl/

Comment: From what I've seen, getting a Hindi font to work on Android does not seem to be easy, even in Android 2.3 where it's officially supported :/.

Answer (score 0):

I think he means using the standard mechanism of localisation, but making it independent of system language selection.
 Maybe [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/android-changing-locale-within-the-app-itself) helps