# change the language in android application

Tags: android

I'm writing an application were it requires to change the language of the application as and when the user requires. The data in different language is stored in the data base, from which the data is fetched and the UI is updated. I'm want to what should be done if device does not support the particular language font. Any help will be much appreciated.Thanks in advance. _/|_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know more about this but ...

for example if you want your application to support both English
and French strings (in addition to the default strings), 
you can simply create two additional
resource directories called `/res/values-en` (for the English strings.xml) and
`/res/values-fr` (for the French strings.xml).

Within the `strings.xml` files, the
resource names are the same.

For example, the `/res/values-en/strings.xml` file could
look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello in English!</string>
</resources>
```

Whereas, the /res/values-fr/strings.xml file would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Bonjour en Français!</string>
</resources>
```

A default layout file in the /res/layout directory that displays the string refers to the
string by the variable name @string/hello, without regard to which language or directory
the string resource is in.

The Android operating system determines which version of
the string (French, English, or default) to load at runtime.A layout with a TextView control
to display the string might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:text="@string/hello" >
</LinearLayout>
```

The string is accessed programmatically in the normal way:

```
String str = getString(R.string.hello);
```

It’s as easy as that.

More you will found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/android-changing-locale-within-the-app-itself)