# How can I change language of my application

Tags: android, internationalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change language programatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android)

I am new to Android. In my application user can select a language from three languages. Based on the language selected by user, the entire application's language should be change. How can I do this?

Comment: Use this to change the language by programmatically:


`code' 
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US"); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 `code'

Answer (score 51):

Use this to change the language programmatically:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US"); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

Write the country code of the language in place of `"en_US"` for whatever language you want. For example, for Japanese, `ja_JP`; for Arabic, `ar`. Check [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120814113314/http://colincooper.net/blog/2011/02/17/android-supported-language-and-locales/) for a list.

And make a folder in `res/values-ja` for Japanese or `res/values-ar` for Arabic..

And make a `string.xml` file, and put whatever languages you want on your layout. It will fetch the default language from values folder otherwise if you want it manually, then it will fetch from your external folder `values-ar`, etc.

An example of `res/values-ar` for Arabic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <resources>
    <string name="label">حسب</string>
    <string name="name">بحث</string> 
    <string name="search">بحث :</string>
 </resource>
```

Comment: where to call your code !?

Comment: Call it where you need.

Comment: will calling it one time be enough to apply it to the whole app ? or each and every activity ?

Comment: thanks your code works for me, changes the language of my app. But I also want to change language of  keyboard according to that, which is not changed, can you help me?

Comment: The link for the list of languages is deprecated. Here's the latest list can be found. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39410286/3145960

Answer (score 6):

You can set the locale.

```
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    // Change locale settings in the app.
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase());
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

If you have language specific content - you can change that base on the setting.
for more detail you can see  [Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) and   [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/android-changing-locale-within-the-app-itself/2271141#2271141)