# What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android?

Tags: android, localization

I'd like to know what to name my folder for different languages. Where can I find the supported list of languages on Android?

Comment: Can you move the answer to your question to an answer to this post, and mark it as the selected answer?  For others who have the same question, it will help for them to be able to see that there's a selected answer :)  (BTW, it's totally fine to answer your own question).

Comment: Yes, please edit this so you are asking a question in the question area  like "What locales does Andriod support, and from what version did it support them? Does a list exist?", then provide the information as an answer. This would probably be handy to link to in the Tag Wiki.  I'm making this CW so others can help turn it into a proper question, thanks for sharing :)

Comment: If you installed the Extras in Android SDK Manager, then after installation, go to the `\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res` directory to see a list of locale [directories] supported by Android. Also, check this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html).

Comment: Define "support".  You can use all three-letter language codes without problem (although there may be no interface by which to select that language).  I've developed apps in Asturian (code `ast`) and there's no problem as of Android 5ish.  Only some distributions let users select it, so I have a option in settings to always launch in X language which includes all my supported locales.

Comment: Here's the answer to the "how to name" part of the question from the [Configuration qualifier names table](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2): "The language is defined by a two-letter ISO 639-1 language code, optionally followed by a two letter ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 region code (preceded by lowercase 'r')."

Answer (score 544, accepted):

> **Updated list as of Android 5.1:**

```
af_ [Afrikaans]
af_NA [Afrikaans (Namibia)]
af_ZA [Afrikaans (South Africa)]
agq_ [Aghem]
agq_CM [Aghem (Cameroon)]
ak_ [Akan]
ak_GH [Akan (Ghana)]
am_ [Amharic]
am_ET [Amharic (Ethiopia)]
ar_ [Arabic]
ar_001 [Arabic (World)]
ar_AE [Arabic (United Arab Emirates)]
ar_BH [Arabic (Bahrain)]
ar_DJ [Arabic (Djibouti)]
ar_DZ [Arabic (Algeria)]
ar_EG [Arabic (Egypt)]
ar_EH [Arabic (Western Sahara)]
ar_ER [Arabic (Eritrea)]
ar_IL [Arabic (Israel)]
ar_IQ [Arabic (Iraq)]
ar_JO [Arabic (Jordan)]
ar_KM [Arabic (Comoros)]
ar_KW [Arabic (Kuwait)]
ar_LB [Arabic (Lebanon)]
ar_LY [Arabic (Libya)]
ar_MA [Arabic (Morocco)]
ar_MR [Arabic (Mauritania)]
ar_OM [Arabic (Oman)]
ar_PS [Arabic (Palestine)]
ar_QA [Arabic (Qatar)]
ar_SA [Arabic (Saudi Arabia)]
ar_SD [Arabic (Sudan)]
ar_SO [Arabic (Somalia)]
ar_SS [Arabic (South Sudan)]
ar_SY [Arabic (Syria)]
ar_TD [Arabic (Chad)]
ar_TN [Arabic (Tunisia)]
ar_YE [Arabic (Yemen)]
as_ [Assamese]
as_IN [Assamese (India)]
asa_ [Asu]
asa_TZ [Asu (Tanzania)]
az_ [Azerbaijani]
az_ [Azerbaijani (Cyrillic)]
az_AZ [Azerbaijani (Cyrillic,Azerbaijan)]
az_ [Azerbaijani (Latin)]
az_AZ [Azerbaijani (Latin,Azerbaijan)]
bas_ [Basaa]
bas_CM [Basaa (Cameroon)]
be_ [Belarusian]
be_BY [Belarusian (Belarus)]
bem_ [Bemba]
bem_ZM [Bemba (Zambia)]
bez_ [Bena]
bez_TZ [Bena (Tanzania)]
bg_ [Bulgarian]
bg_BG [Bulgarian (Bulgaria)]
bm_ [Bambara]
bm_ML [Bambara (Mali)]
bn_ [Bengali]
bn_BD [Bengali (Bangladesh)]
bn_IN [Bengali (India)]
bo_ [Tibetan]
bo_CN [Tibetan (China)]
bo_IN [Tibetan (India)]
br_ [Breton]
br_FR [Breton (France)]
brx_ [Bodo]
brx_IN [Bodo (India)]
bs_ [Bosnian]
bs_ [Bosnian (Cyrillic)]
bs_BA [Bosnian (Cyrillic,Bosnia and Herzegovina)]
bs_ [Bosnian (Latin)]
bs_BA [Bosnian (Latin,Bosnia and Herzegovina)]
ca_ [Catalan]
ca_AD [Catalan (Andorra)]
ca_ES [Catalan (Spain)]
ca_FR [Catalan (France)]
ca_IT [Catalan (Italy)]
cgg_ [Chiga]
cgg_UG [Chiga (Uganda)]
chr_ [Cherokee]
chr_US [Cherokee (United States)]
cs_ [Czech]
cs_CZ [Czech (Czech Republic)]
cy_ [Welsh]
cy_GB [Welsh (United Kingdom)]
da_ [Danish]
da_DK [Danish (Denmark)]
da_GL [Danish (Greenland)]
dav_ [Taita]
dav_KE [Taita (Kenya)]
de_ [German]
de_AT [German (Austria)]
de_BE [German (Belgium)]
de_CH [German (Switzerland)]
de_DE [German (Germany)]
de_LI [German (Liechtenstein)]
de_LU [German (Luxembourg)]
dje_ [Zarma]
dje_NE [Zarma (Niger)]
dua_ [Duala]
dua_CM [Duala (Cameroon)]
dyo_ [Jola-Fonyi]
dyo_SN [Jola-Fonyi (Senegal)]
dz_ [Dzongkha]
dz_BT [Dzongkha (Bhutan)]
ebu_ [Embu]
ebu_KE [Embu (Kenya)]
ee_ [Ewe]
ee_GH [Ewe (Ghana)]
ee_TG [Ewe (Togo)]
el_ [Greek]
el_CY [Greek (Cyprus)]
el_GR [Greek (Greece)]
en_ [English]
en_001 [English (World)]
en_150 [English (Europe)]
en_AG [English (Antigua and Barbuda)]
en_AI [English (Anguilla)]
en_AS [English (American Samoa)]
en_AU [English (Australia)]
en_BB [English (Barbados)]
en_BE [English (Belgium)]
en_BM [English (Bermuda)]
en_BS [English (Bahamas)]
en_BW [English (Botswana)]
en_BZ [English (Belize)]
en_CA [English (Canada)]
en_CC [English (Cocos (Keeling) Islands)]
en_CK [English (Cook Islands)]
en_CM [English (Cameroon)]
en_CX [English (Christmas Island)]
en_DG [English (Diego Garcia)]
en_DM [English (Dominica)]
en_ER [English (Eritrea)]
en_FJ [English (Fiji)]
en_FK [English (Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas))]
en_FM [English (Micronesia)]
en_GB [English (United Kingdom)]
en_GD [English (Grenada)]
en_GG [English (Guernsey)]
en_GH [English (Ghana)]
en_GI [English (Gibraltar)]
en_GM [English (Gambia)]
en_GU [English (Guam)]
en_GY [English (Guyana)]
en_HK [English (Hong Kong)]
en_IE [English (Ireland)]
en_IM [English (Isle of Man)]
en_IN [English (India)]
en_IO [English (British Indian Ocean Territory)]
en_JE [English (Jersey)]
en_JM [English (Jamaica)]
en_KE [English (Kenya)]
en_KI [English (Kiribati)]
en_KN [English (Saint Kitts and Nevis)]
en_KY [English (Cayman Islands)]
en_LC [English (Saint Lucia)]
en_LR [English (Liberia)]
en_LS [English (Lesotho)]
en_MG [English (Madagascar)]
en_MH [English (Marshall Islands)]
en_MO [English (Macau)]
en_MP [English (Northern Mariana Islands)]
en_MS [English (Montserrat)]
en_MT [English (Malta)]
en_MU [English (Mauritius)]
en_MW [English (Malawi)]
en_NA [English (Namibia)]
en_NF [English (Norfolk Island)]
en_NG [English (Nigeria)]
en_NR [English (Nauru)]
en_NU [English (Niue)]
en_NZ [English (New Zealand)]
en_PG [English (Papua New Guinea)]
en_PH [English (Philippines)]
en_PK [English (Pakistan)]
en_PN [English (Pitcairn Islands)]
en_PR [English (Puerto Rico)]
en_PW [English (Palau)]
en_RW [English (Rwanda)]
en_SB [English (Solomon Islands)]
en_SC [English (Seychelles)]
en_SD [English (Sudan)]
en_SG [English (Singapore)]
en_SH [English (Saint Helena)]
en_SL [English (Sierra Leone)]
en_SS [English (South Sudan)]
en_SX [English (Sint Maarten)]
en_SZ [English (Swaziland)]
en_TC [English (Turks and Caicos Islands)]
en_TK [English (Tokelau)]
en_TO [English (Tonga)]
en_TT [English (Trinidad and Tobago)]
en_TV [English (Tuvalu)]
en_TZ [English (Tanzania)]
en_UG [English (Uganda)]
en_UM [English (U.S. Outlying Islands)]
en_US [English (United States)]
en_US [English (United States,Computer)]
en_VC [English (St. Vincent & Grenadines)]
en_VG [English (British Virgin Islands)]
en_VI [English (U.S. Virgin Islands)]
en_VU [English (Vanuatu)]
en_WS [English (Samoa)]
en_ZA [English (South Africa)]
en_ZM [English (Zambia)]
en_ZW [English (Zimbabwe)]
eo_ [Esperanto]
es_ [Spanish]
es_419 [Spanish (Latin America)]
es_AR [Spanish (Argentina)]
es_BO [Spanish (Bolivia)]
es_CL [Spanish (Chile)]
es_CO [Spanish (Colombia)]
es_CR [Spanish (Costa Rica)]
es_CU [Spanish (Cuba)]
es_DO [Spanish (Dominican Republic)]
es_EA [Spanish (Ceuta and Melilla)]
es_EC [Spanish (Ecuador)]
es_ES [Spanish (Spain)]
es_GQ [Spanish (Equatorial Guinea)]
es_GT [Spanish (Guatemala)]
es_HN [Spanish (Honduras)]
es_IC [Spanish (Canary Islands)]
es_MX [Spanish (Mexico)]
es_NI [Spanish (Nicaragua)]
es_PA [Spanish (Panama)]
es_PE [Spanish (Peru)]
es_PH [Spanish (Philippines)]
es_PR [Spanish (Puerto Rico)]
es_PY [Spanish (Paraguay)]
es_SV [Spanish (El Salvador)]
es_US [Spanish (United States)]
es_UY [Spanish (Uruguay)]
es_VE [Spanish (Venezuela)]
et_ [Estonian]
et_EE [Estonian (Estonia)]
eu_ [Basque]
eu_ES [Basque (Spain)]
ewo_ [Ewondo]
ewo_CM [Ewondo (Cameroon)]
fa_ [Persian]
fa_AF [Persian (Afghanistan)]
fa_IR [Persian (Iran)]
ff_ [Fulah]
ff_SN [Fulah (Senegal)]
fi_ [Finnish]
fi_FI [Finnish (Finland)]
fil_ [Filipino]
fil_PH [Filipino (Philippines)]
fo_ [Faroese]
fo_FO [Faroese (Faroe Islands)]
fr_ [French]
fr_BE [French (Belgium)]
fr_BF [French (Burkina Faso)]
fr_BI [French (Burundi)]
fr_BJ [French (Benin)]
fr_BL [French (Saint Barthélemy)]
fr_CA [French (Canada)]
fr_CD [French (Congo (DRC))]
fr_CF [French (Central African Republic)]
fr_CG [French (Congo (Republic))]
fr_CH [French (Switzerland)]
fr_CI [French (Côte d’Ivoire)]
fr_CM [French (Cameroon)]
fr_DJ [French (Djibouti)]
fr_DZ [French (Algeria)]
fr_FR [French (France)]
fr_GA [French (Gabon)]
fr_GF [French (French Guiana)]
fr_GN [French (Guinea)]
fr_GP [French (Guadeloupe)]
fr_GQ [French (Equatorial Guinea)]
fr_HT [French (Haiti)]
fr_KM [French (Comoros)]
fr_LU [French (Luxembourg)]
fr_MA [French (Morocco)]
fr_MC [French (Monaco)]
fr_MF [French (Saint Martin)]
fr_MG [French (Madagascar)]
fr_ML [French (Mali)]
fr_MQ [French (Martinique)]
fr_MR [French (Mauritania)]
fr_MU [French (Mauritius)]
fr_NC [French (New Caledonia)]
fr_NE [French (Niger)]
fr_PF [French (French Polynesia)]
fr_PM [French (Saint Pierre and Miquelon)]
fr_RE [French (Réunion)]
fr_RW [French (Rwanda)]
fr_SC [French (Seychelles)]
fr_SN [French (Senegal)]
fr_SY [French (Syria)]
fr_TD [French (Chad)]
fr_TG [French (Togo)]
fr_TN [French (Tunisia)]
fr_VU [French (Vanuatu)]
fr_WF [French (Wallis and Futuna)]
fr_YT [French (Mayotte)]
ga_ [Irish]
ga_IE [Irish (Ireland)]
gl_ [Galician]
gl_ES [Galician (Spain)]
gsw_ [Swiss German]
gsw_CH [Swiss German (Switzerland)]
gsw_LI [Swiss German (Liechtenstein)]
gu_ [Gujarati]
gu_IN [Gujarati (India)]
guz_ [Gusii]
guz_KE [Gusii (Kenya)]
gv_ [Manx]
gv_IM [Manx (Isle of Man)]
ha_ [Hausa]
ha_ [Hausa (Latin)]
ha_GH [Hausa (Latin,Ghana)]
ha_NE [Hausa (Latin,Niger)]
ha_NG [Hausa (Latin,Nigeria)]
haw_ [Hawaiian]
haw_US [Hawaiian (United States)]
iw_ [Hebrew]
iw_IL [Hebrew (Israel)]
hi_ [Hindi]
hi_IN [Hindi (India)]
hr_ [Croatian]
hr_BA [Croatian (Bosnia and Herzegovina)]
hr_HR [Croatian (Croatia)]
hu_ [Hungarian]
hu_HU [Hungarian (Hungary)]
hy_ [Armenian]
hy_AM [Armenian (Armenia)]
in_ [Indonesian]
in_ID [Indonesian (Indonesia)]
ig_ [Igbo]
ig_NG [Igbo (Nigeria)]
ii_ [Sichuan Yi]
ii_CN [Sichuan Yi (China)]
is_ [Icelandic]
is_IS [Icelandic (Iceland)]
it_ [Italian]
it_CH [Italian (Switzerland)]
it_IT [Italian (Italy)]
it_SM [Italian (San Marino)]
ja_ [Japanese]
ja_JP [Japanese (Japan)]
jgo_ [Ngomba]
jgo_CM [Ngomba (Cameroon)]
jmc_ [Machame]
jmc_TZ [Machame (Tanzania)]
ka_ [Georgian]
ka_GE [Georgian (Georgia)]
kab_ [Kabyle]
kab_DZ [Kabyle (Algeria)]
kam_ [Kamba]
kam_KE [Kamba (Kenya)]
kde_ [Makonde]
kde_TZ [Makonde (Tanzania)]
kea_ [Kabuverdianu]
kea_CV [Kabuverdianu (Cape Verde)]
khq_ [Koyra Chiini]
khq_ML [Koyra Chiini (Mali)]
ki_ [Kikuyu]
ki_KE [Kikuyu (Kenya)]
kk_ [Kazakh]
kk_ [Kazakh (Cyrillic)]
kk_KZ [Kazakh (Cyrillic,Kazakhstan)]
kkj_ [Kako]
kkj_CM [Kako (Cameroon)]
kl_ [Kalaallisut]
kl_GL [Kalaallisut (Greenland)]
kln_ [Kalenjin]
kln_KE [Kalenjin (Kenya)]
km_ [Khmer]
km_KH [Khmer (Cambodia)]
kn_ [Kannada]
kn_IN [Kannada (India)]
ko_ [Korean]
ko_KP [Korean (North Korea)]
ko_KR [Korean (South Korea)]
kok_ [Konkani]
kok_IN [Konkani (India)]
ks_ [Kashmiri]
ks_ [Kashmiri (Arabic)]
ks_IN [Kashmiri (Arabic,India)]
ksb_ [Shambala]
ksb_TZ [Shambala (Tanzania)]
ksf_ [Bafia]
ksf_CM [Bafia (Cameroon)]
kw_ [Cornish]
kw_GB [Cornish (United Kingdom)]
ky_ [Kyrgyz]
ky_ [Kyrgyz (Cyrillic)]
ky_KG [Kyrgyz (Cyrillic,Kyrgyzstan)]
lag_ [Langi]
lag_TZ [Langi (Tanzania)]
lg_ [Ganda]
lg_UG [Ganda (Uganda)]
lkt_ [Lakota]
lkt_US [Lakota (United States)]
ln_ [Lingala]
ln_AO [Lingala (Angola)]
ln_CD [Lingala (Congo (DRC))]
ln_CF [Lingala (Central African Republic)]
ln_CG [Lingala (Congo (Republic))]
lo_ [Lao]
lo_LA [Lao (Laos)]
lt_ [Lithuanian]
lt_LT [Lithuanian (Lithuania)]
lu_ [Luba-Katanga]
lu_CD [Luba-Katanga (Congo (DRC))]
luo_ [Luo]
luo_KE [Luo (Kenya)]
luy_ [Luyia]
luy_KE [Luyia (Kenya)]
lv_ [Latvian]
lv_LV [Latvian (Latvia)]
mas_ [Masai]
mas_KE [Masai (Kenya)]
mas_TZ [Masai (Tanzania)]
mer_ [Meru]
mer_KE [Meru (Kenya)]
mfe_ [Morisyen]
mfe_MU [Morisyen (Mauritius)]
mg_ [Malagasy]
mg_MG [Malagasy (Madagascar)]
mgh_ [Makhuwa-Meetto]
mgh_MZ [Makhuwa-Meetto (Mozambique)]
mgo_ [Meta']
mgo_CM [Meta' (Cameroon)]
mk_ [Macedonian]
mk_MK [Macedonian (Macedonia (FYROM))]
ml_ [Malayalam]
ml_IN [Malayalam (India)]
mn_ [Mongolian]
mn_ [Mongolian (Cyrillic)]
mn_MN [Mongolian (Cyrillic,Mongolia)]
mr_ [Marathi]
mr_IN [Marathi (India)]
ms_ [Malay]
ms_ [Malay (Latin)]
ms_BN [Malay (Latin,Brunei)]
ms_MY [Malay (Latin,Malaysia)]
ms_SG [Malay (Latin,Singapore)]
mt_ [Maltese]
mt_MT [Maltese (Malta)]
mua_ [Mundang]
mua_CM [Mundang (Cameroon)]
my_ [Burmese]
my_MM [Burmese (Myanmar (Burma))]
naq_ [Nama]
naq_NA [Nama (Namibia)]
nb_ [Norwegian Bokmål]
nb_NO [Norwegian Bokmål (Norway)]
nb_SJ [Norwegian Bokmål (Svalbard and Jan Mayen)]
nd_ [North Ndebele]
nd_ZW [North Ndebele (Zimbabwe)]
ne_ [Nepali]
ne_IN [Nepali (India)]
ne_NP [Nepali (Nepal)]
nl_ [Dutch]
nl_AW [Dutch (Aruba)]
nl_BE [Dutch (Belgium)]
nl_BQ [Dutch (Caribbean Netherlands)]
nl_CW [Dutch (Curaçao)]
nl_NL [Dutch (Netherlands)]
nl_SR [Dutch (Suriname)]
nl_SX [Dutch (Sint Maarten)]
nmg_ [Kwasio]
nmg_CM [Kwasio (Cameroon)]
nn_ [Norwegian Nynorsk]
nn_NO [Norwegian Nynorsk (Norway)]
nnh_ [Ngiemboon]
nnh_CM [Ngiemboon (Cameroon)]
nus_ [Nuer]
nus_SD [Nuer (Sudan)]
nyn_ [Nyankole]
nyn_UG [Nyankole (Uganda)]
om_ [Oromo]
om_ET [Oromo (Ethiopia)]
om_KE [Oromo (Kenya)]
or_ [Oriya]
or_IN [Oriya (India)]
pa_ [Punjabi]
pa_ [Punjabi (Arabic)]
pa_PK [Punjabi (Arabic,Pakistan)]
pa_ [Punjabi (Gurmukhi)]
pa_IN [Punjabi (Gurmukhi,India)]
pl_ [Polish]
pl_PL [Polish (Poland)]
ps_ [Pashto]
ps_AF [Pashto (Afghanistan)]
pt_ [Portuguese]
pt_AO [Portuguese (Angola)]
pt_BR [Portuguese (Brazil)]
pt_CV [Portuguese (Cape Verde)]
pt_GW [Portuguese (Guinea-Bissau)]
pt_MO [Portuguese (Macau)]
pt_MZ [Portuguese (Mozambique)]
pt_PT [Portuguese (Portugal)]
pt_ST [Portuguese (São Tomé and Príncipe)]
pt_TL [Portuguese (Timor-Leste)]
rm_ [Romansh]
rm_CH [Romansh (Switzerland)]
rn_ [Rundi]
rn_BI [Rundi (Burundi)]
ro_ [Romanian]
ro_MD [Romanian (Moldova)]
ro_RO [Romanian (Romania)]
rof_ [Rombo]
rof_TZ [Rombo (Tanzania)]
ru_ [Russian]
ru_BY [Russian (Belarus)]
ru_KG [Russian (Kyrgyzstan)]
ru_KZ [Russian (Kazakhstan)]
ru_MD [Russian (Moldova)]
ru_RU [Russian (Russia)]
ru_UA [Russian (Ukraine)]
rw_ [Kinyarwanda]
rw_RW [Kinyarwanda (Rwanda)]
rwk_ [Rwa]
rwk_TZ [Rwa (Tanzania)]
saq_ [Samburu]
saq_KE [Samburu (Kenya)]
sbp_ [Sangu]
sbp_TZ [Sangu (Tanzania)]
seh_ [Sena]
seh_MZ [Sena (Mozambique)]
ses_ [Koyraboro Senni]
ses_ML [Koyraboro Senni (Mali)]
sg_ [Sango]
sg_CF [Sango (Central African Republic)]
shi_ [Tachelhit]
shi_ [Tachelhit (Latin)]
shi_MA [Tachelhit (Latin,Morocco)]
shi_ [Tachelhit (Tifinagh)]
shi_MA [Tachelhit (Tifinagh,Morocco)]
si_ [Sinhala]
si_LK [Sinhala (Sri Lanka)]
sk_ [Slovak]
sk_SK [Slovak (Slovakia)]
sl_ [Slovenian]
sl_SI [Slovenian (Slovenia)]
sn_ [Shona]
sn_ZW [Shona (Zimbabwe)]
so_ [Somali]
so_DJ [Somali (Djibouti)]
so_ET [Somali (Ethiopia)]
so_KE [Somali (Kenya)]
so_SO [Somali (Somalia)]
sq_ [Albanian]
sq_AL [Albanian (Albania)]
sq_MK [Albanian (Macedonia (FYROM))]
sq_XK [Albanian (Kosovo)]
sr_ [Serbian]
sr_ [Serbian (Cyrillic)]
sr_BA [Serbian (Cyrillic,Bosnia and Herzegovina)]
sr_ME [Serbian (Cyrillic,Montenegro)]
sr_RS [Serbian (Cyrillic,Serbia)]
sr_XK [Serbian (Cyrillic,Kosovo)]
sr_ [Serbian (Latin)]
sr_BA [Serbian (Latin,Bosnia and Herzegovina)]
sr_ME [Serbian (Latin,Montenegro)]
sr_RS [Serbian (Latin,Serbia)]
sr_XK [Serbian (Latin,Kosovo)]
sv_ [Swedish]
sv_AX [Swedish (Åland Islands)]
sv_FI [Swedish (Finland)]
sv_SE [Swedish (Sweden)]
sw_ [Swahili]
sw_KE [Swahili (Kenya)]
sw_TZ [Swahili (Tanzania)]
sw_UG [Swahili (Uganda)]
swc_ [Congo Swahili]
swc_CD [Congo Swahili (Congo (DRC))]
ta_ [Tamil]
ta_IN [Tamil (India)]
ta_LK [Tamil (Sri Lanka)]
ta_MY [Tamil (Malaysia)]
ta_SG [Tamil (Singapore)]
te_ [Telugu]
te_IN [Telugu (India)]
teo_ [Teso]
teo_KE [Teso (Kenya)]
teo_UG [Teso (Uganda)]
th_ [Thai]
th_TH [Thai (Thailand)]
ti_ [Tigrinya]
ti_ER [Tigrinya (Eritrea)]
ti_ET [Tigrinya (Ethiopia)]
to_ [Tongan]
to_TO [Tongan (Tonga)]
tr_ [Turkish]
tr_CY [Turkish (Cyprus)]
tr_TR [Turkish (Turkey)]
twq_ [Tasawaq]
twq_NE [Tasawaq (Niger)]
tzm_ [Central Atlas Tamazight]
tzm_ [Central Atlas Tamazight (Latin)]
tzm_MA [Central Atlas Tamazight (Latin,Morocco)]
ug_ [Uyghur]
ug_ [Uyghur (Arabic)]
ug_CN [Uyghur (Arabic,China)]
uk_ [Ukrainian]
uk_UA [Ukrainian (Ukraine)]
ur_ [Urdu]
ur_IN [Urdu (India)]
ur_PK [Urdu (Pakistan)]
uz_ [Uzbek]
uz_ [Uzbek (Arabic)]
uz_AF [Uzbek (Arabic,Afghanistan)]
uz_ [Uzbek (Cyrillic)]
uz_UZ [Uzbek (Cyrillic,Uzbekistan)]
uz_ [Uzbek (Latin)]
uz_UZ [Uzbek (Latin,Uzbekistan)]
vai_ [Vai]
vai_ [Vai (Latin)]
vai_LR [Vai (Latin,Liberia)]
vai_ [Vai (Vai)]
vai_LR [Vai (Vai,Liberia)]
vi_ [Vietnamese]
vi_VN [Vietnamese (Vietnam)]
vun_ [Vunjo]
vun_TZ [Vunjo (Tanzania)]
xog_ [Soga]
xog_UG [Soga (Uganda)]
yav_ [Yangben]
yav_CM [Yangben (Cameroon)]
yo_ [Yoruba]
yo_BJ [Yoruba (Benin)]
yo_NG [Yoruba (Nigeria)]
zgh_ [Standard Moroccan Tamazight]
zgh_MA [Standard Moroccan Tamazight (Morocco)]
zh_ [Chinese]
zh_ [Chinese (Simplified Han)]
zh_CN [Chinese (Simplified Han,China)]
zh_HK [Chinese (Simplified Han,Hong Kong)]
zh_MO [Chinese (Simplified Han,Macau)]
zh_SG [Chinese (Simplified Han,Singapore)]
zh_ [Chinese (Traditional Han)]
zh_HK [Chinese (Traditional Han,Hong Kong)]
zh_MO [Chinese (Traditional Han,Macau)]
zh_TW [Chinese (Traditional Han,Taiwan)]
zu_ [Zulu]
zu_ZA [Zulu (South Africa)]
```

> **Original Answer :**

As of `Android 5.0`, all languages in `BCP 47` are available for application development (they may not necessarily be available for selection in a given device's system settings, though).  When using `ISO 639-1` codes, the resource folder has the format `values-xx...` where xx is the `ISO-639-1` code.

When using `BCP 47` tags, the resource folder is named `values-b+xxx...` where xxx is the three-letter language code.

**Here's the list for before Android 2.3 ([Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20120814113314/http://colincooper.net/blog/2011/02/17/android-supported-language-and-locales/))**

> ```
> Language / Locale                 Supported since version
>
> English, US (en_US)               1.1
> German, Germany (de_DE)           1.1
> Chinese, PRC (zh_CN)              1.5
> Chinese, Taiwan (zh_TW)           1.5
> Czech, Czech Republic (cs_CZ)     1.5
> Dutch, Belgium (nl_BE)            1.5
> Dutch, Netherlands (nl_NL)        1.5
> English, Australia (en_AU)        1.5
> English, Britain (en_GB)          1.5
> English, Canada (en_CA)           1.5
> English, New Zealand (en_NZ)      1.5
> English, Singapore(en_SG)         1.5
> French, Belgium (fr_BE)           1.5
> French, Canada (fr_CA)            1.5
> French, France (fr_FR)            1.5
> French, Switzerland (fr_CH)       1.5
> German, Austria (de_AT)           1.5
> German, Liechtenstein (de_LI)     1.5
> German, Switzerland (de_CH)       1.5
> Italian, Italy (it_IT)            1.5
> Italian, Switzerland (it_CH)      1.5
> Japanese (ja_JP)                  1.5
> Korean (ko_KR)                    1.5
> Polish (pl_PL)                    1.5
> Russian (ru_RU)                   1.5
> Spanish (es_ES)                   1.5
> Arabic, Egypt (ar_EG)             2.3
> Arabic, Israel (ar_IL)            2.3
> Bulgarian, Bulgaria (bg_BG)       2.3
> Catalan, Spain (ca_ES)            2.3
> Croatian, Croatia (hr_HR)         2.3
> Danish, Denmark(da_DK)            2.3
> English, India (en_IN)            2.3
> English, Ireland (en_IE)          2.3
> English, Zimbabwe (en_ZA)         2.3
> Finnish, Finland (fi_FI)          2.3
> Greek, Greece (el_GR)             2.3
> Hebrew, Israel (iw_IL)*           2.3
> Hindi, India (hi_IN)              2.3
> Hungarian, Hungary (hu_HU)        2.3
> Indonesian, Indonesia (in_ID)*    2.3
> Latvian, Latvia (lv_LV)           2.3
> Lithuanian, Lithuania (lt_LT)     2.3
> Norwegian-Bokmål, Norway(nb_NO)   2.3
> Portuguese, Brazil (pt_BR)        2.3
> Portuguese, Portugal (pt_PT)      2.3
> Romanian, Romania (ro_RO)         2.3
> Serbian (sr_RS)                   2.3
> Slovak, Slovakia (sk_SK)          2.3
> Slovenian, Slovenia (sl_SI)       2.3
> Spanish, US (es_US)               2.3
> Swedish, Sweden (sv_SE)           2.3
> Tagalog, Philippines (tl_PH)      2.3
> Thai, Thailand (th_TH)            2.3
> Turkish, Turkey (tr_TR)           2.3
> Ukrainian, Ukraine (uk_UA)        2.3
> Vietnamese, Vietnam (vi_VN)       2.3
> ```
>
> ***Note that Java uses several deprecated two-letter codes. The Hebrew (“he”) >language code is rewritten as “iw”, Indonesian (“id”) as “in”, and Yiddish (“yi”) as “ji”. This rewriting happens even if you construct your own Locale object, not just for instances returned by the various lookup methods. See also https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36908826.**

Comment: Source link appears to be dead

Comment: Via archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20120814113314/http://colincooper.net/blog/2011/02/17/android-supported-language-and-locales/

Comment: Is there any list, like that on developer.android.com?

Comment: The correct format for Android resource folder is not e.g. values-pt_PT but values-pt-rPT. Replace "_" by "-r". I had compilation error and finally looked at Android 4.0.1 source code to see the correct folder name.

Comment: In fact, this is a mess. For example, spanish is not supported with "values-es" directory as it should (ISO-639-1 code is "es"), not even "value-es_ES". It only works with "values-sp" directory (and maybe other fancy forms based on "sp" code). My testing device is under Android 4.0.4, it may be fixed by now, but that is far later than 1.5 where support is expected with ISO-639-1 (or even BCP-47 by the way).

Comment: don't support "fa" or "ar" for TextToSpeech class!
Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 110):

List of locales supported as of API 22 (Android 5.1). Obtained from a Nexus 5 with locale set to "English (United States)" (locale affects the DisplayName output).

```
for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    Log.d("LOCALES", locale.getLanguage() + "_" + locale.getCountry() + " [" + locale.getDisplayName() + "]");
}


    af_ [Afrikaans]
    af_NA [Afrikaans (Namibia)]
    af_ZA [Afrikaans (South Africa)]
    agq_ [Aghem]
    agq_CM [Aghem (Cameroon)]
    ak_ [Akan]
    ak_GH [Akan (Ghana)]
    am_ [Amharic]
    am_ET [Amharic (Ethiopia)]
    ar_ [Arabic]
    ar_001 [Arabic (World)]
    ar_AE [Arabic (United Arab Emirates)]
    ar_BH [Arabic (Bahrain)]
    ar_DJ [Arabic (Djibouti)]
    ar_DZ [Arabic (Algeria)]
    ar_EG [Arabic (Egypt)]
    ar_EH [Arabic (Western Sahara)]
    ar_ER [Arabic (Eritrea)]
    ar_IL [Arabic (Israel)]
    ar_IQ [Arabic (Iraq)]
    ar_JO [Arabic (Jordan)]
    ar_KM [Arabic (Comoros)]
    ar_KW [Arabic (Kuwait)]
    ar_LB [Arabic (Lebanon)]
    ar_LY [Arabic (Libya)]
    ar_MA [Arabic (Morocco)]
    ar_MR [Arabic (Mauritania)]
    ar_OM [Arabic (Oman)]
    ar_PS [Arabic (Palestine)]
    ar_QA [Arabic (Qatar)]
    ar_SA [Arabic (Saudi Arabia)]
    ar_SD [Arabic (Sudan)]
    ar_SO [Arabic (Somalia)]
    ar_SS [Arabic (South Sudan)]
    ar_SY [Arabic (Syria)]
    ar_TD [Arabic (Chad)]
    ar_TN [Arabic (Tunisia)]
    ar_YE [Arabic (Yemen)]
    as_ [Assamese]
    as_IN [Assamese (India)]
    asa_ [Asu]
    asa_TZ [Asu (Tanzania)]
    az_ [Azerbaijani]
    az_ [Azerbaijani (Cyrillic)]
    az_AZ [Azerbaijani (Cyrillic,Azerbaijan)]
    az_ [Azerbaijani (Latin)]
    az_AZ [Azerbaijani (Latin,Azerbaijan)]
    bas_ [Basaa]
    bas_CM [Basaa (Cameroon)]
    be_ [Belarusian]
    be_BY [Belarusian (Belarus)]
    bem_ [Bemba]
    bem_ZM [Bemba (Zambia)]
    bez_ [Bena]
    bez_TZ [Bena (Tanzania)]
    bg_ [Bulgarian]
    bg_BG [Bulgarian (Bulgaria)]
    bm_ [Bambara]
    bm_ML [Bambara (Mali)]
    bn_ [Bengali]
    bn_BD [Bengali (Bangladesh)]
    bn_IN [Bengali (India)]
    bo_ [Tibetan]
    bo_CN [Tibetan (China)]
    bo_IN [Tibetan (India)]
    br_ [Breton]
    br_FR [Breton (France)]
    brx_ [Bodo]
    brx_IN [Bodo (India)]
    bs_ [Bosnian]
    bs_ [Bosnian (Cyrillic)]
    bs_BA [Bosnian (Cyrillic,Bosnia and Herzegovina)]
    bs_ [Bosnian (Latin)]
    bs_BA [Bosnian (Latin,Bosnia and Herzegovina)]
    ca_ [Catalan]
    ca_AD [Catalan (Andorra)]
    ca_ES [Catalan (Spain)]
    ca_FR [Catalan (France)]
    ca_IT [Catalan (Italy)]
    cgg_ [Chiga]
    cgg_UG [Chiga (Uganda)]
    chr_ [Cherokee]
    chr_US [Cherokee (United States)]
    cs_ [Czech]
    cs_CZ [Czech (Czech Republic)]
    cy_ [Welsh]
    cy_GB [Welsh (United Kingdom)]
    da_ [Danish]
    da_DK [Danish (Denmark)]
    da_GL [Danish (Greenland)]
    dav_ [Taita]
    dav_KE [Taita (Kenya)]
    de_ [German]
    de_AT [German (Austria)]
    de_BE [German (Belgium)]
    de_CH [German (Switzerland)]
    de_DE [German (Germany)]
    de_LI [German (Liechtenstein)]
    de_LU [German (Luxembourg)]
    dje_ [Zarma]
    dje_NE [Zarma (Niger)]
    dua_ [Duala]
    dua_CM [Duala (Cameroon)]
    dyo_ [Jola-Fonyi]
    dyo_SN [Jola-Fonyi (Senegal)]
    dz_ [Dzongkha]
    dz_BT [Dzongkha (Bhutan)]
    ebu_ [Embu]
    ebu_KE [Embu (Kenya)]
    ee_ [Ewe]
    ee_GH [Ewe (Ghana)]
    ee_TG [Ewe (Togo)]
    el_ [Greek]
    el_CY [Greek (Cyprus)]
    el_GR [Greek (Greece)]
    en_ [English]
    en_001 [English (World)]
    en_150 [English (Europe)]
    en_AG [English (Antigua and Barbuda)]
    en_AI [English (Anguilla)]
    en_AS [English (American Samoa)]
    en_AU [English (Australia)]
    en_BB [English (Barbados)]
    en_BE [English (Belgium)]
    en_BM [English (Bermuda)]
    en_BS [English (Bahamas)]
    en_BW [English (Botswana)]
    en_BZ [English (Belize)]
    en_CA [English (Canada)]
    en_CC [English (Cocos (Keeling) Islands)]
    en_CK [English (Cook Islands)]
    en_CM [English (Cameroon)]
    en_CX [English (Christmas Island)]
    en_DG [English (Diego Garcia)]
    en_DM [English (Dominica)]
    en_ER [English (Eritrea)]
    en_FJ [English (Fiji)]
    en_FK [English (Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas))]
    en_FM [English (Micronesia)]
    en_GB [English (United Kingdom)]
    en_GD [English (Grenada)]
    en_GG [English (Guernsey)]
    en_GH [English (Ghana)]
    en_GI [English (Gibraltar)]
    en_GM [English (Gambia)]
    en_GU [English (Guam)]
    en_GY [English (Guyana)]
    en_HK [English (Hong Kong)]
    en_IE [English (Ireland)]
    en_IM [English (Isle of Man)]
    en_IN [English (India)]
    en_IO [English (British Indian Ocean Territory)]
    en_JE [English (Jersey)]
    en_JM [English (Jamaica)]
    en_KE [English (Kenya)]
    en_KI [English (Kiribati)]
    en_KN [English (Saint Kitts and Nevis)]
    en_KY [English (Cayman Islands)]
    en_LC [English (Saint Lucia)]
    en_LR [English (Liberia)]
    en_LS [English (Lesotho)]
    en_MG [English (Madagascar)]
    en_MH [English (Marshall Islands)]
    en_MO [English (Macau)]
    en_MP [English (Northern Mariana Islands)]
    en_MS [English (Montserrat)]
    en_MT [English (Malta)]
    en_MU [English (Mauritius)]
    en_MW [English (Malawi)]
    en_NA [English (Namibia)]
    en_NF [English (Norfolk Island)]
    en_NG [English (Nigeria)]
    en_NR [English (Nauru)]
    en_NU [English (Niue)]
    en_NZ [English (New Zealand)]
    en_PG [English (Papua New Guinea)]
    en_PH [English (Philippines)]
    en_PK [English (Pakistan)]
    en_PN [English (Pitcairn Islands)]
    en_PR [English (Puerto Rico)]
    en_PW [English (Palau)]
    en_RW [English (Rwanda)]
    en_SB [English (Solomon Islands)]
    en_SC [English (Seychelles)]
    en_SD [English (Sudan)]
    en_SG [English (Singapore)]
    en_SH [English (Saint Helena)]
    en_SL [English (Sierra Leone)]
    en_SS [English (South Sudan)]
    en_SX [English (Sint Maarten)]
    en_SZ [English (Swaziland)]
    en_TC [English (Turks and Caicos Islands)]
    en_TK [English (Tokelau)]
    en_TO [English (Tonga)]
    en_TT [English (Trinidad and Tobago)]
    en_TV [English (Tuvalu)]
    en_TZ [English (Tanzania)]
    en_UG [English (Uganda)]
    en_UM [English (U.S. Outlying Islands)]
    en_US [English (United States)]
    en_US [English (United States,Computer)]
    en_VC [English (St. Vincent & Grenadines)]
    en_VG [English (British Virgin Islands)]
    en_VI [English (U.S. Virgin Islands)]
    en_VU [English (Vanuatu)]
    en_WS [English (Samoa)]
    en_ZA [English (South Africa)]
    en_ZM [English (Zambia)]
    en_ZW [English (Zimbabwe)]
    eo_ [Esperanto]
    es_ [Spanish]
    es_419 [Spanish (Latin America)]
    es_AR [Spanish (Argentina)]
    es_BO [Spanish (Bolivia)]
    es_CL [Spanish (Chile)]
    es_CO [Spanish (Colombia)]
    es_CR [Spanish (Costa Rica)]
    es_CU [Spanish (Cuba)]
    es_DO [Spanish (Dominican Republic)]
    es_EA [Spanish (Ceuta and Melilla)]
    es_EC [Spanish (Ecuador)]
    es_ES [Spanish (Spain)]
    es_GQ [Spanish (Equatorial Guinea)]
    es_GT [Spanish (Guatemala)]
    es_HN [Spanish (Honduras)]
    es_IC [Spanish (Canary Islands)]
    es_MX [Spanish (Mexico)]
    es_NI [Spanish (Nicaragua)]
    es_PA [Spanish (Panama)]
    es_PE [Spanish (Peru)]
    es_PH [Spanish (Philippines)]
    es_PR [Spanish (Puerto Rico)]
    es_PY [Spanish (Paraguay)]
    es_SV [Spanish (El Salvador)]
    es_US [Spanish (United States)]
    es_UY [Spanish (Uruguay)]
    es_VE [Spanish (Venezuela)]
    et_ [Estonian]
    et_EE [Estonian (Estonia)]
    eu_ [Basque]
    eu_ES [Basque (Spain)]
    ewo_ [Ewondo]
    ewo_CM [Ewondo (Cameroon)]
    fa_ [Persian]
    fa_AF [Persian (Afghanistan)]
    fa_IR [Persian (Iran)]
    ff_ [Fulah]
    ff_SN [Fulah (Senegal)]
    fi_ [Finnish]
    fi_FI [Finnish (Finland)]
    fil_ [Filipino]
    fil_PH [Filipino (Philippines)]
    fo_ [Faroese]
    fo_FO [Faroese (Faroe Islands)]
    fr_ [French]
    fr_BE [French (Belgium)]
    fr_BF [French (Burkina Faso)]
    fr_BI [French (Burundi)]
    fr_BJ [French (Benin)]
    fr_BL [French (Saint Barthélemy)]
    fr_CA [French (Canada)]
    fr_CD [French (Congo (DRC))]
    fr_CF [French (Central African Republic)]
    fr_CG [French (Congo (Republic))]
    fr_CH [French (Switzerland)]
    fr_CI [French (Côte d’Ivoire)]
    fr_CM [French (Cameroon)]
    fr_DJ [French (Djibouti)]
    fr_DZ [French (Algeria)]
    fr_FR [French (France)]
    fr_GA [French (Gabon)]
    fr_GF [French (French Guiana)]
    fr_GN [French (Guinea)]
    fr_GP [French (Guadeloupe)]
    fr_GQ [French (Equatorial Guinea)]
    fr_HT [French (Haiti)]
    fr_KM [French (Comoros)]
    fr_LU [French (Luxembourg)]
    fr_MA [French (Morocco)]
    fr_MC [French (Monaco)]
    fr_MF [French (Saint Martin)]
    fr_MG [French (Madagascar)]
    fr_ML [French (Mali)]
    fr_MQ [French (Martinique)]
    fr_MR [French (Mauritania)]
    fr_MU [French (Mauritius)]
    fr_NC [French (New Caledonia)]
    fr_NE [French (Niger)]
    fr_PF [French (French Polynesia)]
    fr_PM [French (Saint Pierre and Miquelon)]
    fr_RE [French (Réunion)]
    fr_RW [French (Rwanda)]
    fr_SC [French (Seychelles)]
    fr_SN [French (Senegal)]
    fr_SY [French (Syria)]
    fr_TD [French (Chad)]
    fr_TG [French (Togo)]
    fr_TN [French (Tunisia)]
    fr_VU [French (Vanuatu)]
    fr_WF [French (Wallis and Futuna)]
    fr_YT [French (Mayotte)]
    ga_ [Irish]
    ga_IE [Irish (Ireland)]
    gl_ [Galician]
    gl_ES [Galician (Spain)]
    gsw_ [Swiss German]
    gsw_CH [Swiss German (Switzerland)]
    gsw_LI [Swiss German (Liechtenstein)]
    gu_ [Gujarati]
    gu_IN [Gujarati (India)]
    guz_ [Gusii]
    guz_KE [Gusii (Kenya)]
    gv_ [Manx]
    gv_IM [Manx (Isle of Man)]
    ha_ [Hausa]
    ha_ [Hausa (Latin)]
    ha_GH [Hausa (Latin,Ghana)]
    ha_NE [Hausa (Latin,Niger)]
    ha_NG [Hausa (Latin,Nigeria)]
    haw_ [Hawaiian]
    haw_US [Hawaiian (United States)]
    iw_ [Hebrew]
    iw_IL [Hebrew (Israel)]
    hi_ [Hindi]
    hi_IN [Hindi (India)]
    hr_ [Croatian]
    hr_BA [Croatian (Bosnia and Herzegovina)]
    hr_HR [Croatian (Croatia)]
    hu_ [Hungarian]
    hu_HU [Hungarian (Hungary)]
    hy_ [Armenian]
    hy_AM [Armenian (Armenia)]
    in_ [Indonesian]
    in_ID [Indonesian (Indonesia)]
    ig_ [Igbo]
    ig_NG [Igbo (Nigeria)]
    ii_ [Sichuan Yi]
    ii_CN [Sichuan Yi (China)]
    is_ [Icelandic]
    is_IS [Icelandic (Iceland)]
    it_ [Italian]
    it_CH [Italian (Switzerland)]
    it_IT [Italian (Italy)]
    it_SM [Italian (San Marino)]
    ja_ [Japanese]
    ja_JP [Japanese (Japan)]
    jgo_ [Ngomba]
    jgo_CM [Ngomba (Cameroon)]
    jmc_ [Machame]
    jmc_TZ [Machame (Tanzania)]
    ka_ [Georgian]
    ka_GE [Georgian (Georgia)]
    kab_ [Kabyle]
    kab_DZ [Kabyle (Algeria)]
    kam_ [Kamba]
    kam_KE [Kamba (Kenya)]
    kde_ [Makonde]
    kde_TZ [Makonde (Tanzania)]
    kea_ [Kabuverdianu]
    kea_CV [Kabuverdianu (Cape Verde)]
    khq_ [Koyra Chiini]
    khq_ML [Koyra Chiini (Mali)]
    ki_ [Kikuyu]
    ki_KE [Kikuyu (Kenya)]
    kk_ [Kazakh]
    kk_ [Kazakh (Cyrillic)]
    kk_KZ [Kazakh (Cyrillic,Kazakhstan)]
    kkj_ [Kako]
    kkj_CM [Kako (Cameroon)]
    kl_ [Kalaallisut]
    kl_GL [Kalaallisut (Greenland)]
    kln_ [Kalenjin]
    kln_KE [Kalenjin (Kenya)]
    km_ [Khmer]
    km_KH [Khmer (Cambodia)]
    kn_ [Kannada]
    kn_IN [Kannada (India)]
    ko_ [Korean]
    ko_KP [Korean (North Korea)]
    ko_KR [Korean (South Korea)]
    kok_ [Konkani]
    kok_IN [Konkani (India)]
    ks_ [Kashmiri]
    ks_ [Kashmiri (Arabic)]
    ks_IN [Kashmiri (Arabic,India)]
    ksb_ [Shambala]
    ksb_TZ [Shambala (Tanzania)]
    ksf_ [Bafia]
    ksf_CM [Bafia (Cameroon)]
    kw_ [Cornish]
    kw_GB [Cornish (United Kingdom)]
    ky_ [Kyrgyz]
    ky_ [Kyrgyz (Cyrillic)]
    ky_KG [Kyrgyz (Cyrillic,Kyrgyzstan)]
    lag_ [Langi]
    lag_TZ [Langi (Tanzania)]
    lg_ [Ganda]
    lg_UG [Ganda (Uganda)]
    lkt_ [Lakota]
    lkt_US [Lakota (United States)]
    ln_ [Lingala]
    ln_AO [Lingala (Angola)]
    ln_CD [Lingala (Congo (DRC))]
    ln_CF [Lingala (Central African Republic)]
    ln_CG [Lingala (Congo (Republic))]
    lo_ [Lao]
    lo_LA [Lao (Laos)]
    lt_ [Lithuanian]
    lt_LT [Lithuanian (Lithuania)]
    lu_ [Luba-Katanga]
    lu_CD [Luba-Katanga (Congo (DRC))]
    luo_ [Luo]
    luo_KE [Luo (Kenya)]
    luy_ [Luyia]
    luy_KE [Luyia (Kenya)]
    lv_ [Latvian]
    lv_LV [Latvian (Latvia)]
    mas_ [Masai]
    mas_KE [Masai (Kenya)]
    mas_TZ [Masai (Tanzania)]
    mer_ [Meru]
    mer_KE [Meru (Kenya)]
    mfe_ [Morisyen]
    mfe_MU [Morisyen (Mauritius)]
    mg_ [Malagasy]
    mg_MG [Malagasy (Madagascar)]
    mgh_ [Makhuwa-Meetto]
    mgh_MZ [Makhuwa-Meetto (Mozambique)]
    mgo_ [Meta']
    mgo_CM [Meta' (Cameroon)]
    mk_ [Macedonian]
    mk_MK [Macedonian (Macedonia (FYROM))]
    ml_ [Malayalam]
    ml_IN [Malayalam (India)]
    mn_ [Mongolian]
    mn_ [Mongolian (Cyrillic)]
    mn_MN [Mongolian (Cyrillic,Mongolia)]
    mr_ [Marathi]
    mr_IN [Marathi (India)]
    ms_ [Malay]
    ms_ [Malay (Latin)]
    ms_BN [Malay (Latin,Brunei)]
    ms_MY [Malay (Latin,Malaysia)]
    ms_SG [Malay (Latin,Singapore)]
    mt_ [Maltese]
    mt_MT [Maltese (Malta)]
    mua_ [Mundang]
    mua_CM [Mundang (Cameroon)]
    my_ [Burmese]
    my_MM [Burmese (Myanmar (Burma))]
    naq_ [Nama]
    naq_NA [Nama (Namibia)]
    nb_ [Norwegian Bokmål]
    nb_NO [Norwegian Bokmål (Norway)]
    nb_SJ [Norwegian Bokmål (Svalbard and Jan Mayen)]
    nd_ [North Ndebele]
    nd_ZW [North Ndebele (Zimbabwe)]
    ne_ [Nepali]
    ne_IN [Nepali (India)]
    ne_NP [Nepali (Nepal)]
    nl_ [Dutch]
    nl_AW [Dutch (Aruba)]
    nl_BE [Dutch (Belgium)]
    nl_BQ [Dutch (Caribbean Netherlands)]
    nl_CW [Dutch (Curaçao)]
    nl_NL [Dutch (Netherlands)]
    nl_SR [Dutch (Suriname)]
    nl_SX [Dutch (Sint Maarten)]
    nmg_ [Kwasio]
    nmg_CM [Kwasio (Cameroon)]
    nn_ [Norwegian Nynorsk]
    nn_NO [Norwegian Nynorsk (Norway)]
    nnh_ [Ngiemboon]
    nnh_CM [Ngiemboon (Cameroon)]
    nus_ [Nuer]
    nus_SD [Nuer (Sudan)]
    nyn_ [Nyankole]
    nyn_UG [Nyankole (Uganda)]
    om_ [Oromo]
    om_ET [Oromo (Ethiopia)]
    om_KE [Oromo (Kenya)]
    or_ [Oriya]
    or_IN [Oriya (India)]
    pa_ [Punjabi]
    pa_ [Punjabi (Arabic)]
    pa_PK [Punjabi (Arabic,Pakistan)]
    pa_ [Punjabi (Gurmukhi)]
    pa_IN [Punjabi (Gurmukhi,India)]
    pl_ [Polish]
    pl_PL [Polish (Poland)]
    ps_ [Pashto]
    ps_AF [Pashto (Afghanistan)]
    pt_ [Portuguese]
    pt_AO [Portuguese (Angola)]
    pt_BR [Portuguese (Brazil)]
    pt_CV [Portuguese (Cape Verde)]
    pt_GW [Portuguese (Guinea-Bissau)]
    pt_MO [Portuguese (Macau)]
    pt_MZ [Portuguese (Mozambique)]
    pt_PT [Portuguese (Portugal)]
    pt_ST [Portuguese (São Tomé and Príncipe)]
    pt_TL [Portuguese (Timor-Leste)]
    rm_ [Romansh]
    rm_CH [Romansh (Switzerland)]
    rn_ [Rundi]
    rn_BI [Rundi (Burundi)]
    ro_ [Romanian]
    ro_MD [Romanian (Moldova)]
    ro_RO [Romanian (Romania)]
    rof_ [Rombo]
    rof_TZ [Rombo (Tanzania)]
    ru_ [Russian]
    ru_BY [Russian (Belarus)]
    ru_KG [Russian (Kyrgyzstan)]
    ru_KZ [Russian (Kazakhstan)]
    ru_MD [Russian (Moldova)]
    ru_RU [Russian (Russia)]
    ru_UA [Russian (Ukraine)]
    rw_ [Kinyarwanda]
    rw_RW [Kinyarwanda (Rwanda)]
    rwk_ [Rwa]
    rwk_TZ [Rwa (Tanzania)]
    saq_ [Samburu]
    saq_KE [Samburu (Kenya)]
    sbp_ [Sangu]
    sbp_TZ [Sangu (Tanzania)]
    seh_ [Sena]
    seh_MZ [Sena (Mozambique)]
    ses_ [Koyraboro Senni]
    ses_ML [Koyraboro Senni (Mali)]
    sg_ [Sango]
    sg_CF [Sango (Central African Republic)]
    shi_ [Tachelhit]
    shi_ [Tachelhit (Latin)]
    shi_MA [Tachelhit (Latin,Morocco)]
    shi_ [Tachelhit (Tifinagh)]
    shi_MA [Tachelhit (Tifinagh,Morocco)]
    si_ [Sinhala]
    si_LK [Sinhala (Sri Lanka)]
    sk_ [Slovak]
    sk_SK [Slovak (Slovakia)]
    sl_ [Slovenian]
    sl_SI [Slovenian (Slovenia)]
    sn_ [Shona]
    sn_ZW [Shona (Zimbabwe)]
    so_ [Somali]
    so_DJ [Somali (Djibouti)]
    so_ET [Somali (Ethiopia)]
    so_KE [Somali (Kenya)]
    so_SO [Somali (Somalia)]
    sq_ [Albanian]
    sq_AL [Albanian (Albania)]
    sq_MK [Albanian (Macedonia (FYROM))]
    sq_XK [Albanian (Kosovo)]
    sr_ [Serbian]
    sr_ [Serbian (Cyrillic)]
    sr_BA [Serbian (Cyrillic,Bosnia and Herzegovina)]
    sr_ME [Serbian (Cyrillic,Montenegro)]
    sr_RS [Serbian (Cyrillic,Serbia)]
    sr_XK [Serbian (Cyrillic,Kosovo)]
    sr_ [Serbian (Latin)]
    sr_BA [Serbian (Latin,Bosnia and Herzegovina)]
    sr_ME [Serbian (Latin,Montenegro)]
    sr_RS [Serbian (Latin,Serbia)]
    sr_XK [Serbian (Latin,Kosovo)]
    sv_ [Swedish]
    sv_AX [Swedish (Åland Islands)]
    sv_FI [Swedish (Finland)]
    sv_SE [Swedish (Sweden)]
    sw_ [Swahili]
    sw_KE [Swahili (Kenya)]
    sw_TZ [Swahili (Tanzania)]
    sw_UG [Swahili (Uganda)]
    swc_ [Congo Swahili]
    swc_CD [Congo Swahili (Congo (DRC))]
    ta_ [Tamil]
    ta_IN [Tamil (India)]
    ta_LK [Tamil (Sri Lanka)]
    ta_MY [Tamil (Malaysia)]
    ta_SG [Tamil (Singapore)]
    te_ [Telugu]
    te_IN [Telugu (India)]
    teo_ [Teso]
    teo_KE [Teso (Kenya)]
    teo_UG [Teso (Uganda)]
    th_ [Thai]
    th_TH [Thai (Thailand)]
    ti_ [Tigrinya]
    ti_ER [Tigrinya (Eritrea)]
    ti_ET [Tigrinya (Ethiopia)]
    to_ [Tongan]
    to_TO [Tongan (Tonga)]
    tr_ [Turkish]
    tr_CY [Turkish (Cyprus)]
    tr_TR [Turkish (Turkey)]
    twq_ [Tasawaq]
    twq_NE [Tasawaq (Niger)]
    tzm_ [Central Atlas Tamazight]
    tzm_ [Central Atlas Tamazight (Latin)]
    tzm_MA [Central Atlas Tamazight (Latin,Morocco)]
    ug_ [Uyghur]
    ug_ [Uyghur (Arabic)]
    ug_CN [Uyghur (Arabic,China)]
    uk_ [Ukrainian]
    uk_UA [Ukrainian (Ukraine)]
    ur_ [Urdu]
    ur_IN [Urdu (India)]
    ur_PK [Urdu (Pakistan)]
    uz_ [Uzbek]
    uz_ [Uzbek (Arabic)]
    uz_AF [Uzbek (Arabic,Afghanistan)]
    uz_ [Uzbek (Cyrillic)]
    uz_UZ [Uzbek (Cyrillic,Uzbekistan)]
    uz_ [Uzbek (Latin)]
    uz_UZ [Uzbek (Latin,Uzbekistan)]
    vai_ [Vai]
    vai_ [Vai (Latin)]
    vai_LR [Vai (Latin,Liberia)]
    vai_ [Vai (Vai)]
    vai_LR [Vai (Vai,Liberia)]
    vi_ [Vietnamese]
    vi_VN [Vietnamese (Vietnam)]
    vun_ [Vunjo]
    vun_TZ [Vunjo (Tanzania)]
    xog_ [Soga]
    xog_UG [Soga (Uganda)]
    yav_ [Yangben]
    yav_CM [Yangben (Cameroon)]
    yo_ [Yoruba]
    yo_BJ [Yoruba (Benin)]
    yo_NG [Yoruba (Nigeria)]
    zgh_ [Standard Moroccan Tamazight]
    zgh_MA [Standard Moroccan Tamazight (Morocco)]
    zh_ [Chinese]
    zh_ [Chinese (Simplified Han)]
    zh_CN [Chinese (Simplified Han,China)]
    zh_HK [Chinese (Simplified Han,Hong Kong)]
    zh_MO [Chinese (Simplified Han,Macau)]
    zh_SG [Chinese (Simplified Han,Singapore)]
    zh_ [Chinese (Traditional Han)]
    zh_HK [Chinese (Traditional Han,Hong Kong)]
    zh_MO [Chinese (Traditional Han,Macau)]
    zh_TW [Chinese (Traditional Han,Taiwan)]
    zu_ [Zulu]
    zu_ZA [Zulu (South Africa)]
```

Comment: This list is incorrect, as the codes are missing script subtags, there are duplicates, and the codes contain underscores where they shouldn't. Could you correct it?

Answer (score 64):

The best way to see the supported list is to start up the emulator in the latest version and open the "Custom Locale" app.  This will list all of the supported languages and locales for that version of Android.

[image: Custom Locale App]

Answer (score 44):

Update for 4.0

Android 4.0.3 Platform

```
Arabic, Egypt (ar_EG)
Arabic, Israel (ar_IL)
Bulgarian, Bulgaria (bg_BG)
Catalan, Spain (ca_ES)
Chinese, PRC (zh_CN)
Chinese, Taiwan (zh_TW)
Croatian, Croatia (hr_HR)
Czech, Czech Republic (cs_CZ)
Danish, Denmark(da_DK)
Dutch, Belgium (nl_BE)
Dutch, Netherlands (nl_NL)
English, Australia (en_AU)
English, Britain (en_GB)
English, Canada (en_CA)
English, India (en_IN)
English, Ireland (en_IE)
English, New Zealand (en_NZ)
English, Singapore(en_SG)
English, South Africa (en_ZA)
English, US (en_US)
Finnish, Finland (fi_FI)
French, Belgium (fr_BE)
French, Canada (fr_CA)
French, France (fr_FR)
French, Switzerland (fr_CH)
German, Austria (de_AT)
German, Germany (de_DE)
German, Liechtenstein (de_LI)
German, Switzerland (de_CH)
Greek, Greece (el_GR)
Hebrew, Israel (he_IL)
Hindi, India (hi_IN)
Hungarian, Hungary (hu_HU)
Indonesian, Indonesia (id_ID)
Italian, Italy (it_IT)
Italian, Switzerland (it_CH)
Japanese (ja_JP)
Korean (ko_KR)
Latvian, Latvia (lv_LV)
Lithuanian, Lithuania (lt_LT)
Norwegian bokmÃ¥l, Norway (nb_NO)
Polish (pl_PL)
Portuguese, Brazil (pt_BR)
Portuguese, Portugal (pt_PT)
Romanian, Romania (ro_RO)
Russian (ru_RU)
Serbian (sr_RS)
Slovak, Slovakia (sk_SK)
Slovenian, Slovenia (sl_SI)
Spanish (es_ES)
Spanish, US (es_US)
Swedish, Sweden (sv_SE)
Tagalog, Philippines (tl_PH)
Thai, Thailand (th_TH)
Turkish, Turkey (tr_TR)
Ukrainian, Ukraine (uk_UA)
Vietnamese, Vietnam (vi_VN)
```

SOURCE: http://us.dinodirect.com/Forum/Latest-Posts-5/Android-Versions-and-their-Locales-1-86587/

Comment: values-zh-rTW, on the other hand, compiles and works correctly :)

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes, Java uses iw, a deprecated code. Same with Yiddish (uses "ji" instead of "yi") and Indonesian (uses "in" instead of "id") 

(Source: http://www.wilsonmar.com/android_localization.htm#Localez)

Comment: @Jose_GD I thought it's the opposite - that "he" is the deprecated one. Are you sure about it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes, I recently took a look at the Google Calendar app's source code, translated to 44 languages. I've seen hebrew inside res/values-iw/strings.xml. Also there you can find a values-in folder (and not values-id)

Comment: @Jose_GD I don't understand. Which one is the deprecated one? "he" or "iw" ? if it's "iw", how come Google Calendar uses it? According to my experience, "iw" is more popular and only old carriers' roms use "he" . Maybe this is the reason: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3639

Comment: @androiddeveloper that's right, the reason is Google follows Java standard regarding this. Java uses the deprecated codes, so does Android.
From the issue you mentioned (it seems a response from somebody at Google):

*you're correct that it's not a _language_ issue, but it is a _library_ issue. Sun's libraries have this behavior, so, for 
compatibility, we do too.
if you look at the code for creating a Locale, you'll see we explicitly mangle "he" to "iw" for compatibility. a 
couple of other country codes receive the same treatment.*

Comment: I've just noticed this is in the official docs, too: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html. 3rd paragraph: *Note that Java uses several deprecated two-letter codes...*

Comment: @Jose_GD well I was sure it was the opposite. Why was it changed from "iw" to "he" anyway? also, I don't know if it happens today, but a few years ago, in order to support hebrew, I had to put the strings into both "values-he" and "values-iw", because some devices accepted only one of them.

Answer (score 26):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

See CLDR for specific language support.

Ex : CLDR 1.8 for 2.3

http://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads/cldr-1-8

Languages:

```
Afar [Qafar];
Afrikaans;
Akan;
Albanian [shqipe];
Amharic [አማርኛ];
Arabic [‎العربية‎];
Armenian [Հայերէն];
Assamese [অসমীয়া];
Asu [Kipare];
Atsam [cch];
Azerbaijani (Arabic) [azərbaycanca (ərəb)];
Azerbaijani (Cyrillic) [Азәрбајҹан (kiril)];
Azerbaijani (Latin) [azərbaycanca (latın)];
Bambara [bamanakan];
Basque [euskara];
Belarusian [беларуская];
Bemba [Ichibemba];
Bena [Hibena];
Bengali [বাংলা];
Blin [ብሊን];
Bosnian [Bosanski];
Breton [br];
Bulgarian [български];
Burmese [ဗမာ];
Catalan [català];
Central Morocco Tamazight (Latin) [Tamaziɣt (Latn)];
Cherokee [ᏣᎳᎩ];
Chiga [Rukiga];
Colognian [ksh];
Cornish [kernewek];
Croatian [hrvatski];
Czech [čeština];
Danish [dansk];
Divehi [‎ދިވެހިބަސް‎];
Dutch [Nederlands];
Dzongkha [རྫོང་ཁ];
Embu [Kĩembu];
English (Deseret) [ ()];
English (Shavian);
Esperanto;
Estonian [eesti];
Ewe [Eʋegbe];
Faroese [føroyskt];
Filipino;
Finnish [suomi];
French [français];
Friulian [furlan];
Fulah [Pulaar];
Ga [gaa];
Galician [galego];
Ganda [Luganda];
Geez [ግዕዝኛ];
Georgian [ქართული];
German [Deutsch];
Greek [Ελληνικά];
Gujarati [ગુજરાતી];
Gusii [Ekegusii];
Hausa (Arabic) [Hausa (Arab)];
Hausa (Latin) [Hausa (Latn)];
Hawaiian [ʻōlelo Hawaiʻi];
Hebrew [‎עברית‎];
Hindi [हिन्दी];
Hungarian [magyar];
Icelandic [íslenska];
Igbo;
Indonesian [Bahasa Indonesia];
Interlingua;
Inuktitut [ᐃᓄᒃᑎᑐᑦ ᑎᑎᕋᐅᓯᖅ];
Irish [Gaeilge];
Italian [italiano];
Japanese [日本語];
Jju [kaj];
Kabuverdianu;
Kabyle [Taqbaylit];
Kalaallisut;
Kalenjin;
Kamba [Kikamba];
Kannada [ಕನ್ನಡ];
Kazakh (Cyrillic) [Қазақ (Cyrl)];
Khmer [ភាសាខ្មែរ];
Kikuyu [Gikuyu];
Kinyarwanda;
Kirghiz [Кыргыз];
Konkani [कोंकणी];
Korean [한국어];
Koro [kfo];
Koyra Chiini [Koyra ciini];
Koyraboro Senni;
Kpelle [kpe];
Kurdish (Arabic) [‎كوردی (عەرەبی)‎];
Kurdish (Latin) [‎kurdî (لاتین)‎];
Langi [Kɨlaangi];
Lao [ລາວ];
Latvian [latviešu];
Lingala [lingála];
Lithuanian [lietuvių];
Low German [Plattdüütsch];
Luo [Dholuo];
Luyia [Luluhia];
Macedonian [македонски];
Machame [Kimachame];
Makonde [Chimakonde];
Malagasy;
Malay [Bahasa Melayu];
Malayalam [മലയാളം];
Maltese [Malti];
Manx [Gaelg];
Maori [mi];
Marathi [मराठी];
Masai [Maa];
Meru [Kĩmĩrũ];
Mongolian (Cyrillic) [монгол (Cyrl)];
Mongolian (Mongolian) [монгол (Mong)];
Morisyen [kreol morisien];
Nama [Khoekhoegowab];
Nepali [नेपाली];
North Ndebele [isiNdebele];
Northern Sami [davvisámegiella];
Northern Sotho [Sesotho sa Leboa];
Norwegian [norsk];
Norwegian Bokmål [norsk bokmål];
Norwegian Nynorsk [nynorsk];
Nyanja [ny];
Nyankole [Runyankore];
Occitan;
Oriya [ଓଡ଼ିଆ];
Oromo [Oromoo];
Pashto [‎پښتو‎];
Persian [‎فارسی‎];
Polish [polski];
Portuguese [português];
Punjabi (Arabic) [‎پنجاب (العربية)‎];
Punjabi (Gurmukhi) [ਪੰਜਾਬੀ (ਗੁਰਮੁਖੀ)];
Romanian [română];
Romansh [rumantsch];
Rombo [Kihorombo];
Russian [русский];
Rwa [Kiruwa];
Saho [ssy];
Samburu [Kisampur];
Sango [Sängö];
Sanskrit [संस्कृत भाषा];
Sena;
Serbian (Cyrillic) [Српски (Ћирилица)];
Serbian (Latin) [Srpski (Latinica)];
Shambala [Kishambaa];
Shona [chiShona];
Sichuan Yi [ꆈꌠꉙ];
Sidamo [Sidaamu Afo];
Simplified Chinese [中文（简体）];
Sinhala [සිංහල];
Slovak [slovenčina];
Slovenian [slovenščina];
Soga [Olusoga];
Somali [Soomaali];
South Ndebele [isiNdebele];
Southern Sotho [Sesotho];
Spanish [español];
Swahili [Kenya];
Swati [Siswati];
Swedish [svenska];
Swiss German [Schwiizertüütsch];
Syriac [‎ܣܘܪܝܝܐ‎];
Tachelhit (Latin) [tamazight (Latn)];
Tachelhit (Tifinagh) [ⵜⴰⵎⴰⵣⵉⵖⵜ (Tfng)];
Tagalog;
Taita [Kitaita];
Tajik (Cyrillic) [tg (Cyrl)];
Tamil [தமிழ்];
Taroko [trv];
Tatar [Татар];
Telugu [తెలుగు];
Teso [Kiteso];
Thai [ไทย];
Tibetan [པོད་སྐད་];
Tigre [ትግረ];
Tigrinya [ትግርኛ];
Tonga [lea fakatonga];
Traditional Chinese [繁體中文];
Tsonga [Xitsonga];
Tswana [Setswana];
Turkish [Türkçe];
Tyap [kcg];
Uighur (Arabic) [ug (Arab)];
Ukrainian [українська];
Urdu [‎اردو‎];
Uzbek (Arabic) [‎اۉزبېک (Араб)‎];
Uzbek (Cyrillic) [Ўзбек (Кирил)];
Uzbek (Latin) [o'zbekcha (Lotin)];
Venda [Tshivenḓa];
Vietnamese [Tiếng Việt];
Vunjo [Kyivunjo];
Walamo [ወላይታቱ];
Welsh [Cymraeg];
Wolof (Latin) [wo (Latn)];
Xhosa [isiXhosa];
Yoruba [Èdè Yorùbá];
Zulu [isiZulu]
```

**Locale IDs can be found in:**

http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/

**Steps to follow**

Step 1 : Need to find which all Languages supported on Android

Sol - follow my above answer ie in cldr-1-8 Languages.

Step 2 : Since cldr-1-8 Languages does  not give u Locale short form which is need to be found for desire language 
 Sol - Once language is available in cldr-1-8 Languages list then check for the shortform in http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/ link

Example :For language Hindi [हिन्दी] (1)we need to search its present in cldr-1-8 language then (2)search for Hindi in http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/ for Locale id
its comes out to be http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/hi/index.html this link and see Locale id from it .

Comment: How do you see the most recent list? And where is the locale short name (like "en" for English) in this list?

Comment: Thanks, and so Android supports handling all of them, right?

Comment: depends on cldr-1-8 listing of language, If it available in cldr-1-8 language listing then it definitely gone support. Need to cross verify is language is available in cldr-1-8 listing. :)

Comment: I don't know what it means and how to check it out.

Comment: Example if suppose u have to support Hindi language.Then search in above languages is HIndi is available if yes then search short form of Hindi in http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/ and for their u will get below link for Hindi language along with Locale Id ie short form  http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/hi-IN/index.html

Comment: so when you get to this website, how do you know if it has "cldr-1-8" language listing? and what does it mean " it definitely gone support" ? did you mean that it "has support" for it?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand.

Comment: I still don't get about step 1: what is "cldr-1-8" and in which website to look for it. Only thing I found is this: http://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads/cldr-1-8-1 , and it doesn't show a list of languages (or locales).

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/territory_language_information.html

Answer (score 26):

Following jrub post on May 4 '2015, I'm adding updated locale list.
Executed on a Nexus 6P with Android 7.0 Nougat and English US locale.

```
af_ [Afrikaans]
af_NA [Afrikaans (Namibia)]
af_ZA [Afrikaans (South Africa)]
agq_ [Aghem]
agq_CM [Aghem (Cameroon)]
ak_ [Akan]
ak_GH [Akan (Ghana)]
am_ [Amharic]
am_ET [Amharic (Ethiopia)]
ar_ [Arabic]
ar_001 [Arabic (World)]
ar_AE [Arabic (United Arab Emirates)]
ar_BH [Arabic (Bahrain)]
ar_DJ [Arabic (Djibouti)]
ar_DZ [Arabic (Algeria)]
ar_EG [Arabic (Egypt)]
ar_EH [Arabic (Western Sahara)]
ar_ER [Arabic (Eritrea)]
ar_IL [Arabic (Israel)]
ar_IQ [Arabic (Iraq)]
ar_JO [Arabic (Jordan)]
ar_KM [Arabic (Comoros)]
ar_KW [Arabic (Kuwait)]
ar_LB [Arabic (Lebanon)]
ar_LY [Arabic (Libya)]
ar_MA [Arabic (Morocco)]
ar_MR [Arabic (Mauritania)]
ar_OM [Arabic (Oman)]
ar_PS [Arabic (Palestine)]
ar_QA [Arabic (Qatar)]
ar_SA [Arabic (Saudi Arabia)]
ar_SD [Arabic (Sudan)]
ar_SO [Arabic (Somalia)]
ar_SS [Arabic (South Sudan)]
ar_SY [Arabic (Syria)]
ar_TD [Arabic (Chad)]
ar_TN [Arabic (Tunisia)]
ar_YE [Arabic (Yemen)]
as_ [Assamese]
as_IN [Assamese (India)]
asa_ [Asu]
asa_TZ [Asu (Tanzania)]
az_ [Azerbaijani (Cyrillic)]
az_ [Azerbaijani (Latin)]
az_ [Azerbaijani]
az_AZ [Azerbaijani (Cyrillic,Azerbaijan)]
az_AZ [Azerbaijani (Latin,Azerbaijan)]
bas_ [Basaa]
bas_CM [Basaa (Cameroon)]
be_ [Belarusian]
be_BY [Belarusian (Belarus)]
bem_ [Bemba]
bem_ZM [Bemba (Zambia)]
bez_ [Bena]
bez_TZ [Bena (Tanzania)]
bg_ [Bulgarian]
bg_BG [Bulgarian (Bulgaria)]
bm_ [Bambara]
bm_ML [Bambara (Mali)]
bn_ [Bengali]
bn_BD [Bengali (Bangladesh)]
bn_IN [Bengali (India)]
bo_ [Tibetan]
bo_CN [Tibetan (China)]
bo_IN [Tibetan (India)]
bqi [Luri Bakhtiari]  (suggested modification: correct code, but was not present in Android 7 yet)
br_ [Breton]
br_FR [Breton (France)]
brx_ [Bodo]
brx_IN [Bodo (India)]
bs_ [Bosnian (Cyrillic)]
bs_ [Bosnian (Latin)]
bs_ [Bosnian]
bs_BA [Bosnian (Cyrillic,Bosnia & Herzegovina)]
bs_BA [Bosnian (Latin,Bosnia & Herzegovina)]
ca_ [Catalan]
ca_AD [Catalan (Andorra)]
ca_ES [Catalan (Spain)]
ca_FR [Catalan (France)]
ca_IT [Catalan (Italy)]
ce_ [Chechen]
ce_RU [Chechen (Russia)]
cgg_ [Chiga]
cgg_UG [Chiga (Uganda)]
chr_ [Cherokee]
chr_US [Cherokee (United States)]
cs_ [Czech]
cs_CZ [Czech (Czech Republic)]
cy_ [Welsh]
cy_GB [Welsh (United Kingdom)]
da_ [Danish]
da_DK [Danish (Denmark)]
da_GL [Danish (Greenland)]
dav_ [Taita]
dav_KE [Taita (Kenya)]
de_ [German]
de_AT [German (Austria)]
de_BE [German (Belgium)]
de_CH [German (Switzerland)]
de_DE [German (Germany)]
de_LI [German (Liechtenstein)]
de_LU [German (Luxembourg)]
dje_ [Zarma]
dje_NE [Zarma (Niger)]
dsb_ [Lower Sorbian]
dsb_DE [Lower Sorbian (Germany)]
dua_ [Duala]
dua_CM [Duala (Cameroon)]
dyo_ [Jola-Fonyi]
dyo_SN [Jola-Fonyi (Senegal)]
dz_ [Dzongkha]
dz_BT [Dzongkha (Bhutan)]
ebu_ [Embu]
ebu_KE [Embu (Kenya)]
ee_ [Ewe]
ee_GH [Ewe (Ghana)]
ee_TG [Ewe (Togo)]
el_ [Greek]
el_CY [Greek (Cyprus)]
el_GR [Greek (Greece)]
en_ [English]
en_001 [English (World)]
en_150 [English (Europe)]
en_AG [English (Antigua & Barbuda)]
en_AI [English (Anguilla)]
en_AS [English (American Samoa)]
en_AT [English (Austria)]
en_AU [English (Australia)]
en_BB [English (Barbados)]
en_BE [English (Belgium)]
en_BI [English (Burundi)]
en_BM [English (Bermuda)]
en_BS [English (Bahamas)]
en_BW [English (Botswana)]
en_BZ [English (Belize)]
en_CA [English (Canada)]
en_CC [English (Cocos (Keeling) Islands)]
en_CH [English (Switzerland)]
en_CK [English (Cook Islands)]
en_CM [English (Cameroon)]
en_CX [English (Christmas Island)]
en_CY [English (Cyprus)]
en_DE [English (Germany)]
en_DG [English (Diego Garcia)]
en_DK [English (Denmark)]
en_DM [English (Dominica)]
en_ER [English (Eritrea)]
en_FI [English (Finland)]
en_FJ [English (Fiji)]
en_FK [English (Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas))]
en_FM [English (Micronesia)]
en_GB [English (United Kingdom)]
en_GD [English (Grenada)]
en_GG [English (Guernsey)]
en_GH [English (Ghana)]
en_GI [English (Gibraltar)]
en_GM [English (Gambia)]
en_GU [English (Guam)]
en_GY [English (Guyana)]
en_HK [English (Hong Kong)]
en_IE [English (Ireland)]
en_IL [English (Israel)]
en_IM [English (Isle of Man)]
en_IN [English (India)]
en_IO [English (British Indian Ocean Territory)]
en_JE [English (Jersey)]
en_JM [English (Jamaica)]
en_KE [English (Kenya)]
en_KI [English (Kiribati)]
en_KN [English (St. Kitts & Nevis)]
en_KY [English (Cayman Islands)]
en_LC [English (St. Lucia)]
en_LR [English (Liberia)]
en_LS [English (Lesotho)]
en_MG [English (Madagascar)]
en_MH [English (Marshall Islands)]
en_MO [English (Macau)]
en_MP [English (Northern Mariana Islands)]
en_MS [English (Montserrat)]
en_MT [English (Malta)]
en_MU [English (Mauritius)]
en_MW [English (Malawi)]
en_MY [English (Malaysia)]
en_NA [English (Namibia)]
en_NF [English (Norfolk Island)]
en_NG [English (Nigeria)]
en_NL [English (Netherlands)]
en_NR [English (Nauru)]
en_NU [English (Niue)]
en_NZ [English (New Zealand)]
en_PG [English (Papua New Guinea)]
en_PH [English (Philippines)]
en_PK [English (Pakistan)]
en_PN [English (Pitcairn Islands)]
en_PR [English (Puerto Rico)]
en_PW [English (Palau)]
en_RW [English (Rwanda)]
en_SB [English (Solomon Islands)]
en_SC [English (Seychelles)]
en_SD [English (Sudan)]
en_SE [English (Sweden)]
en_SG [English (Singapore)]
en_SH [English (St. Helena)]
en_SI [English (Slovenia)]
en_SL [English (Sierra Leone)]
en_SS [English (South Sudan)]
en_SX [English (Sint Maarten)]
en_SZ [English (Swaziland)]
en_TC [English (Turks & Caicos Islands)]
en_TK [English (Tokelau)]
en_TO [English (Tonga)]
en_TT [English (Trinidad & Tobago)]
en_TV [English (Tuvalu)]
en_TZ [English (Tanzania)]
en_UG [English (Uganda)]
en_UM [English (U.S. Outlying Islands)]
en_US [English (United States)]
en_US [English (United States,Computer)]
en_VC [English (St. Vincent & Grenadines)]
en_VG [English (British Virgin Islands)]
en_VI [English (U.S. Virgin Islands)]
en_VU [English (Vanuatu)]
en_WS [English (Samoa)]
en_ZA [English (South Africa)]
en_ZM [English (Zambia)]
en_ZW [English (Zimbabwe)]
eo_ [Esperanto]
es_ [Spanish]
es_419 [Spanish (Latin America)]
es_AR [Spanish (Argentina)]
es_BO [Spanish (Bolivia)]
es_CL [Spanish (Chile)]
es_CO [Spanish (Colombia)]
es_CR [Spanish (Costa Rica)]
es_CU [Spanish (Cuba)]
es_DO [Spanish (Dominican Republic)]
es_EA [Spanish (Ceuta & Melilla)]
es_EC [Spanish (Ecuador)]
es_ES [Spanish (Spain)]
es_GQ [Spanish (Equatorial Guinea)]
es_GT [Spanish (Guatemala)]
es_HN [Spanish (Honduras)]
es_IC [Spanish (Canary Islands)]
es_MX [Spanish (Mexico)]
es_NI [Spanish (Nicaragua)]
es_PA [Spanish (Panama)]
es_PE [Spanish (Peru)]
es_PH [Spanish (Philippines)]
es_PR [Spanish (Puerto Rico)]
es_PY [Spanish (Paraguay)]
es_SV [Spanish (El Salvador)]
es_US [Spanish (United States)]
es_UY [Spanish (Uruguay)]
es_VE [Spanish (Venezuela)]
et_ [Estonian]
et_EE [Estonian (Estonia)]
eu_ [Basque]
eu_ES [Basque (Spain)]
ewo_ [Ewondo]
ewo_CM [Ewondo (Cameroon)]
fa_ [Persian]
fa_AF [Persian (Afghanistan)]
fa_IR [Persian (Iran)]
ff_ [Fulah]
ff_CM [Fulah (Cameroon)]
ff_GN [Fulah (Guinea)]
ff_MR [Fulah (Mauritania)]
ff_SN [Fulah (Senegal)]
fi_ [Finnish]
fi_FI [Finnish (Finland)]
fil_ [Filipino]
fil_PH [Filipino (Philippines)]
fo_ [Faroese]
fo_DK [Faroese (Denmark)]
fo_FO [Faroese (Faroe Islands)]
fr_ [French]
fr_BE [French (Belgium)]
fr_BF [French (Burkina Faso)]
fr_BI [French (Burundi)]
fr_BJ [French (Benin)]
fr_BL [French (St. Barthélemy)]
fr_CA [French (Canada)]
fr_CD [French (Congo (DRC))]
fr_CF [French (Central African Republic)]
fr_CG [French (Congo (Republic))]
fr_CH [French (Switzerland)]
fr_CI [French (Côte d’Ivoire)]
fr_CM [French (Cameroon)]
fr_DJ [French (Djibouti)]
fr_DZ [French (Algeria)]
fr_FR [French (France)]
fr_GA [French (Gabon)]
fr_GF [French (French Guiana)]
fr_GN [French (Guinea)]
fr_GP [French (Guadeloupe)]
fr_GQ [French (Equatorial Guinea)]
fr_HT [French (Haiti)]
fr_KM [French (Comoros)]
fr_LU [French (Luxembourg)]
fr_MA [French (Morocco)]
fr_MC [French (Monaco)]
fr_MF [French (St. Martin)]
fr_MG [French (Madagascar)]
fr_ML [French (Mali)]
fr_MQ [French (Martinique)]
fr_MR [French (Mauritania)]
fr_MU [French (Mauritius)]
fr_NC [French (New Caledonia)]
fr_NE [French (Niger)]
fr_PF [French (French Polynesia)]
fr_PM [French (St. Pierre & Miquelon)]
fr_RE [French (Réunion)]
fr_RW [French (Rwanda)]
fr_SC [French (Seychelles)]
fr_SN [French (Senegal)]
fr_SY [French (Syria)]
fr_TD [French (Chad)]
fr_TG [French (Togo)]
fr_TN [French (Tunisia)]
fr_VU [French (Vanuatu)]
fr_WF [French (Wallis & Futuna)]
fr_YT [French (Mayotte)]
fur_ [Friulian]
fur_IT [Friulian (Italy)]
fy_ [Western Frisian]
fy_NL [Western Frisian (Netherlands)]
ga_ [Irish]
ga_IE [Irish (Ireland)]
gd_ [Scottish Gaelic]
gd_GB [Scottish Gaelic (United Kingdom)]
gl_ [Galician]
gl_ES [Galician (Spain)]
gsw_ [Swiss German]
gsw_CH [Swiss German (Switzerland)]
gsw_FR [Swiss German (France)]
gsw_LI [Swiss German (Liechtenstein)]
gu_ [Gujarati]
gu_IN [Gujarati (India)]
guz_ [Gusii]
guz_KE [Gusii (Kenya)]
gv_ [Manx]
gv_IM [Manx (Isle of Man)]
ha_ [Hausa]
ha_GH [Hausa (Ghana)]
ha_NE [Hausa (Niger)]
ha_NG [Hausa (Nigeria)]
haw_ [Hawaiian]
haw_US [Hawaiian (United States)]
hi_ [Hindi]
hi_IN [Hindi (India)]
hr_ [Croatian]
hr_BA [Croatian (Bosnia & Herzegovina)]
hr_HR [Croatian (Croatia)]
hsb_ [Upper Sorbian]
hsb_DE [Upper Sorbian (Germany)]
hu_ [Hungarian]
hu_HU [Hungarian (Hungary)]
hy_ [Armenian]
hy_AM [Armenian (Armenia)]
ig_ [Igbo]
ig_NG [Igbo (Nigeria)]
ii_ [Sichuan Yi]
ii_CN [Sichuan Yi (China)]
in_ [Indonesian]
in_ID [Indonesian (Indonesia)]
is_ [Icelandic]
is_IS [Icelandic (Iceland)]
it_ [Italian]
it_CH [Italian (Switzerland)]
it_IT [Italian (Italy)]
it_SM [Italian (San Marino)]
iw_ [Hebrew]
iw_IL [Hebrew (Israel)]
ja_ [Japanese]
ja_JP [Japanese (Japan)]
jgo_ [Ngomba]
jgo_CM [Ngomba (Cameroon)]
ji_ [Yiddish]
ji_001 [Yiddish (World)]
jmc_ [Machame]
jmc_TZ [Machame (Tanzania)]
ka_ [Georgian]
ka_GE [Georgian (Georgia)]
kab_ [Kabyle]
kab_DZ [Kabyle (Algeria)]
kam_ [Kamba]
kam_KE [Kamba (Kenya)]
kde_ [Makonde]
kde_TZ [Makonde (Tanzania)]
kea_ [Kabuverdianu]
kea_CV [Kabuverdianu (Cape Verde)]
khq_ [Koyra Chiini]
khq_ML [Koyra Chiini (Mali)]
ki_ [Kikuyu]
ki_KE [Kikuyu (Kenya)]
kk_ [Kazakh]
kk_KZ [Kazakh (Kazakhstan)]
kkj_ [Kako]
kkj_CM [Kako (Cameroon)]
kl_ [Kalaallisut]
kl_GL [Kalaallisut (Greenland)]
kln_ [Kalenjin]
kln_KE [Kalenjin (Kenya)]
km_ [Khmer]
km_KH [Khmer (Cambodia)]
kn_ [Kannada]
kn_IN [Kannada (India)]
ko_ [Korean]
ko_KP [Korean (North Korea)]
ko_KR [Korean (South Korea)]
kok_ [Konkani]
kok_IN [Konkani (India)]
ks_ [Kashmiri]
ks_IN [Kashmiri (India)]
ksb_ [Shambala]
ksb_TZ [Shambala (Tanzania)]
ksf_ [Bafia]
ksf_CM [Bafia (Cameroon)]
ksh_ [Colognian]
ksh_DE [Colognian (Germany)]
kw_ [Cornish]
kw_GB [Cornish (United Kingdom)]
ky_ [Kyrgyz]
ky_KG [Kyrgyz (Kyrgyzstan)]
lag_ [Langi]
lag_TZ [Langi (Tanzania)]
lb_ [Luxembourgish]
lb_LU [Luxembourgish (Luxembourg)]
lg_ [Ganda]
lg_UG [Ganda (Uganda)]
lkt_ [Lakota]
lkt_US [Lakota (United States)]
ln_ [Lingala]
ln_AO [Lingala (Angola)]
ln_CD [Lingala (Congo (DRC))]
ln_CF [Lingala (Central African Republic)]
ln_CG [Lingala (Congo (Republic))]
lo_ [Lao]
lo_LA [Lao (Laos)]
lrc_ [Northern Luri]
lrc_IQ [Northern Luri (Iraq)]
lrc_IR [Northern Luri (Iran)]
lt_ [Lithuanian]
lt_LT [Lithuanian (Lithuania)]
lu_ [Luba-Katanga]
lu_CD [Luba-Katanga (Congo (DRC))]
luo_ [Luo]
luo_KE [Luo (Kenya)]
luy_ [Luyia]
luy_KE [Luyia (Kenya)]
luz [Southern Luri]  (suggested modification: correct code, but was not present in Android 7 yet)
lv_ [Latvian]
lv_LV [Latvian (Latvia)]
mas_ [Masai]
mas_KE [Masai (Kenya)]
mas_TZ [Masai (Tanzania)]
mer_ [Meru]
mer_KE [Meru (Kenya)]
mfe_ [Morisyen]
mfe_MU [Morisyen (Mauritius)]
mg_ [Malagasy]
mg_MG [Malagasy (Madagascar)]
mgh_ [Makhuwa-Meetto]
mgh_MZ [Makhuwa-Meetto (Mozambique)]
mgo_ [Meta']
mgo_CM [Meta' (Cameroon)]
mk_ [Macedonian]
mk_MK [Macedonian (Macedonia (FYROM))]
ml_ [Malayalam]
ml_IN [Malayalam (India)]
mn_ [Mongolian]
mn_MN [Mongolian (Mongolia)]
mr_ [Marathi]
mr_IN [Marathi (India)]
ms_ [Malay]
ms_BN [Malay (Brunei)]
ms_MY [Malay (Malaysia)]
ms_SG [Malay (Singapore)]
mt_ [Maltese]
mt_MT [Maltese (Malta)]
mua_ [Mundang]
mua_CM [Mundang (Cameroon)]
my_ [Burmese]
my_MM [Burmese (Myanmar (Burma))]
mzn_ [Mazanderani]
mzn_IR [Mazanderani (Iran)]
naq_ [Nama]
naq_NA [Nama (Namibia)]
nb_ [Norwegian Bokmål]
nb_NO [Norwegian Bokmål (Norway)]
nb_SJ [Norwegian Bokmål (Svalbard & Jan Mayen)]
nd_ [North Ndebele]
nd_ZW [North Ndebele (Zimbabwe)]
ne_ [Nepali]
ne_IN [Nepali (India)]
ne_NP [Nepali (Nepal)]
nl_ [Dutch]
nl_AW [Dutch (Aruba)]
nl_BE [Dutch (Belgium)]
nl_BQ [Dutch (Caribbean Netherlands)]
nl_CW [Dutch (Curaçao)]
nl_NL [Dutch (Netherlands)]
nl_SR [Dutch (Suriname)]
nl_SX [Dutch (Sint Maarten)]
nmg_ [Kwasio]
nmg_CM [Kwasio (Cameroon)]
nn_ [Norwegian Nynorsk]
nn_NO [Norwegian Nynorsk (Norway)]
nnh_ [Ngiemboon]
nnh_CM [Ngiemboon (Cameroon)]
nus_ [Nuer]
nus_SS [Nuer (South Sudan)]
nyn_ [Nyankole]
nyn_UG [Nyankole (Uganda)]
om_ [Oromo]
om_ET [Oromo (Ethiopia)]
om_KE [Oromo (Kenya)]
or_ [Oriya]
or_IN [Oriya (India)]
os_ [Ossetic]
os_GE [Ossetic (Georgia)]
os_RU [Ossetic (Russia)]
pa_ [Punjabi (Arabic)]
pa_ [Punjabi (Gurmukhi)]
pa_ [Punjabi]
pa_IN [Punjabi (Gurmukhi,India)]
pa_PK [Punjabi (Arabic,Pakistan)]
pl_ [Polish]
pl_PL [Polish (Poland)]
ps_ [Pashto]
ps_AF [Pashto (Afghanistan)]
pt_ [Portuguese]
pt_AO [Portuguese (Angola)]
pt_BR [Portuguese (Brazil)]
pt_CV [Portuguese (Cape Verde)]
pt_GW [Portuguese (Guinea-Bissau)]
pt_MO [Portuguese (Macau)]
pt_MZ [Portuguese (Mozambique)]
pt_PT [Portuguese (Portugal)]
pt_ST [Portuguese (São Tomé & Príncipe)]
pt_TL [Portuguese (Timor-Leste)]
qu_ [Quechua]
qu_BO [Quechua (Bolivia)]
qu_EC [Quechua (Ecuador)]
qu_PE [Quechua (Peru)]
rm_ [Romansh]
rm_CH [Romansh (Switzerland)]
rn_ [Rundi]
rn_BI [Rundi (Burundi)]
ro_ [Romanian]
ro_MD [Romanian (Moldova)]
ro_RO [Romanian (Romania)]
rof_ [Rombo]
rof_TZ [Rombo (Tanzania)]
ru_ [Russian]
ru_BY [Russian (Belarus)]
ru_KG [Russian (Kyrgyzstan)]
ru_KZ [Russian (Kazakhstan)]
ru_MD [Russian (Moldova)]
ru_RU [Russian (Russia)]
ru_UA [Russian (Ukraine)]
rw_ [Kinyarwanda]
rw_RW [Kinyarwanda (Rwanda)]
rwk_ [Rwa]
rwk_TZ [Rwa (Tanzania)]
sah_ [Sakha]
sah_RU [Sakha (Russia)]
saq_ [Samburu]
saq_KE [Samburu (Kenya)]
sbp_ [Sangu]
sbp_TZ [Sangu (Tanzania)]
se_ [Northern Sami]
se_FI [Northern Sami (Finland)]
se_NO [Northern Sami (Norway)]
se_SE [Northern Sami (Sweden)]
seh_ [Sena]
seh_MZ [Sena (Mozambique)]
ses_ [Koyraboro Senni]
ses_ML [Koyraboro Senni (Mali)]
sg_ [Sango]
sg_CF [Sango (Central African Republic)]
shi_ [Tachelhit (Latin)]
shi_ [Tachelhit (Tifinagh)]
shi_ [Tachelhit]
shi_MA [Tachelhit (Latin,Morocco)]
shi_MA [Tachelhit (Tifinagh,Morocco)]
si_ [Sinhala]
si_LK [Sinhala (Sri Lanka)]
sk_ [Slovak]
sk_SK [Slovak (Slovakia)]
sl_ [Slovenian]
sl_SI [Slovenian (Slovenia)]
smn_ [Inari Sami]
smn_FI [Inari Sami (Finland)]
sn_ [Shona]
sn_ZW [Shona (Zimbabwe)]
so_ [Somali]
so_DJ [Somali (Djibouti)]
so_ET [Somali (Ethiopia)]
so_KE [Somali (Kenya)]
so_SO [Somali (Somalia)]
sq_ [Albanian]
sq_AL [Albanian (Albania)]
sq_MK [Albanian (Macedonia (FYROM))]
sq_XK [Albanian (Kosovo)]
sr_ [Serbian (Cyrillic)]
sr_ [Serbian (Latin)]
sr_ [Serbian]
sr_BA [Serbian (Cyrillic,Bosnia & Herzegovina)]
sr_BA [Serbian (Latin,Bosnia & Herzegovina)]
sr_ME [Serbian (Cyrillic,Montenegro)]
sr_ME [Serbian (Latin,Montenegro)]
sr_RS [Serbian (Cyrillic,Serbia)]
sr_RS [Serbian (Latin,Serbia)]
sr_XK [Serbian (Cyrillic,Kosovo)]
sr_XK [Serbian (Latin,Kosovo)]
sv_ [Swedish]
sv_AX [Swedish (Åland Islands)]
sv_FI [Swedish (Finland)]
sv_SE [Swedish (Sweden)]
sw_ [Swahili]
sw_CD [Swahili (Congo (DRC))]
sw_KE [Swahili (Kenya)]
sw_TZ [Swahili (Tanzania)]
sw_UG [Swahili (Uganda)]
ta_ [Tamil]
ta_IN [Tamil (India)]
ta_LK [Tamil (Sri Lanka)]
ta_MY [Tamil (Malaysia)]
ta_SG [Tamil (Singapore)]
te_ [Telugu]
te_IN [Telugu (India)]
teo_ [Teso]
teo_KE [Teso (Kenya)]
teo_UG [Teso (Uganda)]
th_ [Thai]
th_TH [Thai (Thailand)]
ti_ [Tigrinya]
ti_ER [Tigrinya (Eritrea)]
ti_ET [Tigrinya (Ethiopia)]
to_ [Tongan]
to_TO [Tongan (Tonga)]
tr_ [Turkish]
tr_CY [Turkish (Cyprus)]
tr_TR [Turkish (Turkey)]
twq_ [Tasawaq]
twq_NE [Tasawaq (Niger)]
tzm_ [Central Atlas Tamazight]
tzm_MA [Central Atlas Tamazight (Morocco)]
ug_ [Uyghur]
ug_CN [Uyghur (China)]
uk_ [Ukrainian]
uk_UA [Ukrainian (Ukraine)]
ur_ [Urdu]
ur_IN [Urdu (India)]
ur_PK [Urdu (Pakistan)]
uz_ [Uzbek (Arabic)]
uz_ [Uzbek (Cyrillic)]
uz_ [Uzbek (Latin)]
uz_ [Uzbek]
uz_AF [Uzbek (Arabic,Afghanistan)]
uz_UZ [Uzbek (Cyrillic,Uzbekistan)]
uz_UZ [Uzbek (Latin,Uzbekistan)]
vai_ [Vai (Latin)]
vai_ [Vai (Vai)]
vai_ [Vai]
vai_LR [Vai (Latin,Liberia)]
vai_LR [Vai (Vai,Liberia)]
vi_ [Vietnamese]
vi_VN [Vietnamese (Vietnam)]
vun_ [Vunjo]
vun_TZ [Vunjo (Tanzania)]
wae_ [Walser]
wae_CH [Walser (Switzerland)]
xog_ [Soga]
xog_UG [Soga (Uganda)]
yav_ [Yangben]
yav_CM [Yangben (Cameroon)]
yo_ [Yoruba]
yo_BJ [Yoruba (Benin)]
yo_NG [Yoruba (Nigeria)]
zgh_ [Standard Moroccan Tamazight]
zgh_MA [Standard Moroccan Tamazight (Morocco)]
zh_ [Chinese (Simplified Han)]
zh_ [Chinese (Traditional Han)]
zh_ [Chinese]
zh_CN [Chinese (Simplified Han,China)]
zh_HK [Chinese (Simplified Han,Hong Kong)]
zh_HK [Chinese (Traditional Han,Hong Kong)]
zh_MO [Chinese (Simplified Han,Macau)]
zh_MO [Chinese (Traditional Han,Macau)]
zh_SG [Chinese (Simplified Han,Singapore)]
zh_TW [Chinese (Traditional Han,Taiwan)]
zu_ [Zulu]
zu_ZA [Zulu (South Africa)]
```

Comment: should be noted that `iw` is not the correct code for Hebrew. The right one is `he`. But in diffrent countries there are different implementations for it. see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202406/locale-code-for-hebrew-reference-to-other-locale-codes

Answer (score 25):

I think the best way is to run a sample code to find the supported locales.
I've made a code snippet that does it:

```
final Locale[] availableLocales=Locale.getAvailableLocales();
for(final Locale locale : availableLocales)
  Log.d("Applog",":"+locale.getDisplayName()+":"+locale.getLanguage()+":"
    +locale.getCountry()+":values-"+locale.toString().replace("_","-r"));
```

the columns are : displayName (how it looks to the user), the locale, the variant, and the folder that the developer is supposed to put the strings into.

Here's a table I've made out of the 5.0.1 emulator:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hx1CTPT82qFSbzuWiU1nyGROCNM6HKssKCPhxinvdww/

Weird thing is that for some cases, I got "#" which is something I've never seen before. It's probably quite new, and the rule I've chosen is probably incorrect for those cases (though it still compiles fine when I put such folders and files), but for the rest it should be fine.

If anyone knows about what the "#" is, and how to handle it, please let me know.

Answer (score 18):

First we need to plan how the application will render differently in different locals.
Here it shows example, where the text string and images have to go.

```
de-rDE German / Germany res/values-de/ res/drawable-de-rDE/ 
fr-rFR French / France res/values-fr/ res/drawable-fr-rFR/ 
fr-rCA French / Canada res/values-fr/ res/drawable-fr-rCA/ 
en-rCA English / Canada (res/values/) res/drawable-en-rCA/ 
ja-rJP Japanese / Japan res/values-ja/ res/drawable-ja-rJP/ 
en-rUS English / United States (res/values/) res/drawable-en-rUS/
```

For more info you can see the page [Localization](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html)

Answer (score 18):

If you're using Android Studio you can:

1. **Right click** a directory on your project > **New** > **Android Resource File**
2. In the **Available qualifiers** section select **Locale** and click **>>**

You will see a list of all Languages and if you choose them you will see Specific Regions for each. You can also type in the list to filter languages.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13):

As of Android 7.0, you can read the list from the Language settings straight in the source.  You can see the Android version in the URL:

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-9.0.0_r1/core/res/res/values/locale_config.xml
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.1.0_r1/core/res/res/values/locale_config.xml
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.0.0_r1/core/res/res/values/locale_config.xml
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.1.2_r1/core/res/res/values/locale_config.xml
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.0.0_r1/core/res/res/values/locale_config.xml

The list for Google Play descriptions is different:

- https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/4419860

Answer (score 8):

I found a list, which *might* be the full list of supported locales by a given Android version (API level):
go to `Android-sdk\platforms\android-[XX]\data\res\values\` where XX means the API level, and open `locale_config.xml` with any text editor.
It's human readable and can be easily processed if needed.

Answer (score 6):

```
Arabic, Egypt (ar_EG)
Arabic, Israel (ar_IL)
Bulgarian, Bulgaria (bg_BG)
Catalan, Spain (ca_ES)
Czech, Czech Republic (cs_CZ)
Danish, Denmark(da_DK)
German, Austria (de_AT)
German, Switzerland (de_CH)
German, Germany (de_DE)
German, Liechtenstein (de_LI)
Greek, Greece (el_GR)
English, Australia (en_AU)
English, Canada (en_CA)
English, Britain (en_GB)
English, Ireland (en_IE)
English, India (en_IN)
English, New Zealand (en_NZ)
English, Singapore(en_SG)
English, US (en_US)
English, South Africa (en_ZA)
Spanish (es_ES)
Spanish, US (es_US)
Finnish, Finland (fi_FI)
French, Belgium (fr_BE)
French, Canada (fr_CA)
French, Switzerland (fr_CH)
French, France (fr_FR)
Hebrew, Israel (he_IL)
Hindi, India (hi_IN)
Croatian, Croatia (hr_HR)
Hungarian, Hungary (hu_HU)
Indonesian, Indonesia (id_ID)
Italian, Switzerland (it_CH)
Italian, Italy (it_IT)
Japanese (ja_JP)
Korean (ko_KR)
Lithuanian, Lithuania (lt_LT)
Latvian, Latvia (lv_LV)
Norwegian bokmål, Norway (nb_NO)
Dutch, Belgium (nl_BE)
Dutch, Netherlands (nl_NL)
Polish (pl_PL)
Portuguese, Brazil (pt_BR)
Portuguese, Portugal (pt_PT)
Romanian, Romania (ro_RO)
Russian (ru_RU)
Slovak, Slovakia (sk_SK)
Slovenian, Slovenia (sl_SI)
Serbian (sr_RS)
Swedish, Sweden (sv_SE)
Thai, Thailand (th_TH)
Tagalog, Philippines (tl_PH)
Turkish, Turkey (tr_TR)
Ukrainian, Ukraine (uk_UA)
Vietnamese, Vietnam (vi_VN)
Chinese, PRC (zh_CN)
Chinese, Taiwan (zh_TW)
```

Comment: Where did you get it from? is it all of the languages?

Answer (score 4):

Just FYI, if you are unable to set any locale, the problem might be below attribute in your app level gradle file:

```
resConfigs "en", "hi" //to specify allowed locales for your app
```

So, if you want to support any locale other than English and Hindi, specify your locale here or just remove above line. By default your app will support all the locales.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
public static final Locale  CANADA  Locale constant for en_CA.
public static final Locale  CANADA_FRENCH   Locale constant for fr_CA.
public static final Locale  CHINA   Locale constant for zh_CN.
public static final Locale  CHINESE Locale constant for zh.
public static final Locale  ENGLISH Locale constant for en.
public static final Locale  FRANCE  Locale constant for fr_FR.
public static final Locale  FRENCH  Locale constant for fr.
public static final Locale  GERMAN  Locale constant for de.
public static final Locale  GERMANY Locale constant for de_DE.
public static final Locale  ITALIAN Locale constant for it.
public static final Locale  ITALY   Locale constant for it_IT.
public static final Locale  JAPAN   Locale constant for ja_JP.
public static final Locale  JAPANESE    Locale constant for ja.
public static final Locale  KOREA   Locale constant for ko_KR.
public static final Locale  KOREAN  Locale constant for ko.
public static final Locale  PRC Locale constant for zh_CN.
public static final Locale  ROOT    Locale constant for the root locale.
public static final Locale  SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE  Locale constant for zh_CN.
public static final Locale  TAIWAN  Locale constant for zh_TW.
public static final Locale  TRADITIONAL_CHINESE Locale constant for zh_TW.
public static final Locale  UK  Locale constant for en_GB.
public static final Locale  US  Locale constant for en_US.
```