# How to find supporting languages in android programatically?

Tags: android, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android)

In my android application i want to get list of supporting languages by that particular device 
problematically.
Please any one tell me Is their any any way to do this

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
    Locale[] locs= Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    for(Locale l:locs){
        Log.d(tag, l.getDisplayLanguage());
    }
```