# Can I read languages supported by an android without rooting it?

Tags: android

Can I read the languages that an android device supports? I know we can read the current language, but I want to read all the languages.

Afaik, it's there in System/Fonts. But can I access it without rooting the device?

EDIT: I tried Locale on a Moto-G and it the list contains Gujarati language, that seems to be because v. 5.0.2 supports the language, but the device does not support the Gujarati font. Need to know what fonts are supported on a particular device, so that I can decide whether to render them.

Comment: `Afaik, it's there in System/Fonts` Fonts have **nothing** to do with languages. They only provide graphical representation for the characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find supporting languages in android programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406878/how-to-find-supporting-languages-in-android-programatically)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android)

Comment: @EgonWilzer  please check the edit and suggest if you have a solution. TIA! :)

Comment: @DerGol...lum That's what I think is the problem, the fonts for certain languages aren't available hence I can't render them.

Comment: This means that certain fonts don't provide the required graphics (Unicode characters). Then simply provide the fonts for the specific (natively unsupported) languages, such as Myanmar.ttf (just to name some one I can remember some user asked for).

Comment: @DerGol...lum That requires the device to be rooted, which I can't. Instead if I can just know if the font is not supported and eliminate its rendering?

Comment: `That requires the device to be rooted` NO, it doesn't. Just provide your fonts in your app `assets` folder. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me!

```
public void checkSupportedFonts() {

    mLanguageFonts = new HashMap<String, String>();

    mLanguageFonts.put("en-US", "ab");
    mLanguageFonts.put("hi-IN", "अआ");
    mLanguageFonts.put("bn-IN", "অআ");
    mLanguageFonts.put("gu-IN", "અઆ");
    mLanguageFonts.put("mr-IN", "अआ");
    mLanguageFonts.put("ta-IN", "அஆ");
    mLanguageFonts.put("te-IN", "అఆ");
    mLanguageFonts.put("kn-IN", "ಅಆ");
    mLanguageFonts.put("ml-IN", "അആ");

    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> languageIterator = mLanguageFonts.entrySet().iterator();
    while (languageIterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> pair = (Entry<String, String>)languageIterator.next();
        String font = pair.getValue().toString();

        if(isSupported(font))
            Log.d(TAG, "language is supported : " + pair.getKey());
        else
            Log.d(TAG, "language is unsupported : " + pair.getKey());
        }
}

private boolean isSupported(String text) 
{

    String char1 = text.substring(0, 1);
    text = text.substring(1, 2);
    Bitmap bitmap1 = generateBitmap(context, char1);
    Bitmap bitmap2 = generateBitmap(context, text);
    boolean res = !bitmap1.sameAs(bitmap2);
    bitmap1.recycle();
    bitmap2.recycle();
    return res;
}
```