# Is it possible to use the same string resource file for multiple languages?

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

In my Android application I need to implement localization. Is it possible to provide the same string file for all languages (for example, Chinese, French, Japan, Urdu,..)? If not, how can I create values folder names of strings for different languages?

Comment: And the answer for the part where you want to create folder names can be fetched from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android

Answer (score 1):

`res/values/strings.xml` is used at the default if a specific language is not found. It should contain a default value for every string in your app.  See the 'Why Default Resources Are Important' section of the [localization guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).  In fact, the whole document is good guide to localizing your app.