# Android Localisation Code List

Tags: android, localization

Do you know the localisation key for the following countries used in android.

Angola
France
Portugal
Argentina
Belgique
Brasil
Bulgaria
Canada
Croatia
Denmark
Deutschland
Espana
Greece
Ireland
Italia
Luxembourg
Martinique
Mexico
Montenegro
Nederland
Nouvelle Caledonie 
Pays Bas 
Poland
Romania
Scotland
Singapour
Slovakia
Slovenia
Suisse
Switzerland
United Kingdom
United States
Algerie
Austria
Congo
England
Espagne
Finlande / Finland
Guadeloupe
Guyane
Hungary
Iceland
Israel
Lettonie Latvia
Lituani
Marocco
Maurice
Mayotte
Polynesie Francaise Tahiti
Republic of Malta
Autralia
Norway
Sweden
Estonie / Eesti

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you can find a large list of supported languages with the localisation code:

[What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android)

Hope this will work for you.