# How to make my application support new Locale(s) under old SDK?

Tags: android, localization, internationalization, android-sdk-2.1

I developed an `android` application
And I targeted some old devices (`Android SDK 2.1`)
How I can support languages as (`Bulgarian`, `Danish`, `Arabic`, `Hebrew` ...)
However all the above `Locale(s)` were only supported since version `Android SDK 2.3`

And if that is impossible to do so, what is the best way to implement that without writing a standalone app for every language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on the Android site covers your question:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

As you mention Arabic and Hebrew, note that only with 4.2 is there support for Right To Left (RTL):
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL

Edit:

Device manufacturers don't need to support all of the languages and locales that are available in Android. Or at least that is my reading of the Compatibility Definition Document. It is also possible that outside of Android for a particular version an ODM added a unsupported language/locale as a customization. Unfortunately I don't have any direct first hand knowledge of any ODM doing this.

Given that in March 2013 Android 2.2 and below has a market share around 10% according to Google Play statistics, you might just want to drop support for them and target 2.3 and up which would give you a larger set of supported languages/locales.

Take a look at this SO question regarding what languages/locales are supported by which version of Android:
[What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android)