# How to create a multi-language app with XML in Android?

Tags: android, xml

I want to create a multi-language Android application with three languages: English, Arabic and Persian language.

I must create three XML files in the assets folder and parse them all, then use one for the language?

Please help me to resolve my problem?

Comment: No, the fonts go in the assets/ folder, but the three xml files go in the res/values/ folder.

Comment: i Want display Pesian Language,but not Exists in Languages

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android

Comment: If it's not there, it's possible to add it yourself.

Comment: How add Language to lists...? values-fa

Answer (score 6):

You need to have different strings.xml to support different langauges.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

[What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android).

I don't think there is support for persian language.

Example:

MyProject/

```
res/
   values/
       strings.xml

   values-es/
       strings.xml

   values-fr/
       strings.xml

   values-ar/          // for arabic
       strings.xml
```

For spanish

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Mi Aplicación</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hola Mundo!</string>
</resources>
```

At runtime, the Android system uses the appropriate set of string resources based on the locale currently set for the user's device.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText(R.string.hello_world);
```

Check the doc for more info

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes u need to create three type of xml.

```
res/
   values/
       strings.xml
   values-es/
       strings.xml
   values-fr/
       strings.xml
```

Refer this [doc](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

**EDIT**

Please Check this [Example](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2012/04/some-users-expect-to-use-application-in.html).So u can get idea On Multi language supporting.

Comment: @farzad what do you mean by how to find the language?

Comment: I want user select langauage with three radiobutton

Comment: you define strings in strins.xml and set the text of radio button