# android change layout widgets to right left

Tags: android, android-layout

i am working on an application with multi languages. i have done working with locate.

unlike english, there are some languages with written from right to left so i want to make my layout widgets from right to left , is there any way so i can do that?

#### note

what i am asking for is something to make the textviews and buttons (which are in the right  ) to the left and the elements (which are in the left) to the right.

#### what have i tried?

i thought that locate class could help the problem, i searched about it but it seems that it is not useful in my case.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you will have to change the layout_gravity and alignParentRight="true" or alignParentLeft="true" for each view.

Comment: Please see this page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377590/how-to-create-a-multi-language-app-with-xml-in-android

Comment: @MuhammadAamirALi there is much easier solution. it doesn't make any sence to make a new layout whenever i want to support a new language.

Comment: @srfarzad that thread is about localization language, I have already checked it.

Comment: Have You seen http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html ?

Comment: @sandrstar I think that link would be helpful, thanks. in addition, the solution might be something related to `Bidi`. check this out http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Bidi.html