# Android Ukrainian Language

Tags: android, date, localization

How can i convert `Date` to Ukrainian language dynamically.

I'm using this code:

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, yyyy");
final Date date = calendar.getTime();

final TextView chosenMonth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chosenMonth);
chosenMonth.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
```

To format date as "September, 2013". This text language is Device language, but i need to format this date and display only in Ukrainian language.

I tried to implement this using `Locale` class but there is no constant for UA language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although there is no constant, you can still set the locale yourself if its supported on your device.  [Refer to this list of supported locales by Android version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android).

Create your Ukranian Locale with `new Locale('uk','UA')` and then use it in the version of SimpleDateFormat that takes a Locale.

Would this work?

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, yyyy", new Locale('uk','UA'));
```

Comment: That works but Month is displayed from small letter and in bad format. Need to be "Вересень" but get "вересня"

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`DateFormat.getDateInstance(int style, Locale locale)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance%28int,%20java.util.Locale%29) instead of creating your own patterns with SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: How can i set UA language there, i looked http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html there is no constant for Ukrainian language(Locale.UA).

Comment: Try to use `new Locale("UA")`.