# Android Language support

Tags: android, translation

I have an application to which I want to add Burmese Language support. Anyone any Idea how to achieve that as google translator doesn't have feature to translate to burmese.

Also I have tried Few other links which is giving me keyboard like this
http://www.stars21.com/keyboard/burmese_keyboard.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android official language support allows you to set the phones locale to whatever is available. The list of available locales as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android).

Being on that list means: the user can set the language of the app and the whole system. And you can have folders like `res/values-de` to show locale specific strings.

Supporting a language which is not specified and supported in the phones is difficult. AFAIK 
Burmese language is not supported by phones. You can check out [List of locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) supported by android.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged on your computer, go to the Set Locale and Language© site on Google Play℠ and request the installation over the web interface. Or, follow the steps below to install it in your device directly:

```
Open “Google Play” on your device.
Tap on “Search” and type “locale select” in the search box.
Tap on “Set Locale and Language” app, which should be the first result.
Tap on “Download” and then on the “Accept & download” button.
Wait until the app gets installed.
Now, go to the system settings of your device and choose from the new installed languages in the “Language and Input Settings” option.
Set the language you want from the available list.
```