# Japanese text to speech Android?

Tags: android, speech

I am programming an app which can speech to text in Japanese. However, when I code, I know that Android doesn't support Japanese language.
I try to use SVOX. However, it isn't the best solution?
Can you help me to solve my problem?
Thanks you.

Here is my code after @ErsinGülbahar help :)

```
package com.example.tts;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.http.util.LangUtils;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    Thread x;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        x = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String url1 = "http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q="
                            + "Hello".replace(' ', '+').replace('\n', '.')
                            + "%0A&tl=" + "ja" + "&prev=input";
                    String url2 = "http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=nihongo%0A&tl=ja&prev=input";
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url2);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering,
                                            // etc)
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                }

                finally {
                }
            }

        };
        ImageButton ibm = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        ibm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Callme", 4).show();
                x.run();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, Japanese language is supported since Android version 1.5 (API Level 4)

Comment: No. I use some other app, which has similar function. It must connect to Internet to can speech it

Comment: Look: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/7989085/2649012](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7989085/2649012)

Comment: what are u using ? google translate or whatelse?

Comment: Look at this example: [http://android.okhelp.cz/tts-text-to-speech/](http://android.okhelp.cz/tts-text-to-speech/)

Comment: Sorry. it doesn't support Japanese.

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar I wanna use google translate. can you give any an example :)

Comment: sure I will add an answer soon

Comment: @VanDerCong I add an answer please look it

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar sorry. It can not speech. I will update my code on question

Comment: Sorry. I run successfull. I forget add to my code: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a thread:

```
Thread x=new Thread(){  public void run(){
         try{
             url1="http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q="+word_which_read.replace(' ','+' ).replace('\n','.' )+"%0A&tl="+language+"&prev=input";


            mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url1);
            mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
            mediaPlayer.start();
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                    } 


            finally{ 
            //  x.suspend();
            } 
     }

    };
```

You can call `x.run();` In the url you should set *language* as `ja` this is japanese.
and you should set *word_which_read* as your *word*

Comment: By now, the url does not have "www" prefix. And there is a box to check if user is human or not. Therefore, I think this trick not work anymore..

Answer (score 1):

Here's the list

> ```
> Language / Locale                 Supported since version
>
> English, US (en_US)               1.1
> German, Germany (de_DE)           1.1
> Chinese, PRC (zh_CN)              1.5
> Chinese, Taiwan (zh_TW)           1.5
> Czech, Czech Republic (cs_CZ)     1.5
> Dutch, Belgium (nl_BE)            1.5
> Dutch, Netherlands (nl_NL)        1.5
> English, Australia (en_AU)        1.5
> English, Britain (en_GB)          1.5
> English, Canada (en_CA)           1.5
> English, New Zealand (en_NZ)      1.5
> English, Singapore(en_SG)         1.5
> French, Belgium (fr_BE)           1.5
> French, Canada (fr_CA)            1.5
> French, France (fr_FR)            1.5
> French, Switzerland (fr_CH)       1.5
> German, Austria (de_AT)           1.5
> German, Liechtenstein (de_LI)     1.5
> German, Switzerland (de_CH)       1.5
> Italian, Italy (it_IT)            1.5
> Italian, Switzerland (it_CH)      1.5
> Japanese (ja_JP)                  1.5
> Korean (ko_KR)                    1.5
> Polish (pl_PL)                    1.5
> Russian (ru_RU)                   1.5
> Spanish (es_ES)                   1.5
> Arabic, Egypt (ar_EG)             2.3
> Arabic, Israel (ar_IL)            2.3
> Bulgarian, Bulgaria (bg_BG)       2.3
> Catalan, Spain (ca_ES)            2.3
> Croatian, Croatia (hr_HR)         2.3
> Danish, Denmark(da_DK)            2.3
> English, India (en_IN)            2.3
> English, Ireland (en_IE)          2.3
> English, Zimbabwe (en_ZA)         2.3
> Finnish, Finland (fi_FI)          2.3
> Greek, Greece (el_GR)             2.3
> Hebrew, Israel (iw_IL)*           2.3
> Hindi, India (hi_IN)              2.3
> Hungarian, Hungary (hu_HU)        2.3
> Indonesian, Indonesia (in_ID)*    2.3
> Latvian, Latvia (lv_LV)           2.3
> Lithuanian, Lithuania (lt_LT)     2.3
> Norwegian-Bokmol, Norway(nb_NO)   2.3
> Portuguese, Brazil (pt_BR)        2.3
> Portuguese, Portugal (pt_PT)      2.3
> Romanian, Romania (ro_RO)         2.3
> Serbian (sr_RS)                   2.3
> Slovak, Slovakia (sk_SK)          2.3
> Slovenian, Slovenia (sl_SI)       2.3
> Spanish, US (es_US)               2.3
> Swedish, Sweden (sv_SE)           2.3
> Tagalog, Philippines (tl_PH)      2.3
> Thai, Thailand (th_TH)            2.3
> Turkish, Turkey (tr_TR)           2.3
> Ukrainian, Ukraine (uk_UA)        2.3
> Vietnamese, Vietnam (vi_VN)       2.3
> ```