# How to change language Google Map V2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am using `google-play-service-lib`. How can I change language of google map i.e. show locations in korian language or Hindi Language.

Comment: did you got solution for Hindi language? below given examples are working for "ko" but not for "hi".

Comment: @ArthTilva This was very old query so I have forgotten about Hindi support.

Comment: For people asking about the Hindi (hi_IN) language, check answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862517/how-can-i-change-google-maps-language-to-hindi-in-my-app/63918493#63918493

Answer (score 13):

You can change location for Google Maps that use the Google Map API V2 by using a [Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) Object.  The language needs to be supported on the device being used though.

Here is the [full list of supported languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android).

With this code below I was able to change the language on the map to Chinese:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String languageToLoad = "zh_CN";
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();

}
```

Result, language set to Chinese in the code (no manual changes) on a U.S. based phone:

[image: Chinese Map]

I was also able to get it to show Korean, use this Locale code:

```
 String languageToLoad = "ko_KR";
```

Result:

[image: Korean Map]

**NOTE**

It looks like the supported languages for Google Maps are listed here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport

Comment: This code is very close to what I had already. This makes all the rest of my app use the desired locale, but not the map. Maybe it's because I use the Support library's map: getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)

Comment: Well, it seems it works partially! Locale.setDefault(locale); seems to be the key, however it is heavily cached, so when I change the locale in the app, then it doesn't change the locale of the map.

Comment: @Gavriel Interesting.  One thing to note, be sure to call it before the call to `setContentView()`, or any other type of layout inflating.

Comment: Hi, i'm not able to show google map in hindi language. i've updated play service and google map as well. any idea how can i get it done.

Comment: @VaishaliSharma Did you try the above solution using `hi_IN`?

Comment: this doesn't change the map language until restart the app. is there any way to clear the cache ?

Comment: @RameshKumar Not sure exactly why it wouldn't work in some cases.  It looks like Hindi is supported if you look at the list: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport   Be sure that the device you're testing on also supports the language.

Comment: yes,  my device is  supported hindi language.but not show map in hindi

Comment: @DanielNugent Apologies for piling on this really old thread, but I tried the solution you have provided in this answer while using the locale "ko_KR" and it works correctly. However changing the locale to "hi" or "hi_IN" does not work. There exists an issue in google's issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/36823099) to which I have added a comment.

Answer (score 3):

We only need to change the location in the application to get the Map´s descriptions with different language. We have to add validations to avoid the use of deprecated methods:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String language= "hi"; //Hindi language!.
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
           config.setLocale(locale);
           getContext().createConfigurationContext(config);
        }else { //deprecated 
           config.locale = locale;
           getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }

...
...
```

...

Very important to say that **all the languages are not supported**, this is an example in Russian language:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

We can get the code languages from:

https://www.transifex.com/explore/languages/

Answer (score 1):

Just change the locale on the device.  If translations are available, they will be shown automatically.

A screenshot of my US phone with the locale switched to Korean:

[image]

Comment: Does this work? I tried changing the device's locale to Italian, Spanish, French, but Google Maps is always shown in English.

Comment: Yes, I tested it before I answered.  I changed the locale on my phone to Korean, and my own Maps test app mostly changed to Korean, even the names of minor streets in my city.  I used this app to change locale: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bruce.setlocale

Comment: Note: The app chooses its language when it starts.  You may have to force stop the app and restart it to get it to change languages.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli i am having the same experience as you. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @rfsk2010 I haven't tried the application suggested by Kevin. I would expect the map locale to change without using third party applications to help it. As things currently stand, I have yet to find a solution, sorry.

Comment: The purpose of the third-party app I mentioned is to change the locale of the device, not the map specifically.  Once the locale is changed, **all** apps that have resources for that locale should automatically start using them.  (With the caveat that they must be restarted, which may mean force closing them.)

Comment: Is there a way to change the map's language programmatically from my app (without changing the system locale)?

Comment: @Gavriel It's a little late!  But I just posted an answer that changes the map language programmatically if you're still interested.

Answer (score 1):

hope this easy solution for changing map language helps someone:

simply add call `setUpMapLocale()` in your activity `onCreate()`:

```
 private fun setUpMapLocale() {
        val languageToLoad = "iw_IL" // your desired language locale
        val locale = Locale(languageToLoad)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        baseContext.resources.configuration.setLocale(locale)
    }
```

so i just had to call `setLocale()` on the existing configuration attached to `baseContext` resources

Answer (score 0):

With new Google Map Render Support now you will get this, Need to follow a few steps,

1. Update Google Map Dependency

   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
2. Create New Class that Extends the Application, and initialize a new Map Renderer.

   ```
    class MyApplication : Application() {
           override fun onCreate() {
           super.onCreate()
           MapsInitializer.initialize(
               applicationContext,
               MapsInitializer.Renderer.LATEST,
               object : OnMapsSdkInitializedCallback {
               override fun onMapsSdkInitialized(p0: MapsInitializer.Renderer) {
                    Log.e("MapsInitializer", p0.name)
                }
            })
    }
   ```

   }
3. Register MyApplication class in Manifest.

```html
<application
    android:name="com.extra.MyApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you think that locale configuration is already correct as mentioned below and you still have the problem.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en"); // Exmaple for English
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Resources resources = getResources();
Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
configuration.setLocale(locale);
resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
```

It is possible that you are using default google maps initializer which uses LEGACY renderer as below:

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
```

If you really use it then let test with LATEST renderer instead:

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(this, MapsInitializer.Renderer.LATEST, null);
```

I tried and tested with many things, but it works with only with LATEST renderer.