# Android Google Map Localization

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to show google map in French, Italian in Android app.
How I can set language of map ?
I checked google map API documentation but didn't find anything to set map language.

I tried below code but doesn't work for me.

```
String languageToLoad = "zh_CN";
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
```

Comment: may be they google uses language preference used in mobile, try by changinh the language to any of these languages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change language Google Map V2 android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863288/how-to-change-language-google-map-v2-android)

Comment: Check the below link to change the language http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863288/how-to-change-language-google-map-v2-android