# Change language in Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, locale

I have been using the following link for changing the language on fragment start [change-language-google-map-v2-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863288/how-to-change-language-google-map-v2-android)
,the language of the phone gets changed but on the map it doesn't. I'm using `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` inside the fragment. Appreciating for any help!

Comment: As I commented there, the app must be restarted for the language change to take effect.  This may require force closing it.

Comment: This may helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863288/how-to-change-language-google-map-v2-android

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I am already restarting the app. Rest of the languages get changed though.

Comment: @MilapTank I already mentioned that I have been referring to that link.

Comment: Can you provide source code?