# Google Map Display English view in Arabic

Tags: android, google-maps, android-googleapiclient

I am using google map and it is display in arabic view in arabic os mobile, But i need to display english view in Arabic os mobile.

So, is this possible for google map language is changed?

Comment: Try changing the Locale to English in your `onCreate`. 
Look into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863288/how-to-change-language-google-map-v2-android) for a detail code snippet.

Comment: thanks, for ur answer, but it is already implemented but english google map is not displayed. so what i will do ? other solution pls.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible [How to change language of maps dynamically in android?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/v9H4aSlRKBI)

> It is also not possible to use one
>   language for google map and other
>   language for device settings and google
>   keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request in Google issue tracker to make it possible to set region and language bias programmatically.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63829150

Please feel free to star this feature request to add your vote and subscribe to notifications. Hopefully one day Google will implement it.