# Why locations name are gone from Google Maps when change the language in map to Locale language?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to set Google Maps language as Locale language. Here is my code

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback {

private final static String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
static final CameraPosition cp = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(23.860407,90.264061))
        .bearing(0)
        .zoom(12)
        .build();
private GoogleMap mMap;
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
String language= "bn_BD";
Locale locale = new Locale(language);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.locale = locale; 
 this.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is 
 ready to be used.
 mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp));
}
}
```

But when i run this locations name are gone from the map. Here is the output

[image]

Comment: Try this, It'll help you out there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863288/how-to-change-language-google-map-v2-android

Comment: @RakeshKumar  please see my code. I have used the same code from your link

Comment: It seems your language is not in the list https://www.transifex.com/explore/languages/

Comment: My language is in the list

Comment: Are you able to convert other languages than this ?

Comment: I have used arabic and it works

Comment: Yes, It seems your language does not support