# changing language in app at runtime does not change map language

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I am stuck with an issue while working on a project and I have already spent a lot of time doing R&D and trying various solution mentioned I found while googling it.

"In my app I have an option for user to change language and I have got a Activity which has map on it, what happening is it set the map language correctly for the first time I install the app on device and select language for the first time but after it is installed if user changes the language and go back to map activity it does not change language on map unless user uninstall the app and reinstall it again and set the language again of his choice."

Any suggestion or solution will be highly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863288/how-to-change-language-google-map-v2-android

Comment: everything depends on your code. Probably you did something wrong there

Comment: I have sorted this by killing app and relaunching it programmatically... but the map is showing in selected language along with english language (In dial language ) while I want it to be strictly in one language