# What is "values" folder name for Danish Language?

Tags: android, localization

I read the [localization in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html). Here for we need to create different values's folder for each language.

for e.g.

1. res/values/strings.xml : Contains English text for all the strings that the application uses, including text for a string named title.
2. res/values-fr/strings.xml : Contain French text for all the strings, including title.
3. res/values-ja/strings.xml : Contain Japanese text for all the strings except title.

Now I want to give support for Danish language then what should I name to value's folder ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Danish, you got to use values-da folder.

**Edit**: It turns out, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android) that it is values-da.

Plus, according to the Android `Locale` class documentation:

```
The language codes are two-letter lowercase ISO language codes (such as "en") as defined by ISO 639-1. 
The country codes are two-letter uppercase ISO country codes (such as "US") as defined by ISO 3166-1. 
The variant codes are unspecified.
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, but what is the logic for this name ?

Comment: It is the country code top-level domain. See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain

Comment: If that's so, then it's a bug: DK is the country code for Denmark, DA is the language code for Danish. There is non DK language code.

Comment: I already edited my post. You can see more details here:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for that list :)

Comment: @joao2fast4u, can you too please voteup my question ?

Answer (score 3):

For Danish generally, you would want to use `res/values-da/strings.xml`.

To have strings specific to a country as well as a language you would use `res/values-da-rDK/strings.xml` for Denmark, `res/values-da-rGL/strings.xml` for Greenland, `res/values-da-rDE/strings.xml` for Germany (there being a sizable Danish-speaking community in Southern Schleswig along with a few elsewhere in Germany), `res/values-da-rFO/strings.xml` for the Faroe Islands, and so on. You can even have something like `res/values-da-rFR/strings.xml` as while there isn't a large Danish-speaking population in France, nothing stops you doing something like that anyway.

You can mix these, e.g. being specific to country only for a handful of values, falling back to `res/values-da/strings.xml` for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Via http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes, you would use res/values-da/strings.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Android value's folder is following the locale naming specified by ISO-639-1.

Danish language, according to the standard, have the locale `da`, so your folder will be `values-da`.

The same rule applies to all languages.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes