# How to add more locale (Switzerland) to android

Tags: android, locale

In the Android Locale file I do not see Switzerland. But I would like to display the currency (CHF) is someone is using my application from Switzerland. The problem is I never see the swiss locale even if I want to add it programatically. Anyone knows how to add Swiss locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think important for you is:

1. German, Switzerland (de_CH)
2. French, Switzerland (fr_CH)
3. Italian, Switzerland (it_CH)

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android) SO question