# Android Supporting Indian Languages

Tags: android

What are the values folders that are available for indian languages in android.  going through this link [supported languages/locales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android) i found out android supports  hindi. Any other languages supported by android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya android will support all languages. You have to provide the appropriate version of the values folder. The ISO codes for the languages are available here [Language ISO codes](http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm)

Comment: I created values folder values-ta-IN , I got this error  invalid resource directory name: \res values-ta-IN

Comment: Just give values-ta....it will works

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following link for list of supporting languages.

http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php