# Android Localization structure of values folder

Tags: android, eclipse, localization

I`m still learning android development and come with one app which I want to localize to multiple languages.

But please help me a little bit with values folder structure. I have main values folder and in it I have analytics.xml, strings.xml,styles.xml,mraid_attr.xml and colors.xml.

When I make new folder for localization, eg: values-fr I must put all of these files in it or just string.xml where I have translated strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put your translated strings in your localization folder, but Lint will warn you about non-translated strings.

So if you have configuration strings (i.e no translation needed), create a separate XMl (like config.xml) and let only your translated strings on your localization folders.

Comment: I dont have configuration string in strings.xml, just text for buttons etc :) So this will be ok? http://prntscr.com/6qqsrv

Can I just ask where can I find country flags shortcodes? Because in some tutorials is writen there must be values-fr_rFR, and on other sites is just values-fr?

Comment: You can find country codes here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android

If you add a values-fr folder, it will be take by Belgium, Canada, France and Switzerland.
But if you just want France, you can use values-fr_rFR, or values-fr_rCA for Canada.
Don't forget to put your question a resolved ;)