# How to get the currency symbol for particular country using locale?

Tags: java, locale, currency

I have tried this code and it gives me the `Country Code`for some countries instead of the `currency symbol`

> **I want the currency symbol not the code**

**The array resourseList contains all the countries with it's code**

```
String m= (String) Array.get(recourseList,i);
String[] ma=m.split(",");
Locale locale=new Locale("en", ma[1]);
Currency currency= Currency.getInstance(locale);
String symbol = currency.getSymbol();
((TextView) finalV.findViewById(R.id.currencySymbolid)).setText(symbol);
```

Comment: Do you want currency code or currency symbol?

Comment: i am looking for symbol

Comment: Although you are looking for the symbol, be aware that sometimes the currency code is just as important.  You may want to include both.  For example, both USA & Canada use $, but without the code there is no way to tell if it's US Dollars or Canadian Dollars.

Comment: i just need the symbol in my app

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It says in the [Currency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) specification:

> getSymbol() gets the symbol of this currency for the default locale.
>   For example, for the US Dollar, the symbol is "$" if the default
>   locale is the US, while for other locales it may be "US$". If no
>   symbol can be determined, the ISO 4217 currency code is returned.

**EDITED**
I have found a way around this issue

```
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

public class CurrencyCode
{

    public static void main() {
        Map<Currency, Locale> map = getCurrencyLocaleMap();
        String [] countries = { "US", "CA", "MX", "GB", "DE", "PL", "RU", "JP", "CN" };

        for (String countryCode : countries) {
           Locale locale = new Locale("EN",countryCode);
           Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
           String symbol = currency.getSymbol(map.get(currency));
           System.out.println("For country " + countryCode + ", currency symbol is " + symbol);
        }
    }

    public static Map<Currency, Locale> getCurrencyLocaleMap() {
       Map<Currency, Locale> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
           try {
             Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
             map.put(currency, locale);
           }
           catch (Exception e){ 
             // skip strange locale 
           }
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
For country US, currency symbol is $
For country CA, currency symbol is $
For country MX, currency symbol is $
For country GB, currency symbol is £
For country DE, currency symbol is €
For country PL, currency symbol is zł
For country RU, currency symbol is руб.
For country SE, currency symbol is kr
For country JP, currency symbol is ￥
For country CN, currency symbol is ￥
```

Comment: i understand but please check my code, I'm changing  the local

Comment: What Locale do you use?

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in the question itself the `resourcelist` contains all the country code

Comment: what is the country code?? the one that i have given?

Comment: Those are the [ISO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) country code

Comment: Hmm I don't think this is a very good solution after playing around with it. Many different locales will use the same Currency, such as "sn_ZW" is associated with the currency "USD"; however unlike "en_US" getting a symbol of "$", the "sn_ZW" locale will return a symbol of "US $". We can't guarantee order either of the list in Locale.getAvailableLocales(); so we could get some really bizarre results.

Comment: @CNick **sn_ZW**  does not seem to be listed in Java [supported locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java9locales-3559485.html). I wonder where do you have it from?

Comment: @MaxZoom Ah yeah I was experimenting on Android with this solution. Looks like Android adds more locales to the supported Java 9 ones: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30028371/88270. This scenario might happen in another country than Zimbabwe that is supported in Java9, but I don't have an example off the top of my head where this could happen.