# How can I get NumberFormat to use a currency but with fractional cents/pennies?

Tags: java, scala, format, currency, number-formatting

I'd like to use `NumberFormat` to convert a `Double` to a `String`. I'm currently using a `NumberFormat` based on a currency locale but this rounds the `Double` to 2 decimal places. How could I get it to not round the currency so that it includes fractional pennies?

So if I have

```
val doubleFormatMoney = 1.032323135

val format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US)

val stringFormatMoney = format.format(doubleFormatMoney)
```

Then we should have `stringFormatMoney = $1.032323135` but instead I get `stringFormatMoney = $1.03`

Comment: Why not include the applicable piece of code? It would make it easier to answer.

Comment: You change the NumberFormat chosen,  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: What about System.out.println("" + new Double(1d/3d));

Comment: Note, one should not use Double to deal with money values in the first place, see http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=213

Comment: US currency rounds to two decimal places, so your currency gets formatted that way. If you don't want your numbers to change and you only want to add a currency symbol to the front of your number, why don't you just make a method to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The per-Locale currency format specification includes how many decimal places to use, since that varies by currency (some currencies use 3dp, for example the Jordanian Dinar). Therefore `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US)` includes rounding to 2dp by definition.

If you want to use the standard `Double` `toString` plus the Locale's currency symbol, you can do:

```
Currency.getInstance(Locale.US).getSymbol(Locale.US) + doubleFormatMoney
```

See [How to get the currency symbol for particular country using locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969439/how-to-get-the-currency-symbol-for-particular-country-using-locale)