# How can i find Indian Accent in TextToSpeech class of Andorid

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I cannot find `Locale.IN` in Android, like `Locale.UK`, `Locale.US`.

Where could I find it?

Comment: English, India (en_IN) has to be there.

Comment: yes i did it like this tts.setLanguage(new Locale("en_IN")); but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Locale locale = new Locale("en", "IN");` to set English India for the TTS.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "IN");
int availability = mTTSObject.isLanguageAvailable(locale);
switch (availability) {
    case TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED: {
        mTTSObject.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        break;
    }
    case TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA: {
        mTTSObject.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        break;
    }
    case TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE: {
        mTTSObject.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        break;
    }
    case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE:
    case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE: {
        mTTSObject.setLanguage(locale);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Locale.ENGLISH is available in Locale class

Comment: But i want it in indian accent

Comment: Are you talking about local languages

Comment: No @KeyurLakhani i am asking about the English only in Indian accent

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the list of Locale available in android specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android). In India either we speak UK based English or US based English. there is no such Indian accent in English. Generally we speak UK based English.

Answer (score 0):

I am not Indian, but if you set the language to Locale("hi", "IN") and let the tts speak English phrases they pretty much sound like the way my Indian friends speak. Might not be a perfect Indian accent you are looking for but close enough I think. Similarly if you want to put some "french accent" set the language to Locale("fr", "FR") and and let it speak English phrases.