# Brazil strings not showing in file directory in Android?

Tags: android, locale

So I have multiple locale res directories.  I'm trying to add one for brazil, but the strings file icon always defaults to the french flag.  I was able to do other locales just fine, but cant get Brazil to work.  I've attached a picture.[file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn7rR.png)

Comment: Forget about an icon. If you choose on your device in national options your language/country - are translation working fine?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `values-br` means `values` for the Breton language (I believe its an old language that's rarely spoken). You can find a list of all of the correct country abbreviations [here](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php).

The official language of Brazil is Portuguese, so you want to be making a directory for Portuguese: `values-pt`.

If you want to be referring to Brazilian Portuguese specifically, you can use `values-pt-rBR`.

The `rBR` at the end means the region of your language (in this case Portuguese) is Brazil. You can find a list of the region abbreviations [here](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search).

Comment: Boom! Perfect, this worked and was very well explained.  Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Thanks.  It's odd that Android Studio doesn't include this in the list of languages in the Translations Editor.

Comment: Does case matter here? `values-pt-rbr` vs `values-pt-rBR`

Answer (score 1):

here is the list with the languages ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20120814113314/http://colincooper.net/blog/2011/02/17/android-supported-language-and-locales/))

```
Language / Locale                            Supported since version
English, US (en-rUS)                                    1.1
German, Germany (de-rDE)                                1.1
Chinese, PRC (zh-rCN)                                   1.5
Chinese, Taiwan (zh-rTW)                                1.5
Czech, Czech Republic (cs-rCZ)                          1.5
Dutch, Belgium (nl-rBE)                                 1.5
Dutch, Netherlands (nl-rNL)                             1.5
English, Australia (en-rAU)                             1.5
English, Britain (en-rGB)                               1.5
English, Canada (en-rCA)                                1.5
English, New Zealand (en-rNZ)                           1.5
English, Singapore(en-rSG)                              1.5
French, Belgium (fr-rBE)                                1.5
French, Canada (fr-rCA)                                 1.5
French, France (fr-rFR)                                 1.5
French, Switzerland (fr-rCH)                            1.5
German, Austria (de-rAT)                                1.5
German, Liechtenstein (de-rLI)                          1.5
German, Switzerland (de-rCH)                            1.5
Italian, Italy (it-rIT)                                 1.5
Italian, Switzerland (it-rCH)                           1.5
Japanese (ja-rJP)                                       1.5
Korean (ko-rKR)                                         1.5
Polish (pl-rPL)                                         1.5
Russian (ru-rRU)                                        1.5
Spanish (es-rES)                                        1.5
Arabic, Egypt (ar-rEG)                                  2.3
Arabic, Israel (ar-rIL)                                 2.3
Bulgarian, Bulgaria (bg-rBG)                            2.3
Catalan, Spain (ca-rES)                                 2.3
Croatian, Croatia (hr-rHR)                              2.3
Danish, Denmark(da-rDK)                                 2.3
English, India (en-rIN)                                 2.3
English, Ireland (en-rIE)                               2.3
English, Zimbabwe (en-rZA)                              2.3
Finnish, Finland (fi-rFI)                               2.3
Greek, Greece (el-rGR)                                  2.3
Hebrew, Israel (iw-rIL)*                                2.3
Hindi, India (hi-rIN)                                   2.3
Hungarian, Hungary (hu-rHU)                             2.3
Indonesian, Indonesia (in-rID)*                         2.3
Latvian, Latvia (lv-rLV)                                2.3
Lithuanian, Lithuania (lt-rLT)                          2.3
Norwegian-Bokmol, Norway(nb-rNO)                        2.3
Portuguese, Brazil (pt-rBR)                             2.3
Portuguese, Portugal (pt-rPT)                           2.3
Romanian, Romania (ro-rRO)                              2.3
Serbian (sr-rRS)                                        2.3
Slovak, Slovakia (sk-rSK)                               2.3
Slovenian, Slovenia (sl-rSI)                            2.3
Spanish, US (es-rUS)                                    2.3
Swedish, Sweden (sv-rSE)                                2.3
Tagalog, Philippines (tl-rPH)                           2.3
Thai, Thailand (th-rTH)                                 2.3
Turkish, Turkey (tr-rTR)                                2.3
Ukrainian, Ukraine (uk-rUA)                             2.3
Vietnamese, Vietnam (vi-rVN)                            2.3
```

- Note that Java uses several deprecated two-letter codes. The Hebrew (“he”) language code is rewritten as “iw”, Indonesian (“id”) as “in”, and Yiddish (“yi”) as “ji”. This rewriting happens even if you construct your own Locale object, not just for instances returned by the various lookup methods

Comment: Note that the list above does not indicate the correct directory names. You need to replace `_` with `-r`, so for example, English in the US becomes `values-en-rUS` (instead of `values-en_US`)

Comment: the values are correct. But it is true that I forgot to mention the -r part