# Google Map In Hindi

Tags: android, google-maps, localization

I am using Google Map API for displaying map.It shows google map in english but i want to display google map content in hindi language.I am using this code but its not working:

```
          String languageToLoad = "hi"; // your language
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
                getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: try this `languageToLoad="hi_IN";`

Comment: User_1191 is right for google map content is show on Hindi used "hi_IN" and for other supported language list is show on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android link

Answer (score -1):

Change your language code:

```
 String languageToLoad = "hi_IN";
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
```

Here is a link for codes: [Android Supported Language and Locales](https://web.archive.org/web/20120814113314/http://colincooper.net/blog/2011/02/17/android-supported-language-and-locales/)