# Which are the new Android N languages?

Tags: android, locale, android-7.0-nougat

I am reading the change log of the new Android N preview. There is something interesting about locales:

> Along with multi-locale support, Android N also expands the range of languages available to users. It offers more than 25 variants each for commonly used languages such as English, Spanish, French, and Arabic. It also adds partial support for more than 100 new languages.

Source: https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#multi-locale_languages

Did you guys found a list of those 100 new languages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I executed the code references from Chris on Android-N and got this list of new languages:

```
af_NA [Afrikaans (Namibia)]
agq_CM [Aghem (Cameroon)]
ak_ [Akan]
ak_GH [Akan (Ghana)]
am_ [Amharic]
ar_ [Arabic]
ar_001 [Arabic (World)]
ar_BH [Arabic (Bahrain)]
ar_DJ [Arabic (Djibouti)]
ar_EG [Arabic (Egypt)]
ar_EH [Arabic (Western Sahara)]
ar_ER [Arabic (Eritrea)]
ar_IQ [Arabic (Iraq)]
ar_KW [Arabic (Kuwait)]
ar_LB [Arabic (Lebanon)]
ar_MR [Arabic (Mauritania)]
ar_OM [Arabic (Oman)]
ar_PS [Arabic (Palestine)]
ar_SA [Arabic (Saudi Arabia)]
ar_SD [Arabic (Sudan)]
ar_SY [Arabic (Syria)]
ar_TD [Arabic (Chad)]
ar_YE [Arabic (Yemen)]
as_ [Assamese]
as_IN [Assamese (India)]
asa_TZ [Asu (Tanzania)]
az_ [Azerbaijani (Latin)]
az_ [Azerbaijani]
az_AZ [Azerbaijani (Cyrillic,Azerbaijan)]
az_AZ [Azerbaijani (Latin,Azerbaijan)]
bas_ [Basaa]
be_ [Belarusian]
bem_ZM [Bemba (Zambia)]
bez_TZ [Bena (Tanzania)]
bg_BG [Bulgarian (Bulgaria)]
bn_BD [Bengali (Bangladesh)]
bo_ [Tibetan]
bo_CN [Tibetan (China)]
bo_IN [Tibetan (India)]
br_ [Breton]
brx_ [Bodo]
bs_ [Bosnian (Latin)]
bs_ [Bosnian]
bs_BA [Bosnian (Cyrillic,Bosnia & Herzegovina)]
ca_IT [Catalan (Italy)]
ce_RU [Chechen (Russia)]
cgg_ [Chiga]
chr_ [Cherokee]
chr_US [Cherokee (United States)]
cs_ [Czech]
cy_ [Welsh]
cy_GB [Welsh (United Kingdom)]
da_DK [Danish (Denmark)]
da_GL [Danish (Greenland)]
dav_ [Taita]
dav_KE [Taita (Kenya)]
de_AT [German (Austria)]
de_BE [German (Belgium)]
de_CH [German (Switzerland)]
de_DE [German (Germany)]
de_LI [German (Liechtenstein)]
dje_ [Zarma]
dua_ [Duala]
dyo_ [Jola-Fonyi]
dyo_SN [Jola-Fonyi (Senegal)]
dz_ [Dzongkha]
ebu_ [Embu]
ebu_KE [Embu (Kenya)]
ee_ [Ewe]
ee_GH [Ewe (Ghana)]
el_ [Greek]
el_CY [Greek (Cyprus)]
en_ [English]
en_001 [English (World)]
en_150 [English (Europe)]
en_AS [English (American Samoa)]
en_AU [English (Australia)]
en_BB [English (Barbados)]
en_BI [English (Burundi)]
en_BS [English (Bahamas)]
en_BW [English (Botswana)]
en_BZ [English (Belize)]
en_CX [English (Christmas Island)]
en_DE [English (Germany)]
en_DG [English (Diego Garcia)]
en_DK [English (Denmark)]
en_DM [English (Dominica)]
en_FI [English (Finland)]
en_FM [English (Micronesia)]
en_GB [English (United Kingdom)]
en_GD [English (Grenada)]
en_GG [English (Guernsey)]
en_GH [English (Ghana)]
en_GI [English (Gibraltar)]
en_GU [English (Guam)]
en_GY [English (Guyana)]
en_IL [English (Israel)]
en_IM [English (Isle of Man)]
en_IN [English (India)]
en_IO [English (British Indian Ocean Territory)]
en_KE [English (Kenya)]
en_KY [English (Cayman Islands)]
en_LS [English (Lesotho)]
en_MO [English (Macau)]
en_MP [English (Northern Mariana Islands)]
en_MU [English (Mauritius)]
en_MW [English (Malawi)]
en_MY [English (Malaysia)]
en_NA [English (Namibia)]
en_NF [English (Norfolk Island)]
en_NR [English (Nauru)]
en_NZ [English (New Zealand)]
en_PG [English (Papua New Guinea)]
en_PH [English (Philippines)]
en_PK [English (Pakistan)]
en_PW [English (Palau)]
en_RW [English (Rwanda)]
en_SB [English (Solomon Islands)]
en_SC [English (Seychelles)]
en_SE [English (Sweden)]
en_SH [English (St. Helena)]
en_SI [English (Slovenia)]
en_SS [English (South Sudan)]
en_SX [English (Sint Maarten)]
en_SZ [English (Swaziland)]
en_TK [English (Tokelau)]
en_TT [English (Trinidad & Tobago)]
en_TV [English (Tuvalu)]
en_TZ [English (Tanzania)]
en_UM [English (U.S. Outlying Islands)]
en_VC [English (St. Vincent & Grenadines)]
en_WS [English (Samoa)]
en_ZM [English (Zambia)]
en_ZW [English (Zimbabwe)]
es_BO [Spanish (Bolivia)]
es_CL [Spanish (Chile)]
es_CO [Spanish (Colombia)]
es_DO [Spanish (Dominican Republic)]
es_ES [Spanish (Spain)]
es_GT [Spanish (Guatemala)]
es_IC [Spanish (Canary Islands)]
es_MX [Spanish (Mexico)]
es_NI [Spanish (Nicaragua)]
es_PA [Spanish (Panama)]
es_PE [Spanish (Peru)]
es_PH [Spanish (Philippines)]
es_PR [Spanish (Puerto Rico)]
es_PY [Spanish (Paraguay)]
es_US [Spanish (United States)]
es_UY [Spanish (Uruguay)]
et_ [Estonian]
et_EE [Estonian (Estonia)]
eu_ [Basque]
eu_ES [Basque (Spain)]
ewo_ [Ewondo]
ewo_CM [Ewondo (Cameroon)]
fa_ [Persian]
fa_AF [Persian (Afghanistan)]
fa_IR [Persian (Iran)]
ff_ [Fulah]
ff_CM [Fulah (Cameroon)]
ff_GN [Fulah (Guinea)]
ff_MR [Fulah (Mauritania)]
ff_SN [Fulah (Senegal)]
fi_ [Finnish]
fi_FI [Finnish (Finland)]
fil_ [Filipino]
fil_PH [Filipino (Philippines)]
fo_ [Faroese]
fo_DK [Faroese (Denmark)]
fo_FO [Faroese (Faroe Islands)]
fr_BE [French (Belgium)]
fr_BF [French (Burkina Faso)]
fr_BL [French (St. Barthélemy)]
fr_CA [French (Canada)]
fr_CD [French (Congo (DRC))]
fr_CF [French (Central African Republic)]
fr_CG [French (Congo (Republic))]
fr_CH [French (Switzerland)]
fr_CM [French (Cameroon)]
fr_DJ [French (Djibouti)]
fr_DZ [French (Algeria)]
fr_FR [French (France)]
fr_GF [French (French Guiana)]
fr_GQ [French (Equatorial Guinea)]
fr_HT [French (Haiti)]
fr_MA [French (Morocco)]
fr_MC [French (Monaco)]
fr_MF [French (St. Martin)]
fr_MG [French (Madagascar)]
fr_ML [French (Mali)]
fr_MQ [French (Martinique)]
fr_MR [French (Mauritania)]
fr_MU [French (Mauritius)]
fr_NC [French (New Caledonia)]
fr_NE [French (Niger)]
fr_PM [French (St. Pierre & Miquelon)]
fr_RE [French (Réunion)]
fr_RW [French (Rwanda)]
fr_SN [French (Senegal)]
fr_YT [French (Mayotte)]
fy_ [Western Frisian]
ha_ [Hausa]
ha_GH [Hausa (Ghana)]
ha_NE [Hausa (Niger)]
hi_ [Hindi]
hr_ [Croatian]
hr_HR [Croatian (Croatia)]
hu_ [Hungarian]
hy_ [Armenian]
hy_AM [Armenian (Armenia)]
in_ [Indonesian]
in_ID [Indonesian (Indonesia)]
iw_ [Hebrew]
ja_ [Japanese]
ja_JP [Japanese (Japan)]
kab_DZ [Kabyle (Algeria)]
kde_TZ [Makonde (Tanzania)]
kk_ [Kazakh]
kk_KZ [Kazakh (Kazakhstan)]
kl_ [Kalaallisut]
kln_KE [Kalenjin (Kenya)]
km_KH [Khmer (Cambodia)]
kn_ [Kannada]
kok_ [Konkani]
ks_ [Kashmiri]
ks_IN [Kashmiri (India)]
ksb_TZ [Shambala (Tanzania)]
ksf_ [Bafia]
ksf_CM [Bafia (Cameroon)]
ksh_ [Colognian]
ksh_DE [Colognian (Germany)]
ky_KG [Kyrgyz (Kyrgyzstan)]
lag_ [Langi]
lg_ [Ganda]
lkt_US [Lakota (United States)]
ln_ [Lingala]
ln_AO [Lingala (Angola)]
lo_LA [Lao (Laos)]
lrc_ [Northern Luri]
lrc_IQ [Northern Luri (Iraq)]
lrc_IR [Northern Luri (Iran)]
lt_ [Lithuanian]
lt_LT [Lithuanian (Lithuania)]
lu_ [Luba-Katanga]
luo_ [Luo]
luy_KE [Luyia (Kenya)]
mer_ [Meru]
mfe_ [Morisyen]
mgh_ [Makhuwa-Meetto]
mk_ [Macedonian]
mn_ [Mongolian]
ms_SG [Malay (Singapore)]
mua_ [Mundang]
mua_CM [Mundang (Cameroon)]
my_MM [Burmese (Myanmar (Burma))]
naq_ [Nama]
nb_SJ [Norwegian Bokmål (Svalbard & Jan Mayen)]
nl_BQ [Dutch (Caribbean Netherlands)]
nl_CW [Dutch (Curaçao)]
nl_SR [Dutch (Suriname)]
nl_SX [Dutch (Sint Maarten)]
nnh_CM [Ngiemboon (Cameroon)]
nus_SS [Nuer (South Sudan)]
nyn_UG [Nyankole (Uganda)]
or_IN [Oriya (India)]
os_RU [Ossetic (Russia)]
pa_ [Punjabi (Gurmukhi)]
pl_ [Polish]
ps_AF [Pashto (Afghanistan)]
pt_ [Portuguese]
pt_PT [Portuguese (Portugal)]
qu_EC [Quechua (Ecuador)]
rm_ [Romansh]
rn_ [Rundi]
ro_ [Romanian]
rof_ [Rombo]
rof_TZ [Rombo (Tanzania)]
ru_ [Russian]
ru_KZ [Russian (Kazakhstan)]
ru_RU [Russian (Russia)]
rw_ [Kinyarwanda]
rwk_ [Rwa]
sah_RU [Sakha (Russia)]
se_SE [Northern Sami (Sweden)]
seh_ [Sena]
seh_MZ [Sena (Mozambique)]
sk_SK [Slovak (Slovakia)]
sl_SI [Slovenian (Slovenia)]
smn_FI [Inari Sami (Finland)]
sn_ZW [Shona (Zimbabwe)]
so_DJ [Somali (Djibouti)]
so_ET [Somali (Ethiopia)]
so_KE [Somali (Kenya)]
so_SO [Somali (Somalia)]
sq_MK [Albanian (Macedonia (FYROM))]
sr_BA [Serbian (Cyrillic,Bosnia & Herzegovina)]
sr_ME [Serbian (Latin,Montenegro)]
sr_RS [Serbian (Latin,Serbia)]
sr_XK [Serbian (Cyrillic,Kosovo)]
sv_ [Swedish]
sv_AX [Swedish (Åland Islands)]
sv_FI [Swedish (Finland)]
sw_ [Swahili]
sw_TZ [Swahili (Tanzania)]
ta_ [Tamil]
teo_ [Teso]
teo_KE [Teso (Kenya)]
th_ [Thai]
th_TH [Thai (Thailand)]
to_ [Tongan]
twq_ [Tasawaq]
twq_NE [Tasawaq (Niger)]
uk_UA [Ukrainian (Ukraine)]
ur_PK [Urdu (Pakistan)]
uz_ [Uzbek (Cyrillic)]
uz_UZ [Uzbek (Cyrillic,Uzbekistan)]
vai_ [Vai]
vai_LR [Vai (Vai,Liberia)]
wae_ [Walser]
xog_UG [Soga (Uganda)]
yav_ [Yangben]
yo_BJ [Yoruba (Benin)]
zh_HK [Chinese (Simplified Han,Hong Kong)]
zh_HK [Chinese (Traditional Han,Hong Kong)]
zh_MO [Chinese (Simplified Han,Macau)]
zh_MO [Chinese (Traditional Han,Macau)]
```

Good news for Cologne, the apps can been translated to Kölsch (ksh_DE [Colognian])

Comment: Thanks for the list!  It's a shame that there's still no way for the average end user to select other languages though (I'm seeing at least one language that's official in Europe that's missing!).  Guess I'll keep providing an override option in my apps.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30028371/1176870) you can run the following code to get the list of languages:

```
for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    Log.d("LOCALES", locale.getLanguage() + "_" + locale.getCountry() + " [" + locale.getDisplayName() + "]");
}
```

After running the script and cross referencing it with the results from API23 I got the following:

```
af_ [Afrikaans]
af_ZA [Afrikaans (South Africa)]
agq_ [Aghem]
am_ET [Amharic (Ethiopia)]
ar_AE [Arabic (United Arab Emirates)]
ar_DZ [Arabic (Algeria)]
ar_IL [Arabic (Israel)]
ar_JO [Arabic (Jordan)]
ar_KM [Arabic (Comoros)]
ar_LY [Arabic (Libya)]
ar_MA [Arabic (Morocco)]
ar_QA [Arabic (Qatar)]
ar_SO [Arabic (Somalia)]
ar_SS [Arabic (South Sudan)]
ar_TN [Arabic (Tunisia)]
asa_ [Asu]
az_ [Azerbaijani (Cyrillic)]
bas_CM [Basaa (Cameroon)]
be_BY [Belarusian (Belarus)]
bem_ [Bemba]
bez_ [Bena]
bg_ [Bulgarian]
bm_ [Bambara (Latin)]
bm_ [Bambara]
bm_ML [Bambara (Latin,Mali)]
bm_ML [Bambara (Mali)]
bn_ [Bengali]
bn_IN [Bengali (India)]
br_FR [Breton (France)]
brx_IN [Bodo (India)]
bs_ [Bosnian (Cyrillic)]
bs_BA [Bosnian (Latin,Bosnia & Herzegovina)]
ca_ [Catalan]
ca_AD [Catalan (Andorra)]
ca_ES [Catalan (Spain)]
ca_FR [Catalan (France)]
ce_ [Chechen]
cgg_UG [Chiga (Uganda)]
cs_CZ [Czech (Czech Republic)]
da_ [Danish]
de_ [German]
de_LU [German (Luxembourg)]
dje_NE [Zarma (Niger)]
dsb_ [Lower Sorbian]
dsb_DE [Lower Sorbian (Germany)]
dua_CM [Duala (Cameroon)]
dz_BT [Dzongkha (Bhutan)]
ee_TG [Ewe (Togo)]
el_GR [Greek (Greece)]
en_AG [English (Antigua & Barbuda)]
en_AI [English (Anguilla)]
en_AT [English (Austria)]
en_BE [English (Belgium)]
en_BM [English (Bermuda)]
en_CA [English (Canada)]
en_CC [English (Cocos (Keeling) Islands)]
en_CH [English (Switzerland)]
en_CK [English (Cook Islands)]
en_CM [English (Cameroon)]
en_CY [English (Cyprus)]
en_ER [English (Eritrea)]
en_FJ [English (Fiji)]
en_FK [English (Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas))]
en_GM [English (Gambia)]
en_HK [English (Hong Kong)]
en_IE [English (Ireland)]
en_JE [English (Jersey)]
en_JM [English (Jamaica)]
en_KI [English (Kiribati)]
en_KN [English (St. Kitts & Nevis)]
en_LC [English (St. Lucia)]
en_LR [English (Liberia)]
en_MG [English (Madagascar)]
en_MH [English (Marshall Islands)]
en_MS [English (Montserrat)]
en_MT [English (Malta)]
en_NG [English (Nigeria)]
en_NL [English (Netherlands)]
en_NU [English (Niue)]
en_PN [English (Pitcairn Islands)]
en_PR [English (Puerto Rico)]
en_SD [English (Sudan)]
en_SG [English (Singapore)]
en_SL [English (Sierra Leone)]
en_TC [English (Turks & Caicos Islands)]
en_TO [English (Tonga)]
en_UG [English (Uganda)]
en_US [English (United States)]
en_US [English (United States,Computer)]
en_VG [English (British Virgin Islands)]
en_VI [English (U.S. Virgin Islands)]
en_VU [English (Vanuatu)]
en_ZA [English (South Africa)]
eo_ [Esperanto]
es_ [Spanish]
es_419 [Spanish (Latin America)]
es_AR [Spanish (Argentina)]
es_CR [Spanish (Costa Rica)]
es_CU [Spanish (Cuba)]
es_EA [Spanish (Ceuta & Melilla)]
es_EC [Spanish (Ecuador)]
es_GQ [Spanish (Equatorial Guinea)]
es_HN [Spanish (Honduras)]
es_SV [Spanish (El Salvador)]
es_VE [Spanish (Venezuela)]
fr_ [French]
fr_BI [French (Burundi)]
fr_BJ [French (Benin)]
fr_CI [French (Côte d’Ivoire)]
fr_GA [French (Gabon)]
fr_GN [French (Guinea)]
fr_GP [French (Guadeloupe)]
fr_KM [French (Comoros)]
fr_LU [French (Luxembourg)]
fr_PF [French (French Polynesia)]
fr_SC [French (Seychelles)]
fr_SY [French (Syria)]
fr_TD [French (Chad)]
fr_TG [French (Togo)]
fr_TN [French (Tunisia)]
fr_VU [French (Vanuatu)]
fr_WF [French (Wallis & Futuna)]
fur_ [Friulian]
fur_IT [Friulian (Italy)]
fy_NL [Western Frisian (Netherlands)]
ga_ [Irish]
ga_IE [Irish (Ireland)]
gd_ [Scottish Gaelic]
gd_GB [Scottish Gaelic (United Kingdom)]
gl_ [Galician]
gl_ES [Galician (Spain)]
gsw_ [Swiss German]
gsw_CH [Swiss German (Switzerland)]
gsw_FR [Swiss German (France)]
gsw_LI [Swiss German (Liechtenstein)]
gu_ [Gujarati]
gu_IN [Gujarati (India)]
guz_ [Gusii]
guz_KE [Gusii (Kenya)]
gv_ [Manx]
gv_IM [Manx (Isle of Man)]
ha_NG [Hausa (Nigeria)]
haw_ [Hawaiian]
haw_US [Hawaiian (United States)]
hi_IN [Hindi (India)]
hr_BA [Croatian (Bosnia & Herzegovina)]
hsb_ [Upper Sorbian]
hsb_DE [Upper Sorbian (Germany)]
hu_HU [Hungarian (Hungary)]
ig_ [Igbo]
ig_NG [Igbo (Nigeria)]
ii_ [Sichuan Yi]
ii_CN [Sichuan Yi (China)]
is_ [Icelandic]
is_IS [Icelandic (Iceland)]
it_ [Italian]
it_CH [Italian (Switzerland)]
it_IT [Italian (Italy)]
it_SM [Italian (San Marino)]
iw_IL [Hebrew (Israel)]
jgo_ [Ngomba]
jgo_CM [Ngomba (Cameroon)]
ji_ [Yiddish]
ji_001 [Yiddish (World)]
jmc_ [Machame]
jmc_TZ [Machame (Tanzania)]
ka_ [Georgian]
ka_GE [Georgian (Georgia)]
kab_ [Kabyle]
kam_ [Kamba]
kam_KE [Kamba (Kenya)]
kde_ [Makonde]
kea_ [Kabuverdianu]
kea_CV [Kabuverdianu (Cape Verde)]
khq_ [Koyra Chiini]
khq_ML [Koyra Chiini (Mali)]
ki_ [Kikuyu]
ki_KE [Kikuyu (Kenya)]
kkj_ [Kako]
kkj_CM [Kako (Cameroon)]
kl_GL [Kalaallisut (Greenland)]
kln_ [Kalenjin]
km_ [Khmer]
kn_IN [Kannada (India)]
ko_ [Korean]
ko_KP [Korean (North Korea)]
ko_KR [Korean (South Korea)]
kok_IN [Konkani (India)]
ksb_ [Shambala]
kw_ [Cornish]
kw_GB [Cornish (United Kingdom)]
ky_ [Kyrgyz]
lag_TZ [Langi (Tanzania)]
lb_ [Luxembourgish]
lb_LU [Luxembourgish (Luxembourg)]
lg_UG [Ganda (Uganda)]
lkt_ [Lakota]
ln_CD [Lingala (Congo (DRC))]
ln_CF [Lingala (Central African Republic)]
ln_CG [Lingala (Congo (Republic))]
lo_ [Lao]
lu_CD [Luba-Katanga (Congo (DRC))]
luo_KE [Luo (Kenya)]
luy_ [Luyia]
lv_ [Latvian]
lv_LV [Latvian (Latvia)]
mas_ [Masai]
mas_KE [Masai (Kenya)]
mas_TZ [Masai (Tanzania)]
mer_KE [Meru (Kenya)]
mfe_MU [Morisyen (Mauritius)]
mg_ [Malagasy]
mg_MG [Malagasy (Madagascar)]
mgh_MZ [Makhuwa-Meetto (Mozambique)]
mgo_ [Metaʼ]
mgo_CM [Metaʼ (Cameroon)]
mk_MK [Macedonian (Macedonia (FYROM))]
ml_ [Malayalam]
ml_IN [Malayalam (India)]
mn_MN [Mongolian (Mongolia)]
mr_ [Marathi]
mr_IN [Marathi (India)]
ms_ [Malay]
ms_BN [Malay (Brunei)]
ms_MY [Malay (Malaysia)]
mt_ [Maltese]
mt_MT [Maltese (Malta)]
my_ [Burmese]
mzn_ [Mazanderani]
mzn_IR [Mazanderani (Iran)]
naq_NA [Nama (Namibia)]
nb_ [Norwegian Bokmål]
nb_NO [Norwegian Bokmål (Norway)]
nd_ [North Ndebele]
nd_ZW [North Ndebele (Zimbabwe)]
ne_ [Nepali]
ne_IN [Nepali (India)]
ne_NP [Nepali (Nepal)]
nl_ [Dutch]
nl_AW [Dutch (Aruba)]
nl_BE [Dutch (Belgium)]
nl_NL [Dutch (Netherlands)]
nmg_ [Kwasio]
nmg_CM [Kwasio (Cameroon)]
nn_ [Norwegian Nynorsk]
nn_NO [Norwegian Nynorsk (Norway)]
nnh_ [Ngiemboon]
nus_ [Nuer]
nyn_ [Nyankole]
om_ [Oromo]
om_ET [Oromo (Ethiopia)]
om_KE [Oromo (Kenya)]
or_ [Oriya]
os_ [Ossetic]
os_GE [Ossetic (Georgia)]
pa_ [Punjabi (Arabic)]
pa_ [Punjabi]
pa_IN [Punjabi (Gurmukhi,India)]
pa_PK [Punjabi (Arabic,Pakistan)]
pl_PL [Polish (Poland)]
ps_ [Pashto]
pt_AO [Portuguese (Angola)]
pt_BR [Portuguese (Brazil)]
pt_CV [Portuguese (Cape Verde)]
pt_GW [Portuguese (Guinea-Bissau)]
pt_MO [Portuguese (Macau)]
pt_MZ [Portuguese (Mozambique)]
pt_ST [Portuguese (São Tomé & Príncipe)]
pt_TL [Portuguese (Timor-Leste)]
qu_ [Quechua]
qu_BO [Quechua (Bolivia)]
qu_PE [Quechua (Peru)]
rm_CH [Romansh (Switzerland)]
rn_BI [Rundi (Burundi)]
ro_MD [Romanian (Moldova)]
ro_RO [Romanian (Romania)]
ru_BY [Russian (Belarus)]
ru_KG [Russian (Kyrgyzstan)]
ru_MD [Russian (Moldova)]
ru_UA [Russian (Ukraine)]
rw_RW [Kinyarwanda (Rwanda)]
rwk_TZ [Rwa (Tanzania)]
sah_ [Sakha]
saq_ [Samburu]
saq_KE [Samburu (Kenya)]
sbp_ [Sangu]
sbp_TZ [Sangu (Tanzania)]
se_ [Northern Sami]
se_FI [Northern Sami (Finland)]
se_NO [Northern Sami (Norway)]
ses_ [Koyraboro Senni]
ses_ML [Koyraboro Senni (Mali)]
sg_ [Sango]
sg_CF [Sango (Central African Republic)]
shi_ [Tachelhit (Latin)]
shi_ [Tachelhit (Tifinagh)]
shi_ [Tachelhit]
shi_MA [Tachelhit (Latin,Morocco)]
shi_MA [Tachelhit (Tifinagh,Morocco)]
si_ [Sinhala]
si_LK [Sinhala (Sri Lanka)]
sk_ [Slovak]
sl_ [Slovenian]
smn_ [Inari Sami]
sn_ [Shona]
so_ [Somali]
sq_ [Albanian]
sq_AL [Albanian (Albania)]
sq_XK [Albanian (Kosovo)]
sr_ [Serbian (Cyrillic)]
sr_ [Serbian (Latin)]
sr_ [Serbian]
sr_BA [Serbian (Latin,Bosnia & Herzegovina)]
sr_ME [Serbian (Cyrillic,Montenegro)]
sr_RS [Serbian (Cyrillic,Serbia)]
sr_XK [Serbian (Latin,Kosovo)]
sv_SE [Swedish (Sweden)]
sw_CD [Swahili (Congo (DRC))]
sw_KE [Swahili (Kenya)]
sw_UG [Swahili (Uganda)]
ta_IN [Tamil (India)]
ta_LK [Tamil (Sri Lanka)]
ta_MY [Tamil (Malaysia)]
ta_SG [Tamil (Singapore)]
te_ [Telugu]
te_IN [Telugu (India)]
teo_UG [Teso (Uganda)]
ti_ [Tigrinya]
ti_ER [Tigrinya (Eritrea)]
ti_ET [Tigrinya (Ethiopia)]
to_TO [Tongan (Tonga)]
tr_ [Turkish]
tr_CY [Turkish (Cyprus)]
tr_TR [Turkish (Turkey)]
tzm_ [Central Atlas Tamazight]
tzm_MA [Central Atlas Tamazight (Morocco)]
ug_ [Uyghur]
ug_CN [Uyghur (China)]
uk_ [Ukrainian]
ur_ [Urdu]
ur_IN [Urdu (India)]
uz_ [Uzbek (Arabic)]
uz_ [Uzbek (Latin)]
uz_ [Uzbek]
uz_AF [Uzbek (Arabic,Afghanistan)]
uz_UZ [Uzbek (Latin,Uzbekistan)]
vai_ [Vai (Latin)]
vai_ [Vai (Vai)]
vai_LR [Vai (Latin,Liberia)]
vi_ [Vietnamese]
vi_VN [Vietnamese (Vietnam)]
vun_ [Vunjo]
vun_TZ [Vunjo (Tanzania)]
wae_CH [Walser (Switzerland)]
xog_ [Soga]
yav_CM [Yangben (Cameroon)]
yo_ [Yoruba]
yo_NG [Yoruba (Nigeria)]
zgh_ [Standard Moroccan Tamazight]
zgh_MA [Standard Moroccan Tamazight (Morocco)]
zh_ [Chinese (Simplified Han)]
zh_ [Chinese (Traditional Han)]
zh_ [Chinese]
zh_CN [Chinese (Simplified Han,China)]
zh_SG [Chinese (Simplified Han,Singapore)]
zh_TW [Chinese (Traditional Han,Taiwan)]
zu_ [Zulu]
zu_ZA [Zulu (South Africa)]
```

Comment: In your run doesn't seem to be basque included. Can you confirm it?