# Get language name in that language from language code

Tags: java, android, locale

I have a list of language codes (as in "en", "es"...) I need to display in those language like this:

```
English
Español
Français
Deutsch
日本語
```

Is there any built-in API to get these in Android or should I map them myself?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayName(java.util.Locale) or http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayLanguage(java.util.Locale)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The `Locale` class have [a method](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale#getDisplayName(java.util.Locale)) for this: `public String getDisplayLanguage(Locale locale)`, as the documentation says:

> Returns the name of this locale's language, localized to `locale`. The exact output form depends on whether this locale corresponds to a specific language, script, country and variant.

So you can get language names for locales like this:

```java
String lng = "en";
Locale loc = new Locale(lng);
String name = loc.getDisplayLanguage(loc); // English

lng = "es";
loc = new Locale(lng);
name = loc.getDisplayLanguage(loc); // español

//...
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I needed. I had to capitalize the first letter because "es" returns "español" insead of "Español" but it's almost perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @razielsarafan it's easy to capitalize: `name = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);`

Comment: To get all the country codes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30028371/3527024

Comment: Also, I want to additionally mention that Locale needs to be instanced with the language code only in this case. If you try doing this using the language+country code (like for example, `es_MX` - Spanish from Mexico) you will have to do:

`Locale auxLocale = new Locale(languageCode, countryCode);` 

Otherwise it won't work. I'm posting this for anyone to be on the lookout - it took me a bit to realize in my case, since I needed to use language and country codes.

Thanks all for your answers!

Comment: Android 9 - it returns country in English