# Get all languages from java

Tags: java

I want to get all languages using this code:

```
public List<String> getGeneratePreferedLanguagesList()
    {
        String[] languageCodes = Locale.getISOLanguages();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String cc : languageCodes)
        {
            list.add(new Locale("", cc).getDisplayLanguage());
        }

        Collections.sort(list);

        return list;
    }
```

But the final list is empty. Do you know where I'm wrong?

Comment: So your `Locale.getISOLanguages()` already returns an empty result?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Just tested. Actually your list **is not empty**. It contains many elements. It's just that your `String`s are all empty due to `getDisplayLanguage()`. You can easily debug such stuff by placing small `System.out.println(...)` in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should't pass an empty string as first argument, you should pass the language.

In your current language.

```java
Locale locale = new Locale(cc);
list.add(locale.getDisplayLanguage());
```

In its own language.

```java
Locale locale = new Locale(cc);
list.add(locale.getDisplayLanguage(locale));
```

Modify that line and you should check always the the javadoc.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale(java.lang.String)

Comment: The constructor with two strings: first string is language, second string is country.

Comment: Yeah but he doesn't have the country.

Comment: By the way is there a way to display every language label in it's own language?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36061116/get-language-name-in-that-language-from-language-code

Answer (score 3):

I assume that by "the final list is empty" you mean that the list contains all empty stings. If that's what's happening, it's because you are using the wrong `Locale` constructor. Try:

```
list.add(new Locale(cc).getDisplayLanguage());
```

To display each language in it's own language, you can try this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(cc);
list.add(locale.getDisplayLanguage(locale));
```

Comment: By the way is there a way to display every language label in it's own language?

Comment: @PeterPenzov - I added a suggestion for doing this to my answer.