# How to get language's full name from languageCode? (e.g: from 'en' to 'English')

Tags: dart, flutter, globalization

I'm looking for the dart equivalent of this SO question/answer:
[Get language name in that language from language code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36061116/get-language-name-in-that-language-from-language-code)

In other words I'd rather avoid going manually one by one of checking if langCode=='en' return 'English' else if langCode == 'fr' return 'French' etc...

I tried looking for possible methods that do this in Locale, Intl, and Localizations classes, to no avail.

```
DropdownButton<String>(
            items: langCodesList.map((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                child: Text(value),
                value: value,
              );
            }).toList(),
            hint: Text(Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode),
          ))
```

I want the DDL to display the full language name.

Answer (score 20):

[image]

**language class**

```
class LanguageLocal {
  final isoLangs = {
    "ab": {"name": "Abkhaz", "nativeName": "аҧсуа"},
    "aa": {"name": "Afar", "nativeName": "Afaraf"},
    "af": {"name": "Afrikaans", "nativeName": "Afrikaans"},
    "ak": {"name": "Akan", "nativeName": "Akan"},
    "sq": {"name": "Albanian", "nativeName": "Shqip"},
    "am": {"name": "Amharic", "nativeName": "አማርኛ"},
    "ar": {"name": "Arabic", "nativeName": "العربية"},
    "an": {"name": "Aragonese", "nativeName": "Aragonés"},
    "hy": {"name": "Armenian", "nativeName": "Հայերեն"},
    "as": {"name": "Assamese", "nativeName": "অসমীয়া"},
    "av": {"name": "Avaric", "nativeName": "авар мацӀ, магӀарул мацӀ"},
    "ae": {"name": "Avestan", "nativeName": "avesta"},
    "ay": {"name": "Aymara", "nativeName": "aymar aru"},
    "az": {"name": "Azerbaijani", "nativeName": "azərbaycan dili"},
    "bm": {"name": "Bambara", "nativeName": "bamanankan"},
    "ba": {"name": "Bashkir", "nativeName": "башҡорт теле"},
    "eu": {"name": "Basque", "nativeName": "euskara, euskera"},
    "be": {"name": "Belarusian", "nativeName": "Беларуская"},
    "bn": {"name": "Bengali", "nativeName": "বাংলা"},
    "bh": {"name": "Bihari", "nativeName": "भोजपुरी"},
    "bi": {"name": "Bislama", "nativeName": "Bislama"},
    "bs": {"name": "Bosnian", "nativeName": "bosanski jezik"},
    "br": {"name": "Breton", "nativeName": "brezhoneg"},
    "bg": {"name": "Bulgarian", "nativeName": "български език"},
    "my": {"name": "Burmese", "nativeName": "ဗမာစာ"},
    "ca": {"name": "Catalan; Valencian", "nativeName": "Català"},
    "ch": {"name": "Chamorro", "nativeName": "Chamoru"},
    "ce": {"name": "Chechen", "nativeName": "нохчийн мотт"},
    "ny": {
      "name": "Chichewa; Chewa; Nyanja",
      "nativeName": "chiCheŵa, chinyanja"
    },
    "zh": {"name": "Chinese", "nativeName": "中文 (Zhōngwén), 汉语, 漢語"},
    "cv": {"name": "Chuvash", "nativeName": "чӑваш чӗлхи"},
    "kw": {"name": "Cornish", "nativeName": "Kernewek"},
    "co": {"name": "Corsican", "nativeName": "corsu, lingua corsa"},
    "cr": {"name": "Cree", "nativeName": "ᓀᐦᐃᔭᐍᐏᐣ"},
    "hr": {"name": "Croatian", "nativeName": "hrvatski"},
    "cs": {"name": "Czech", "nativeName": "česky, čeština"},
    "da": {"name": "Danish", "nativeName": "dansk"},
    "dv": {"name": "Divehi; Dhivehi; Maldivian;", "nativeName": "ދިވެހި"},
    "nl": {"name": "Dutch", "nativeName": "Nederlands, Vlaams"},
    "en": {"name": "English", "nativeName": "English"},
    "eo": {"name": "Esperanto", "nativeName": "Esperanto"},
    "et": {"name": "Estonian", "nativeName": "eesti, eesti keel"},
    "ee": {"name": "Ewe", "nativeName": "Eʋegbe"},
    "fo": {"name": "Faroese", "nativeName": "føroyskt"},
    "fj": {"name": "Fijian", "nativeName": "vosa Vakaviti"},
    "fi": {"name": "Finnish", "nativeName": "suomi, suomen kieli"},
    "fr": {"name": "French", "nativeName": "français, langue française"},
    "ff": {
      "name": "Fula; Fulah; Pulaar; Pular",
      "nativeName": "Fulfulde, Pulaar, Pular"
    },
    "gl": {"name": "Galician", "nativeName": "Galego"},
    "ka": {"name": "Georgian", "nativeName": "ქართული"},
    "de": {"name": "German", "nativeName": "Deutsch"},
    "el": {"name": "Greek, Modern", "nativeName": "Ελληνικά"},
    "gn": {"name": "Guaraní", "nativeName": "Avañeẽ"},
    "gu": {"name": "Gujarati", "nativeName": "ગુજરાતી"},
    "ht": {"name": "Haitian; Haitian Creole", "nativeName": "Kreyòl ayisyen"},
    "ha": {"name": "Hausa", "nativeName": "Hausa, هَوُسَ"},
    "he": {"name": "Hebrew (modern)", "nativeName": "עברית"},
    "hz": {"name": "Herero", "nativeName": "Otjiherero"},
    "hi": {"name": "Hindi", "nativeName": "हिन्दी, हिंदी"},
    "ho": {"name": "Hiri Motu", "nativeName": "Hiri Motu"},
    "hu": {"name": "Hungarian", "nativeName": "Magyar"},
    "ia": {"name": "Interlingua", "nativeName": "Interlingua"},
    "id": {"name": "Indonesian", "nativeName": "Bahasa Indonesia"},
    "ie": {
      "name": "Interlingue",
      "nativeName": "Originally called Occidental; then Interlingue after WWII"
    },
    "ga": {"name": "Irish", "nativeName": "Gaeilge"},
    "ig": {"name": "Igbo", "nativeName": "Asụsụ Igbo"},
    "ik": {"name": "Inupiaq", "nativeName": "Iñupiaq, Iñupiatun"},
    "io": {"name": "Ido", "nativeName": "Ido"},
    "is": {"name": "Icelandic", "nativeName": "Íslenska"},
    "it": {"name": "Italian", "nativeName": "Italiano"},
    "iu": {"name": "Inuktitut", "nativeName": "ᐃᓄᒃᑎᑐᑦ"},
    "ja": {"name": "Japanese", "nativeName": "日本語 (にほんご／にっぽんご)"},
    "jv": {"name": "Javanese", "nativeName": "basa Jawa"},
    "kl": {
      "name": "Kalaallisut, Greenlandic",
      "nativeName": "kalaallisut, kalaallit oqaasii"
    },
    "kn": {"name": "Kannada", "nativeName": "ಕನ್ನಡ"},
    "kr": {"name": "Kanuri", "nativeName": "Kanuri"},
    "ks": {"name": "Kashmiri", "nativeName": "कश्मीरी, كشميري‎"},
    "kk": {"name": "Kazakh", "nativeName": "Қазақ тілі"},
    "km": {"name": "Khmer", "nativeName": "ភាសាខ្មែរ"},
    "ki": {"name": "Kikuyu, Gikuyu", "nativeName": "Gĩkũyũ"},
    "rw": {"name": "Kinyarwanda", "nativeName": "Ikinyarwanda"},
    "ky": {"name": "Kirghiz, Kyrgyz", "nativeName": "кыргыз тили"},
    "kv": {"name": "Komi", "nativeName": "коми кыв"},
    "kg": {"name": "Kongo", "nativeName": "KiKongo"},
    "ko": {"name": "Korean", "nativeName": "한국어 (韓國語), 조선말 (朝鮮語)"},
    "ku": {"name": "Kurdish", "nativeName": "Kurdî, كوردی‎"},
    "kj": {"name": "Kwanyama, Kuanyama", "nativeName": "Kuanyama"},
    "la": {"name": "Latin", "nativeName": "latine, lingua latina"},
    "lb": {
      "name": "Luxembourgish, Letzeburgesch",
      "nativeName": "Lëtzebuergesch"
    },
    "lg": {"name": "Luganda", "nativeName": "Luganda"},
    "li": {
      "name": "Limburgish, Limburgan, Limburger",
      "nativeName": "Limburgs"
    },
    "ln": {"name": "Lingala", "nativeName": "Lingála"},
    "lo": {"name": "Lao", "nativeName": "ພາສາລາວ"},
    "lt": {"name": "Lithuanian", "nativeName": "lietuvių kalba"},
    "lu": {"name": "Luba-Katanga", "nativeName": ""},
    "lv": {"name": "Latvian", "nativeName": "latviešu valoda"},
    "gv": {"name": "Manx", "nativeName": "Gaelg, Gailck"},
    "mk": {"name": "Macedonian", "nativeName": "македонски јазик"},
    "mg": {"name": "Malagasy", "nativeName": "Malagasy fiteny"},
    "ms": {"name": "Malay", "nativeName": "bahasa Melayu, بهاس ملايو‎"},
    "ml": {"name": "Malayalam", "nativeName": "മലയാളം"},
    "mt": {"name": "Maltese", "nativeName": "Malti"},
    "mi": {"name": "Māori", "nativeName": "te reo Māori"},
    "mr": {"name": "Marathi (Marāṭhī)", "nativeName": "मराठी"},
    "mh": {"name": "Marshallese", "nativeName": "Kajin M̧ajeļ"},
    "mn": {"name": "Mongolian", "nativeName": "монгол"},
    "na": {"name": "Nauru", "nativeName": "Ekakairũ Naoero"},
    "nv": {"name": "Navajo, Navaho", "nativeName": "Diné bizaad, Dinékʼehǰí"},
    "nb": {"name": "Norwegian Bokmål", "nativeName": "Norsk bokmål"},
    "nd": {"name": "North Ndebele", "nativeName": "isiNdebele"},
    "ne": {"name": "Nepali", "nativeName": "नेपाली"},
    "ng": {"name": "Ndonga", "nativeName": "Owambo"},
    "nn": {"name": "Norwegian Nynorsk", "nativeName": "Norsk nynorsk"},
    "no": {"name": "Norwegian", "nativeName": "Norsk"},
    "ii": {"name": "Nuosu", "nativeName": "ꆈꌠ꒿ Nuosuhxop"},
    "nr": {"name": "South Ndebele", "nativeName": "isiNdebele"},
    "oc": {"name": "Occitan", "nativeName": "Occitan"},
    "oj": {"name": "Ojibwe, Ojibwa", "nativeName": "ᐊᓂᔑᓈᐯᒧᐎᓐ"},
    "cu": {
      "name":
          "Old Church Slavonic, Church Slavic, Church Slavonic, Old Bulgarian, Old Slavonic",
      "nativeName": "ѩзыкъ словѣньскъ"
    },
    "om": {"name": "Oromo", "nativeName": "Afaan Oromoo"},
    "or": {"name": "Oriya", "nativeName": "ଓଡ଼ିଆ"},
    "os": {"name": "Ossetian, Ossetic", "nativeName": "ирон æвзаг"},
    "pa": {"name": "Panjabi, Punjabi", "nativeName": "ਪੰਜਾਬੀ, پنجابی‎"},
    "pi": {"name": "Pāli", "nativeName": "पाऴि"},
    "fa": {"name": "Persian", "nativeName": "فارسی"},
    "pl": {"name": "Polish", "nativeName": "polski"},
    "ps": {"name": "Pashto, Pushto", "nativeName": "پښتو"},
    "pt": {"name": "Portuguese", "nativeName": "Português"},
    "qu": {"name": "Quechua", "nativeName": "Runa Simi, Kichwa"},
    "rm": {"name": "Romansh", "nativeName": "rumantsch grischun"},
    "rn": {"name": "Kirundi", "nativeName": "kiRundi"},
    "ro": {"name": "Romanian, Moldavian, Moldovan", "nativeName": "română"},
    "ru": {"name": "Russian", "nativeName": "русский язык"},
    "sa": {"name": "Sanskrit (Saṁskṛta)", "nativeName": "संस्कृतम्"},
    "sc": {"name": "Sardinian", "nativeName": "sardu"},
    "sd": {"name": "Sindhi", "nativeName": "सिन्धी, سنڌي، سندھی‎"},
    "se": {"name": "Northern Sami", "nativeName": "Davvisámegiella"},
    "sm": {"name": "Samoan", "nativeName": "gagana faa Samoa"},
    "sg": {"name": "Sango", "nativeName": "yângâ tî sängö"},
    "sr": {"name": "Serbian", "nativeName": "српски језик"},
    "gd": {"name": "Scottish Gaelic; Gaelic", "nativeName": "Gàidhlig"},
    "sn": {"name": "Shona", "nativeName": "chiShona"},
    "si": {"name": "Sinhala, Sinhalese", "nativeName": "සිංහල"},
    "sk": {"name": "Slovak", "nativeName": "slovenčina"},
    "sl": {"name": "Slovene", "nativeName": "slovenščina"},
    "so": {"name": "Somali", "nativeName": "Soomaaliga, af Soomaali"},
    "st": {"name": "Southern Sotho", "nativeName": "Sesotho"},
    "es": {"name": "Spanish; Castilian", "nativeName": "español, castellano"},
    "su": {"name": "Sundanese", "nativeName": "Basa Sunda"},
    "sw": {"name": "Swahili", "nativeName": "Kiswahili"},
    "ss": {"name": "Swati", "nativeName": "SiSwati"},
    "sv": {"name": "Swedish", "nativeName": "svenska"},
    "ta": {"name": "Tamil", "nativeName": "தமிழ்"},
    "te": {"name": "Telugu", "nativeName": "తెలుగు"},
    "tg": {"name": "Tajik", "nativeName": "тоҷикӣ, toğikī, تاجیکی‎"},
    "th": {"name": "Thai", "nativeName": "ไทย"},
    "ti": {"name": "Tigrinya", "nativeName": "ትግርኛ"},
    "bo": {
      "name": "Tibetan Standard, Tibetan, Central",
      "nativeName": "བོད་ཡིག"
    },
    "tk": {"name": "Turkmen", "nativeName": "Türkmen, Түркмен"},
    "tl": {"name": "Tagalog", "nativeName": "Wikang Tagalog, ᜏᜒᜃᜅ᜔ ᜆᜄᜎᜓᜄ᜔"},
    "tn": {"name": "Tswana", "nativeName": "Setswana"},
    "to": {"name": "Tonga (Tonga Islands)", "nativeName": "faka Tonga"},
    "tr": {"name": "Turkish", "nativeName": "Türkçe"},
    "ts": {"name": "Tsonga", "nativeName": "Xitsonga"},
    "tt": {"name": "Tatar", "nativeName": "татарча, tatarça, تاتارچا‎"},
    "tw": {"name": "Twi", "nativeName": "Twi"},
    "ty": {"name": "Tahitian", "nativeName": "Reo Tahiti"},
    "ug": {"name": "Uighur, Uyghur", "nativeName": "Uyƣurqə, ئۇيغۇرچە‎"},
    "uk": {"name": "Ukrainian", "nativeName": "українська"},
    "ur": {"name": "Urdu", "nativeName": "اردو"},
    "uz": {"name": "Uzbek", "nativeName": "zbek, Ўзбек, أۇزبېك‎"},
    "ve": {"name": "Venda", "nativeName": "Tshivenḓa"},
    "vi": {"name": "Vietnamese", "nativeName": "Tiếng Việt"},
    "vo": {"name": "Volapük", "nativeName": "Volapük"},
    "wa": {"name": "Walloon", "nativeName": "Walon"},
    "cy": {"name": "Welsh", "nativeName": "Cymraeg"},
    "wo": {"name": "Wolof", "nativeName": "Wollof"},
    "fy": {"name": "Western Frisian", "nativeName": "Frysk"},
    "xh": {"name": "Xhosa", "nativeName": "isiXhosa"},
    "yi": {"name": "Yiddish", "nativeName": "ייִדיש"},
    "yo": {"name": "Yoruba", "nativeName": "Yorùbá"},
    "za": {"name": "Zhuang, Chuang", "nativeName": "Saɯ cueŋƅ, Saw cuengh"}
  };

  getDisplayLanguage(key) {
    if (isoLangs.containsKey(key)) {
      return isoLangs[key];
    } else {
      throw Exception("Language key incorrect");
    }
  }
}
```

[Language List](https://gist.github.com/mirontoli/4722797)

**Widget**

```
class LanguageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  LanguageWidgetState createState() {
    return new LanguageWidgetState();
  }
}

class LanguageWidgetState extends State<LanguageWidget> {
  var language = LanguageLocal();

  var langCodesList = ["ar", "en", "fr"];

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> list;

  String _selectedLanguage = "ar";

  @override
  void initState() {
    list = langCodesList.map((String value) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        child: Text(language.getDisplayLanguage(value)["nativeName"]),
        value: value,
      );
    }).toList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: new Container(
        child: Center(
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: _selectedLanguage,
          items: list,
          hint: Text(language.getDisplayLanguage(
              Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode)["name"]),
          onChanged: (String value) {
            print(value);
            setState(() {
              _selectedLanguage = value;
            });
          },
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This type of verbiage is precisely what I was hoping to avoid. I meant that I was looking for something like this built into the framework.

Answer (score 10):

Try this package: [flutter_localized_locales](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_localized_locales)

Then add its localizations delegate:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_localized_locales/flutter_localized_locales.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    localizationsDelegates: [
      LocaleNamesLocalizationsDelegate(),
      ...
    ]
    ...
  );
}
```

If you also use [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization), it should look like this:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    localizationsDelegates: [
      for (var delegate in context.localizationDelegates) delegate,
      LocaleNamesLocalizationsDelegate(),
    ]
    ...
  );
}
```

Use it:

```dart
//if current local is 'km'
LocaleNames.of(context).nameOf("en"); //អង់គ្លេស

//if current local is 'en'
LocaleNames.of(context).nameOf("en"); //English
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use extensions like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension FullName on Locale {
  String fullName() {
    switch (this.languageCode) {
      case 'en':
        return 'English';

      case 'ar':
        return 'العربية';
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```

and you can get the name from locale instance like this

```
Locale _locale = Locale('en');

String fullName = _locale.fullName;
```