# Flutter Dart - get localized country name from country code

Tags: flutter, dart, country-codes, countries

I have a list of alpha-2 country codes.

```
 List<String> countryCodes = ["DE", "CH", "AT"];
```

How to get the localized country names in Flutter/Dart?

If the device language is set to english, i want this output..

> Germany, Switzerland, Austria

If the device language is set to german, i want this output..

> Deutschland, Schweiz, Österreich

Is this possible without any 3rd party package in Flutter/Dart?

In Java you could do..

```
Locale loc = new Locale("","DE");
loc.getDisplayCountry();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get language's full name from languageCode? (e.g: from 'en' to 'English')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999971/how-to-get-languages-full-name-from-languagecode-e-g-from-en-to-english)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65838283/4593315

Comment: No, this is not what i was looking for. I need the "Country Name" from the Country Code (eg. 'DE', 'RU', 'US', 'HU' etc.), not the "Language Code".

Comment: There is nothing in the Dart or Flutter SDK that will do that, so I imagine your answer to "Is this possible" is simply... NO.  But if you still need it done, perhaps something in "pub" will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

If you have any country code and wants to get corresponding country name, use [country_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/country_picker) package like this

```
Country.tryParse(countryCode)?.name
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the localized country names from a country code one can use the **Country Codes** package from pub.dev.

Its easy to use. I recommend.

https://pub.dev/packages/country_codes

Answer (score 0):

You can use [country_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/country_picker) :

```
MaterialApp(
  supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('en'),
    const Locale('lt'),
  ],
  localizationsDelegates: [
    CountryLocalizations.delegate,
    ...
  ],
  ...)
```

and then get the localized country name via :

```
CountryLocalizations.of(context)?.countryName(countryCode: 'LT')
```