# How to have an APP name for each language (Cordova to Android)

Tags: android, cordova, globalization

I'm using cordova and a wanna publish to Google Play, how can I publish a APP with diferent name to each language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to change app name in string.xml files

in value/strings.xml

```
 <string name="app_name">App Name in English</string>
```

in value-fr/strings.xml

```
 <string name="app_name">App name French</string>
```

**Android will automatically change app name both in home screen and in app screens according to current device language**

This is good example to start with :- https://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-
tutorial/

This is documentation regarding localization :- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

This is list of supported languages by android :- 
[What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android)

[image: Localization]

Comment: What about for iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Create locales/android/values-[COUNTRY-CODE]/strings.xml on your project.
For example: locales/android/values-br/strings.xml.

Add following content on your string.xml (update values as required):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">RI Brasil</string>
    <string name="launcher_name">RI Brasil</string>
    <string name="activity_name">RI Brasil</string>
</resources>
```

It [works for PhoneGap Build](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/401), I've didn't check on phonegap cli.

Comment: What about for iOS?

Comment: @BiswasKhayargoli you should make change directly on Xcode, where you can localize infoplist following values: CFBundleDisplayName, CFBundleName. Check this link for more details: https://github.com/speige/cordova-plugin-pgb-ios-localize-app-name#behind-the-scenes-tour