# How to localize app name in cordova for iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, localization, phonegap

I am looking for a solution to localize my app's name in:

- English (EN)
- Chinese (Simplified) zh-Hans
- Chinese (Traditional) zh-Hant

I am using build.phonegap to build my both apps so I cannot modify the platform code but instead it has to be from either some config on config.xml or using cordova hooks or any other solution. So far I found solution for android using hooks but it will not work for iOS.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have an APP name for each language (Cordova to Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672351/how-to-have-an-app-name-for-each-language-cordova-to-android)

Answer (score -1):

For iOS you can do code in config.xml file.

```
<platform name="ios">
  <edit-config target="CFBundleLocalizations" file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite">
    <array>
      <string>en</string>
      <string>es</string>
    </array>
  </edit-config>
</platform>
```

Usage of `<edit-config>` in `config.xml` was introduced in [Cordova 6.4.0](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2016/10/25/tools-release.html).