# How to change app name dynamically in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to change the app name dynamically in flutter because I have many languages inside the app.

I have .arb files for all languages I have and I want to read the app name from these files regarding to the system language. I can do this for all values inside the app except app name.

thanks a lot for any help.

I can manuelly change the name from the AndroidManiFest file for android. but it doesn't help for my issue.

I'm using Android studio.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672351/how-to-have-an-app-name-for-each-language-cordova-to-android

Comment: @Hedwin thanks for your answer. That means there is no way to do this with these .arb files I created and I have to do the same for IOS if I decided later to work with? I mean I have to translate the "app name" again inside ios files? This means I have to translate it 3 times for flutter, android and ios? Is that true? thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hello, as far as ı understand, this solves your problem; https://localizely.com/i18n-questions/flutter/how-to-localize-flutter-app-name/

Comment: hello, thank you @k.spoyraz . that means I have to add the Translation in each string file depends on the Plattform. Thanks again for your help.