# Using a custom language for your app in android other than the languages international known

Tags: java, android

i have been researching on how you can use your own custom language on android but so far have had no fruits. One can create values like values-fr for french and others but how do you work on it when the language is not known. For example Kikuyu a language i happen to know is nowhere to be translated in android studio neither google.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    String lang = "en";
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_en:
            lang = "en";
            break;
        case R.id.btn_ru:
            lang = "ru";
            break;
        case R.id.btn_de:
            lang = "de";
            break;
        case R.id.btn_fr:
            lang = "fr";
            break;
        case R.id.btn_kik:
            lang = "kik";
        default:
            break;
    }
    changeLang(lang);
}
```

the code works fine with the en, ru and rest except for the lang not known "kik". after checking the "kik" it remains as the original language
can someone have a different view on how to solve this

Comment: Did you try "ki" instead of "kik"? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kikuyu_language

Answer (score 1):

According to the list in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30028371/80901) to the question 
[What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android), Kikuyu is supported in newer Android devices.

```
ki_ [Kikuyu]
ki_KE [Kikuyu (Kenya)]
```