# Add language into Android Wear 1.5/2.0

Tags: android, localization, translation, wear-os

If I added Slovak (SK) language (*values-sk-rSK and values-sk*) to the Android Wear 1.5 apks (*framework-res.apk also*), language wasn't set to SK automatically even I had SK on the phone.. so for change language on the Wear watches is needed to translate also Wear app on the phone to SK lang..? Or why my translation wasn't loaded on the watches..?

I have a lot of experiences with adding translation into the Android ROM for phones, but seems it works differently on Android Wear...

Thank you for any help...

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [Localization Tips: Design your application to work in any locale](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#strategies) documentation, if your application is missing even one default resource, it will not run on a device that is set to an unsupported locale.

> For example, the `res/values/strings.xml` default file might lack one string that the application needs: When the application runs in an unsupported locale and attempts to load `res/values/strings.xml`, the user will see an error message and a Force Close button.

You may also check this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html) which explains challenges in resolving Language resources. Be noted that when your Java code refers to strings, the system would load strings from the default (`en_US`) resource file, even if the app has Spanish resources localized under `es_ES`. This is because when the system cannot find an exact match, it continues to look for resources by stripping the country code off the locale. Finally, if no match is found, the system falls back to the default, which is `en_US`.

Here's a related [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android) which might help.

Comment: I know all of that and seems it works differently on Android Wear device... Even if strings are correct, my SK locale is not loaded on the Android Wear device.. Using same method for translate Android app for phones works fine.. My strings are loaded on Android Wear device only if I add them to the existing locales like en-rGB for example.. but cant add them as new locale sk-rSK which is not yet included in Android Wear ROM... Android Wear 2.0 will support RRO vendor method so hope it will then load sk-rSK correctly...