# How to retrieve list of available languages in device

Tags: android, localization

I am developing an app that needs to retrieve the list of languages that are available in the device, in order to gather statistics. Basically, I would like to retrieve the list of languages that the user can see (and select) when accessing the *Language and input->Language* setting of the Settings app. I've tried several ways but don't seem to work:

This retrieves a list of locales, but some of them are not available in the device:

```
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
```

This works fine in my physical device but in the emulator does not retrieve some of the languages that are available:

```
String[] locales = Resources.getSystem().getAssets().getLocales();
```

This obtains the list of languages the user has chosen in the Settings app (API  >= 24):

```
LocaleList locales = getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales();
```

Is there any way in which I could retrieve such list?

Comment: check out this link help you to find your solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android)

Comment: @himanimehta Thanks, but that link does not help, as it shows a list of languages supported by a given Android API version, not a list of the languages supported by the device (manufacturers often limit the default list of languages)

Comment: did you figure out ?? @ManexGaraio