# Android SpeechRecognizer not getting started again

Tags: android, kotlin, speech-recognition

I know how the SpeechRecognizer works in the android. I have a requirement that i need to call **SpeechRecognizer.stopListening()** method after some time. But after that when i start listener again it would not work.

Code to start SpeechRecognizer

```
private void promptSpeechInput() {
    /*
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    */

    speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());
    // for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android
    /*intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en_IN"); */
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 200);
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, new Long(5000));
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, new Long(5000));
    speechIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.DICTATION_MODE", false);
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, false);
    /*
    intent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.GET_AUDIO_FORMAT", "audio/AMR");
    intent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.GET_AUDIO", true);
    */

    sr.startListening(speechIntent);
}
```

After few seconds of speaking i do use

```
sr.stopListening();
```

And after receiving the results in **onResults** i am trying to start it again using

```
sr.startListening(speechIntent);
```

but its not working. What should i do to make it work ?

**EDIT**

if I call **promptSpeechInput();** method again instead of **sr.startListening(speechIntent);** it starts giving me `SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY` error repeatedly.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to again set the **RecognitionListener** to have this work. As weird it sounds, every time when you need to listen to the user reset and set the listener again to make it work.

If you are looking for a quick solution you can try [DroidSpeech](https://github.com/vikramezhil/DroidSpeech), which takes care of all the heavy lifting. With a few lines of code, you will have the speech recognition running perfectly in no time.

```
DroidSpeech droidSpeech = new DroidSpeech(this, null);
droidSpeech.setOnDroidSpeechListener(this);
```

To start listening to the user call the below code,

```
droidSpeech.startDroidSpeechRecognition();
```

And you will get the voice result in the listener method,

```
@Override
public void onDroidSpeechFinalResult(String finalSpeechResult, boolean droidSpeechWillListen)
{
  // Do whatever you want with the speech result
}
```