# Google voice recognition without popup in android studio

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition, voice

Job: I wanna an app like "When I call the method it'll start voice recognizer and  gives the result of voice recognition

Problem: Voice recognizer is starting when I call the method but it's not giving the result of voice recognition instantly. It's giving the result of first calling in second calling.

My codes:
Voice Recognition Class:

```
package com.ooo.voicerecog;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
public class VoiceRecognitionActivity extends Activity implements        
RecognitionListener {
private SpeechRecognizer speech = null;
private Intent recognizerIntent;
public ArrayList<String> matches;
public String newtext=null;
public String text =null;
public void starto(){
int MyVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (MyVersion > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
    if (!checkIfAlreadyhavePermission()) {
        requestForSpecificPermission();
    }
}
speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
recognizerIntent = new 
Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,
        "en");
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
        this.getPackageName());
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);
speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
}
public String getvoice(){
starto();
speech.stopListening();
return text;
}
private boolean checkIfAlreadyhavePermission() {
int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
return true;
} else {
return false;}
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] 
permissions, int[] grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {
case 101:
if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //granted
} else {
                //not granted
}
break;
default:
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
grantResults);
    }
}
private void requestForSpecificPermission() {
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 101);
}
@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() { }

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) { }

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {}

@Override
public void onError(int errorCode) {
    String errorMessage = getErrorText(errorCode);
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {}

@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0) {}

@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0) { }

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
matches = 
results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    for (String result : matches)
        text += result + "\n";}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {}

public static String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
    String message;
    switch (errorCode) {
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
            message = "Audio recording error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
            message = "Client side error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
            message = "Insufficient permissions";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
            message = "Network error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
            message = "Network timeout";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
            message = "No match";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
            message = "RecognitionService busy";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
            message = "error from server";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
            message = "No speech input";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
            break;
    }
    return message;
  }

   }
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.ooo.voicerecog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends VoiceRecognitionActivity{
public Button button;
public Button button1;
public TextView textView;
public String texo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            textView.setText(getvoice());



        }
    });




  }}
```

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is that you're having or question that you're asking. Please [edit] your question and be **specific** and clearly explain the problem, and ask a **specific question** (*this doesn't work right* is not specific). See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. It will not open google prompt and start listening. Below line does the trick

```
speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
```

code:

```
speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());
    // for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android
    /*intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en_IN"); */
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 10000);
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, new Long(5000));
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, new Long(5000));
    speechIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.DICTATION_MODE", false);
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
    /*
    intent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.GET_AUDIO_FORMAT", "audio/AMR");
    intent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.GET_AUDIO", true);
    */
    isRecognizerRunning = true;
    sr.startListening(speechIntent);
```

and listens to it using custom class

```
class listener implements RecognitionListener {

    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        CommonUtilities._Log(CommonUtilities.logs.e, TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
    }

    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        CommonUtilities._Log(CommonUtilities.logs.e, TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
    }

    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

    }

    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        CommonUtilities._Log(CommonUtilities.logs.e, TAG, "onBufferReceived");
    }

    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        CommonUtilities._Log(CommonUtilities.logs.e, TAG, "onEndofSpeech");
        isRecognizerRunning = false;
    }

    public void onError(int error) {
        String message;
        switch (error) {
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
                message = "Audio recording error";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
                message = "Client side error";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
                message = "Insufficient permissions";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
                message = "Network error";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
                message = "Network timeout";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
                message = "No match";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
                message = "RecognitionService busy";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
                message = "error from server";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
                message = "No speech input";
                break;
            default:
                message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
                break;
        }

    }

    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        String str = "";
        ArrayList data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            CommonUtilities._Log(CommonUtilities.logs.e, TAG, "onResults result " + data.get(i) + " size " + data.size());
            str += data.get(i);
        }
        if (!data.get(0).toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            checkAndPerformAction(data.get(0).toString());      // best match
        }
    }

    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
        String str = "";
        ArrayList data = partialResults.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        CommonUtilities._Log(CommonUtilities.logs.e, TAG, "onPartialResults " + data.get(0).toString());
        String[] partial = data.get(0).toString().split(" ");
        if (partial.length > previousPartialResults.length) {
            if (partial.length == 1 && !partial[0].trim().isEmpty()) {
                previousPartialResults = partial;
                CommonUtilities._Log(CommonUtilities.logs.e, TAG, "onPartialResults New " + partial[0].trim());
            } else if (partial.length != 1) {
                previousPartialResults = partial;
                CommonUtilities._Log(CommonUtilities.logs.e, TAG, "onPartialResults New " + previousPartialResults[previousPartialResults.length - 1]);
            }
        }
        CommonUtilities._Log(CommonUtilities.logs.e, TAG, "onPartialResults final " + str);
    }

    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
        CommonUtilities._Log(CommonUtilities.logs.e, TAG, "onEvent " + eventType);
    }
}
```

Comment: The app is already working without pop up. My problem is not this

Comment: @BoraySaygılıer: Then edit your question and **be more clear** about what the problem is that you're having.