# Urdu support on Google Play Support

Tags: android, localization, google-play, google-play-console, urdu

Does Google Play Console support Urdu ? I want to add Urdu support for my android application on Google Play Console,but didnt find languge support ?

How do I add my Urdu texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urdu is supported by Android from at least Android 5.1. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30028371/6296561) for reference. Basically, you can use that language but it looks like it is newly added. That means not all versions of Android supports it.

Comment: That is not the correct answer to his question. He is asking about *Google Play Console* description localization, not app content localization. 
Still, in 2020 Google has not added Urdu in Google Play Console.