# How to change city name language from location?

Tags: java, android, location

In my application i want get user City name from **Latitude** and **Longitude**.
For this i write below codes, but show me city name fro **English** language such as **"Tehran"**

But i want show this city name for **Farsi** , such as **"تهران"**

How can i it for change language?

**My codes :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SimpleLocation mLocation;
    private Geocoder geocoder;
    private List<Address> addresses;
    private String cityName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // construct a new instance
        mLocation = new SimpleLocation(this);

        // reduce the precision to 5,000m for privacy reasons
        mLocation.setBlurRadius(5000);

        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        // if we can't access the location yet
        if (!mLocation.hasLocationEnabled()) {
            // ask the user to enable location access
            SimpleLocation.openSettings(this);
        }

        final double latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
        final double longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        findViewById(R.id.textView).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + cityName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // make the device update its location
        mLocation.beginUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // stop location updates (saves battery)
        mLocation.endUpdates();

        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of passing `Locale.getDefault()`, pass `new Locale("fa_IR")`

Comment: What is your current locale? (Locale.getDefault()?)

Comment: @FAЯAƸ, Thanks my dear friend for your help . it's ok

Comment: @FAЯAƸ, but in my code show me state, city, street name and country name. i want just show city name. how can i it? can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing `Locale.getDefault()`, pass `new Locale("fa_IR")`.

And use `addresses.get(0).getLocality()` to get the name of the city.

See list of supported locales.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7989085/5722608

Comment: but in my code show me state, city, street name and country name. i want just show city name. how can i it? can you help me?

Comment: @Dr.Kook Check my updated answer. To get a clear picture, place a brea kpoint and check what you are receiving in the address object.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the locale in the constructor below:

```
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, new Locale("Your desired locale code"));
```

Comment: @Dr.Kook In general, you need to let the user choose the locale. So, either use default locale or let him choose it in some configuration form. Preferably the first.

Comment: @Dr.Kook check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android

Answer (score 1):

Change TextView with locale

```
Locale loc = new Locale("ar"); // change locale as per your requirement
textView.setTextLocale(loc);
textView.setText("Farsi");
```

Comment: No this will let strings displayed in a locale, not results being translated.

Answer (score 0):

User localization for changing the language using string.xml. pl follow the https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html to know more about localization in android application.