# Locale for Gujrati language for Text to Speech

Tags: android, locale, text-to-speech

I want to try speech Gujarati language for my application. I've tried this locale code for the Gujarati language:

> result = tts.setLanguage(Locale("gu-IN"))
>
> result = tts.setLanguage(Locale("gu"))
>
> result = tts?.setLanguage(Locale("gu-IND"))!!

I've tried these locale codes for the Gujarati Language .. but none of them work.

Comment: Use `gu_IN` Here are more options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7989085/3999808

Comment: @ZUNJAE I already try but it's not working

Comment: you are using `-` but it should be underscore `_`

Comment: i also test with - and _ but not working , but in hin-IND is perfect work in Hindi @KaranMer

Comment: try `Locale.getAvailableLocales().forEach { Log.d("x", it) }` to get a list of all available locales and see if the one you need is there

Comment: Ok i Will check it @ZUNJAE

Answer (score 0):

The code gu-IN is correct you can confirm by [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages).
If it's not working in your program then you can try this [code](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/list-voices#text-to-speech-list-java) to confirm if the language is in the list or not.

If it's available then you need to re-check your code. You can also share your code for help.