# Android add Dari local language

Tags: android, localization

I need to add the Dari local language to an Android application but I can not find a local code for it. What is the local id for the Dari language.

Comment: afghanistan language??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if Dari is afghanistan language then this local id

```
fa_ [Persian]
fa_AF [Persian (Afghanistan)]
fa_IR [Persian (Iran)]
```

if you want to see the other one
this is link

[What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android)

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  The people in charge of the ISO codes consider Dari to be the principal Afghani variant of Persian, hence `fa_AF`.

Comment: i used values-fa_AF for dari directory and put dari language strings.xml file in it but its not recognizing this locale.

Comment: seems the folder should be values-fa-rAF