# Language not changing back to English from Hindi

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

My code is running well and is changing language from English to Hindi but when we again click on it it won't change back to english language

```
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Language",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = sharedPreferences.edit();


        language.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (sharedPreferences.getString("lang","eng").equals("eng")){
                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Changing Language to Hindi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    context = LocaleHelper.setLocale(Settings.this,"hi");
                    resources = context.getResources();
                    editor1.putString("lang","hi");
                    editor1.apply();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.this,Settings.class));
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Changing Language to English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    context = LocaleHelper.setLocale(Settings.this,"eng");
                    resources = context.getResources();
                    editor1.putString("lang","eng");
                    editor1.apply();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.this,Settings.class));
                }
            }
        });
```

I am getting the Toast message correctly When clicking on language it is showing changing language to Hindi , when we click again, it shows changing language to English but the language is changing

I am not sure what to do

Answer (score 0):

Try `.setLocale(Settings.this,"en");` instead of `.setLocale(Settings.this,"eng");`.

The language code might be causing the issue, for language code reference refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7973023/8551764).

### Update

This method worked for me. Implement your `setLocale` strategy in your `BaseActivity`. Also create a `LanguageHelper` class.

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LanguageHelper(base!!).changeBaseContextLocale())
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        LanguageHelper(this).updateLocaleForLegacy()
    }
}
```

LanguageHelper class:

```
class LanguageHelper(val context: Context) {

    private fun getSelectedLocaleFromSharedPref(): String {
        ...
    }

    fun changeBaseContextLocale(): Context? {
        val locale = Locale(getSelectedLocaleFromSharedPref())
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            updateLocale()
        } else context
    }

    // update the locale for API 24 and above.
    private fun updateLocale(): Context {
        val configuration = Configuration(context.resources.configuration)
        configuration.setLocale(Locale(getSelectedLocaleFromSharedPref()));
        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }


    // update the locale for API 23 and below.
    fun updateLocaleForLegacy(): Context? {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) return context

        val resources: Resources = context.resources
        val configuration: Configuration = resources.getConfiguration()
        configuration.setLocale(Locale(getSelectedLocaleFromSharedPref()))
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics())
        return context
    }
}
```

In the settings, only store the selected language locale (for example: "en") in the shared preferences and then restart the app, then the language will change.

Comment: still not working

Comment: @DhananjaySingh Please check the updated answer, this method has worked for me.