# How to choose Locale from string

Tags: android

I am using PreferenceActivity for storing language. This is my XML.

```
<item>US</item>
        <item>UK</item>
        <item>CANADA</item>
        <item>CANADA_FRENCH</item>
        <item>CHINESE</item>
        <item>FRENCH</item>
        <item>GERMAN</item>
        <item>ITALIAN</item>
        <item>JAPANESE</item>

<string-array name="listOfLanguagesValues">
        <item>US</item>
        <item>UK</item>
        <item>CANADA</item>
        <item>CANADA_FRENCH</item>
        <item>CHINESE</item>
        <item>FRENCH</item>
        <item>GERMAN</item>
        <item>ITALIAN</item>
        <item>JAPANESE</item>
```

Then i read save dlanguage with

```
String selectedLanguage = sharedPreferences.getString("listOfLanguages", "NULL");
```

but i don't know how to use now `LOCAL.SELECTED LANGUAGE`. This languages are all from `LOCAL.` options

Can i somehow cast it to local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hopr I get the question!!

You need a second array. For example:

```
    <string-array name="languageSettings">
        <item name="0">UK</item>
        <item name="1">German</item>
        <item name="2">Italy</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="languageSettingsValues">
        <item name="0">UK</item>
        <item name="1">DE</item>
        <item name="2">IT</item>
    </string-array>
```

You can connect it to your ListPreference like this:

```
    <ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="0"
    android:entries="@array/languageSettings"
    android:entryValues="@array/languageSettingsValues"
    android:key="languageSetting"
    android:summary="@string/preferences_alternativesettings_text"
    android:title="@string/preferences_alternativesettings_titel" />
```

This line should work

```
String selectedLanguage = sharedPreferences.getString("listOfLanguages", "NULL");
```

Comment: i know this. But how to cast to Local now. Now you get UK. How to cast it to Local?

Comment: Perhaps this will help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464771/how-can-i-change-language-of-my-application)